# Showcase of beautiful typography done in TeX & friends

Tags: typography, big-list, examples

If you were asked to show examples of beautifully typeset documents in TeX & friends, what would you suggest? Preferably documents available online (I'm aware I could go to a bookstore and find many such documents called 'books'). Extra bonus for documents whose LaTeX source is available.

This is not an idle question. Seeing great examples of any craft is both educational and inspiring, let alone explaining why we prefer TeX to Word or other text editors.

For instance, I like how Philipp Lehman's [Font Installation Guide](https://texdoc.org/serve/fontinstallationguide/0) looks. I don't know enough LaTeX to realize how much customization was done, but the ToC looks polished.

Your nominations, please ...

Comment: Interestingly, the font installation guide probably doesn’t even have that many customizations, at least by the looks of it. Rather, the polished looks come from a very few choice adjustments.

Comment: I really like the microtype manual PDF. Since it's nicely using PDF features like layers and such to create an appealing document.

Comment: It seems to me that the font installation guide was set-up in a more elaborated way in previous versions. Am I missing something or confused with another document?

Comment: I just want to come and vote this up!

Comment: Similar: [Beautiful presentations done with TeX and related systems](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/105621/5645)

Comment: This question has the most stunning and mind-blowing answers I've ever read! I never though Latex can do stuff like this. Now I'll not automatically think about boring theses when people mentioned Latex anymore.

Comment: Most of the links given in answers lead to 404!

Comment: The font installation guide makes me wince. Is it just me, or are the gutters on the wrong sides?

Answer (score 629):

Lately, I've begun working on duplicating [a 16th century French Bible](http://www.bvh.univ-tours.fr/Consult/consult.asp?numtable=B372615206_18229&numfiche=571&mode=1&offset=15&ecran=0) with XeTeX:

https://github.com/raphink/geneve_1564

It features image `lettrine` and OTF features using  XeTeX, specifically the advanced features from the open-source [EB Garamond](http://www.georgduffner.at/ebgaramond/) font, some of which were implemented specifically for this project (thanks to Georg Duffner's great reactivity).

[image: French Bible using EB Garamond]

[image: Second page]

The project is still a work in progress (the marginpars can be improved) and only features one page so far.

### Edit:

After reworking a few details, I ordered a printed copy recently, using [zazzle](http://www.zazzle.fr/geneve_1564_posters-228814041376241982):

[image: Printed poster]

### Edit on 2015/07/07:

Fixed some details in the first page, and added a second page, featuring the EB Garamond Initials font.

Comment: This is a great example to show how something can be (re)created in LaTeX.

Comment: Just awesome. Speechless.

Comment: Truely awesome! This is nothing less than digitally "carving" a PDF file :)

Comment: Wow, amazing. Although, looking at the original page: the little shape above "A R G V M E N T" is mirrored ;)

Comment: Oh yes, I chose a default aldine, the work is not finished. The hyphenation points in the margin paragraphs are not finished either. It's a work in progress.

Comment: I'm sure you've already thought of it, but this is most definitely a candidate for http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34482/contest-show-off-your-skillz-in-tex-friends-tex-sx-birthday.

Comment: @doncherry: no, I didn't see the thread, I was away from TeX.SX for some time.

Comment: Simply impressive!

Comment: How beautiful! True LaTeX masterpiece!

Comment: How did you make the decorative `D.png` and `genese.pdf`? Just scan them?

Comment: They are scanned and "cleaned" a bit (mostly, vectorized).

Comment: A beautiful piece of work, that drop cap is magnificent!

Comment: Incredible.  Can't imagine trying to do that with something other than LaTeX.

Comment: Back in the XVIth century, they did it with their own hands :-)

Comment: I don't know if this is an error on your side... but the Hebrew word on top of the page is written incorrectly.  It should probably be ‏יהוה, not ‎‏יחוח‎.

Comment: Yes @Gandaro , I did notice that. I think it was a mistake made by the original typographer. I just scanned this part and vectorized it, although I was tempted to fix it ;-)

Comment: Since the little Hebrew word at the top is the beautiful name of the Almighty God, you would be forgiven for correcting it, I'm sure. It might have happened as a bleeding error due to the old printing systems with those woodcuts.

Comment: Yes, I might have to erase it and re-type it with a proper font then, such as Ezra SIL

Comment: I don't dare to upvote this, as 365 is just such a nice number of votes! ;)

Gorgeous typesetting though, you must have really invested an enormous amount of time into this!

Comment: You are awesome.

Comment: @Gandaro There, I (finally) fixed it: https://github.com/raphink/geneve_1564/releases/download/2016-06-08_02/geneve_1564.pdf I used Ezra SIL and edited the heading file in Inkscape.

Comment: Ah, but now there's a problem with the argument text… I'll have to figure out why…

Comment: You don't need `-shell-escape` to compile this and it would be better to omit it in case of accidents. (I deleted it before compiling as I couldn't see any good reason for it in the code.)

Comment: Outstanding. Very very good, inspiring for us all

Comment: Wow, this is amazing! This is how I'd love my book to look like!

Comment: I never thought I would upvote a bible page so hard that my mouse would almost break. Congrats!

Answer (score 389):

My lecture notes on Flight Dynamics, in Italian.

[image]

This is [Lecture Note 1](http://wpage.unina.it/agodemar/DSV-DQV/DSV-DQV_Quaderno_1.pdf).

Comment: Damn, fine-tuning of caption positioning, wow!

Comment: Wow! @agodemar have you though on open sourcing it? At least the figure code, it must be awsome!

Comment: What did you use to create the figures?

Comment: @marczellm Most of the figures are made with [Inkscape](http://inkscape.org/); annotations are made using Inkscape's the "Render LaTeX formula" feature. Some figures with 3D scenes were made with [Sketch](http://www.frontiernet.net/~eugene.ressler/) and annotated with tikz. Some other scenes were made with [Blender](http://www.blender.org/) some other with [Cinema4D](http://www.maxon.net/).

Comment: I'm interested in how you managed the caption and figure placement, too!

Comment: @PagliaOrba For the picture on the right-and-page above I used captionof from the caption package, combined with fine-tuned makebox and risebox commands. I didn't care about being in odd- or even-numbered page.

Comment: This is amazing! I wished all professors would take so much care of the learning material. :')

Comment: @agodemar wow! very nice, I'm a mechanical engineer and I wish I had such lectures in my study, could you post the code, I'm writing my thesis and I wish to use your style in my thesis.

Comment: @MuhammadAbdulrasool here are templates that I give to my students for their own homework reports: [http://wpage.unina.it/agodemar/DSV-DQV/Template_LaTeX_Esercitazioni_DSV.zip](http://wpage.unina.it/agodemar/DSV-DQV/Template_LaTeX_Esercitazioni_DSV.zip)

Answer (score 280):

I use LaTeX to typeset my role playing games (RPGs) projects for some years now. I thought I share them here, as they go beyond the usual scientific background. Most content was created in German, but thanks to the LaTeX sources, partial translations in English, Polish, Spanish and French have been done by others. (Xe)LaTeX is used to apply the same layouts to those languages.

At the core there is a CC BY-SA licensed 4 page booklet called *NIP'AJIN* containing game rules. There are separate homepages for the [German](http://ludus-leonis.com/nipajin), [English](http://ludus-leonis.com/en/nipajin), [Polish](http://ludus-leonis.com/pl/nipajin), [Spanish](http://ludus-leonis.com/es/nipajin) and [French](http://ludus-leonis.com/fr/nipajin) PDFs, (Xe)LaTeX sources for all of them are available in a single [GitHub-Repository](https://github.com/ludus-leonis/nipajin). NIP'AJIN makes heavy use of a custom truetype symbol font, for which sources can be found in [a second GitHub-Repository](https://github.com/ludus-leonis/nipajin-dingbats). To keep the page count small, it does not make use of illustrations:

[image: Preview of NIP'AJIN]

Based on that, I have created longer booklets that include those 4 pages and add more content as well as illustrations. Maybe notable are *NIP'AJIN Shots Vol.I* and *Vol.II* that keep the same layout. [German PDFs](http://ludus-leonis.com/nipajin/shots) are available, most of the content (excluding illustrations) is also in the GitHub repository mentioned above:

[image: Preview of NIP'AJIN Shots Vol.I]

Using the same style files of those Shots, I have also created themed booklets. Notable are *Kurai Jikan*, a manga/anime themed booklet (currently available in English, German and Polish), and *Einhundertelf Jahre* (German only), a toys-themed booklet:

[image: Preview of Kurai Jikan]

[image: Preview of Einhundertelf Jahre]

Due license issues with the illustrations, no sources are available for those two, but the PDFs are distributed for free as CC BY-NC-ND. They are done the same way as the starter kit / author's package, found in the [GitHub-Repository](https://github.com/ludus-leonis/nipajin) in the `starter` folder: they take the red-white layout from above and override some layout instructions to replace colors, backgrounds and fonts. The starter kit demonstrates this by creating a blue layout.

Finally, I recently created a CC BY-SA leaflet in German, English and Polish to promote the game. Full sources for it are available in this third [GitHub-Repository](https://github.com/ludus-leonis/nipajin-flyer).

[image: Preview of Leaflet RPG]

Still work-in-progress is [ROBiN](http://ludus-leonis.com/robin), a Robin Hood / medieval themed 80-page book (look at the eBook Version - German however).

**edited on 2016/01/26** Since this answer is still quite popular, I updated it to reflect the current state of the various projects and updated previews and links.

Comment: Amazing work. Since you post it here, is there any way you will share the sources, too? You really nailed the usual RPG book look. Regarding your WiP book I have one point of critique if I may and that's the small caps. They look fake at times, especially for "Kämpfe" for example. Are they?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. The fonts are the reason I am currently migrating from pdflatex to xelatex which should give me better control about font families. I've already been asked about sources, too, and am trying to come up with a solution, once I clarified some legal/license implications.

Comment: Perhaps you might consider LuaLaTeX, too. I found it easier to use but then I don't use a Mac. Good to hear about your plans to open-source these documents. I hope you can sort out the legal stuff :)

Comment: Some sources are now available, for a link see the main article.

Comment: Sources are now hosted on GitHub, see link "Autorenpaket" above.

Comment: +1: Amazing work. I did not think that this is possible in LaTeX ("everything" is possible, but you get what I mean).

Comment: This is truelly amazing. Thanks for sharing, i installed Latex right away now i can see it's capabilities

Comment: Stunning work! I'm looking to use LaTeX for my own RPG projects so this is both a huge inspiration and heartwarming to see just what kind of things are possible.

Comment: Fantastic (with double sense) and amazing work!!! I like very much your work and style, @TeXter

Comment: @TeXter Your work is GREAT!!. Is possible you share the TEX code of KuraiJikan or Einhundertelf Jahre , even without images and with error compilations for not having images?.

Comment: The Tex code for KuraiJikan/Einundertelf Jahre is not very different from the so-called "starter" PDF/setup, which is already part of the nipajin git respository mentioned above. it just contains blue images/headlines instead of anime/toy. Kurai/111 does the same as this "starter", just uses cooler images.

Answer (score 264):

## Bilingual dictionary typeset in `LaTex` and `XeLaTex`

I was asked to publish complete code of bilingual dictionary typesetting in `LaTex`. This regards typesetting of *[Icelandic-Czech Students' Dictionary](http://www.hvalur.org)*.

**The code:**

The complete code can be found in two versions on `GitHub` repositories.

1. [LaTex version](https://github.com/chejnik/LaTex-ICSS)
2. [XeLaTex version](https://github.com/paolobrasolin/tex-dicISCZ)

---

**Examples:**

Example picture of current LaTex version layout.

[image: example_image]

Second example picture : lines in both columns are correctly aligned while displaying two images

[image: example_image2]

---

**Preview**:

1. the first results of [example letters can be viewed here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/dict-system/files/ICSS/)
2. [current version example of letter A](http://www.hvalur.org/download.php)

I humbly admit that this is community collaborative work that helped us step by step to add useful functions to the code. Thank you !!!

We owe the final shape of typography to Paolo Brasolin, that has made diametrical changes, namely:

1. lines in two columns document are aligned
2. `microtype` package in use
3. clarity of the code
4. alignment of figures
5. geometry of layout

---

**Questions and answers that helped to complete the code:**

See [How to set a letter to the margin of the page and position it vertically according to alphabetical order?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/57317/4918) for some explanations about the thumb index.

See [How to display unprinted text in headers?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/43691/8380) for explanations about unprinted headwords in header.

See also question [Two different layouts using fancyhdr](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/32882/8380) that exlains how to use different layouts using `fancyhdr`

See also [Texindy sorting Icelandic](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/165273/texindy-sorting-icelandic/170370#170370) that solves correct sorting of Icelandic index

Comment: Really nice! Maybe you can upload a few pages as a PDF so one can zoom and see the details …

Comment: I added a link to your thumb index question. Since the code is a “community coolaborative work” you may like to add some more links for further reading and to point the reader to more details about some code snippets.

Comment: Thank you for suggestions in editing the answer. I have added the links to PDF and also two more related questions.

Comment: This looks fantastic. Great job

Comment: This is great! Is there a complete source repository somewhere (github or so)?

Comment: As a former dictionary typesetter, this is excellent work. The detail note about collation is a nice touch

Answer (score 209):

If I can be allowed to plug my own project, my [page for Bertrand Russell's *Introduction to Mathematical Philosophy*](http://people.umass.edu/klement/russell-imp.html) shows off 6 different PDFs for different page sizes, including eBook versions, produced with the same core source file. The source is available too. However, it was also one of my first LaTeX projects and I’m a bit embarassed by some of the messiness in the code.

A more recent, and cleaner project (source also available) is [Wittgenstein’s *Tractatus Logico-Philosophicus*](http://people.umass.edu/klement/tlp/) also available in different versions from the same source.

Comment: Vote up for making the source of the whole book available. Great study material. The preamble is also nicely commented.

Comment: Another vote for publishing the source code!  Thanks a bunch- complete book examples really help when tackling a project like this.

Comment: Just a humble question concerning the website. Why, oh why Comic Sans in the header?

Comment: @helcim: The website specifies `font-family: BlackJack, cursive;` On windows, `cursive` often (unfortunately) maps to Comic Sans.

Comment: BlackJack is embedded on the page. It appears your browser doesn't support embedded fonts. But Comic Sans? Yuck. Sorry about that.

Comment: The tractatus is still under copyright isn't it? Author's lifetime plus seventy?

Comment: In the US, everything published prior to 1923 is in the public domain. Author's life + 70 years applies to unpublished stuff. Other countries have different laws.

Comment: So when was 'Principia' published? I've always wanted a copy---preferable a hardback (multi volume I believe) but I'd settle for a pdf :)

Comment: Did you generate the HTML from the tex file? If yes, how did you do that?

Comment: Thank you for sharing your projects! really amazing

Answer (score 205):

My first attempt to make something ... beautiful?

Without trying to imitate any particular book or style, I tried to evoke the beauty of ancient publications (very far from the illuminated books of he Middle Ages with Gothic or Uncial fonts, which are difficult to read for modern people).

The idea was add only add some `fourier-orns` ornaments, color, `lettrine`s and old style numbers (except in math mode) once so popular. The type font is Palatino, that looks old but not 
strange for people (who mostly will be not aware that is not the usual Times Roman). 
There are not ligatures nor random small missplacing of old printing presses, but protrusion and expansion of the `microtype` package help in recreate slight imperfections preventing  printing characters always with exactly the same size. Paper is artificially aged with `wallpaper` package with a simple backgroud.

The two sample pages below  (with nonsense dummy text, biologist please ignore the content) have been joined by the inner margins with Gimp, to simulate their appearance in a paper book.

[image]

**Edit**: I planned to post the code when it was more polished and it could be used as book template... But I never have time to do it, so as requested, here it is, as is. In `graphicx` package have been included the `[demo]` option and `\TileWallPaper` has been commented to make it compilable without images.

```
\documentclass[twoside,12pt,english]{book}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{marron}{RGB}{60,30,10}
\definecolor{darkblue}{RGB}{0,0,80}
\definecolor{lightblue}{RGB}{80,80,80}
\definecolor{darkgreen}{RGB}{0,80,0}
\definecolor{darkgray}{RGB}{0,80,0}
\definecolor{darkred}{RGB}{80,0,0}
\definecolor{shadecolor}{rgb}{0.97,0.97,0.97}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{wallpaper}
\usepackage{wrapfig,booktabs}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\input Acorn.fd
\newcommand*\initfamily{\usefont{U}{Acorn}{xl}{n}}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
tmargin=5cm, 
bmargin=5cm, 
lmargin=5cm, 
rmargin=3cm,
headheight=1.5cm,
headsep=0.8cm,
footskip=0.5cm}


% \usepackage[full]{textcomp}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{pplj} 
\usepackage[
final,
stretch=10,
protrusion=true,
tracking=true,
spacing=on,
kerning=on,
expansion=true]{microtype}

\setlength{\parskip}{1.3ex plus 0.2ex minus 0.2ex}


\usepackage{fourier-orns}

\newcommand{\ornamento}{\vspace{2em}\noindent \textcolor{darkgray}{\hrulefill~ \raisebox{-2.5pt}[10pt][10pt]{\leafright \decofourleft \decothreeleft  \aldineright \decotwo \floweroneleft \decoone   \floweroneright \decotwo \aldineleft\decothreeright \decofourright \leafleft} ~  \hrulefill \\ \vspace{2em}}}
\newcommand{\ornpar}{\noindent \textcolor{darkgray}{ \raisebox{-1.9pt}[10pt][10pt]{\leafright} \hrulefill \raisebox{-1.9pt}[10pt][10pt]{\leafright \decofourleft \decothreeleft  \aldineright \decotwo \floweroneleft \decoone}}}
\newcommand{\ornimpar}{\textcolor{darkgray}{\raisebox{-1.9pt}[10pt][10pt]{\decoone \floweroneright \decotwo \aldineleft \decothreeright \decofourright \leafleft} \hrulefill \raisebox{-1.9pt}[10pt][10pt]{\leafleft}}}

\makeatletter
\def\headrule{{\color{darkgray}\raisebox{-2.1pt}[10pt][10pt]{\leafright} \hrulefill \raisebox{-2.1pt}[10pt][10pt]{~~~\decofourleft \decotwo\decofourright~~~} \hrulefill \raisebox{-2.1pt}[10pt][10pt]{ \leafleft}}}
\makeatother

\fancyhf{}

\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{#1}}

\newcommand{\estcab}[1]{\itshape\textcolor{marron}{\nouppercase #1}}

\fancyhead[LE]{\estcab{Fran Oldstyle}}
\fancyhead[RE]{\estcab{History of taxonomy}}
% \fancyhead[CE,CO]{\estcab{\decoone}}
\fancyhead[LO]{\estcab{\rightmark}} % malo cuando no hay section ~~~ \thesection
\fancyhead[RO]{\estcab{\leftmark}}

% \fancyhead[RO]{\bf\nouppercase{ \leftmark}}
% \fancyfoot[LE]{\bf \thepage ~~ \leafNE}
% \fancyfoot[RO]{ \leafNE  ~~ \bf \thepage}

\fancyfoot[LO]{
\ornimpar \\ \large \hfill \sffamily\bf \textcolor{darkgray}{\leafNE ~~~ \thepage}
}
\fancyfoot[RE]{\ornpar   \\ \large  \sffamily\bf \textcolor{darkgray}{\thepage ~~~ \reflectbox{\leafNE}}  \hfill}

\newenvironment{Section}[1]
{\section{\vspace{0ex}#1}}
{\vspace{12pt}\centering ------- \decofourleft\decofourright ------- \par}



\usepackage{lipsum}
\setlength{\parindent}{1em} % Sangría española
\pagestyle{fancy}

\renewcommand{\footnoterule}{\vspace{-0.5em}\noindent\textcolor{marron}{\decosix \raisebox{2.9pt}{\line(1,0){100}} \lefthand} \vspace{.5em} }
\usepackage[hang,splitrule]{footmisc}
\addtolength{\footskip}{0.5cm}
\setlength{\footnotemargin}{0.3cm}
\setlength{\footnotesep}{0.4cm} 

\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithout{figure}{chapter}
\counterwithout{table}{chapter}


\begin{document}
% \TileWallPaper{300pt}{300pt}{Descargas/fondopapelviejo.jpg}

\chapter{Six kingdoms of life?}
\newpage

\section{Plant\ae}
\lettrine[lines=3]{\initfamily\textcolor{darkgreen}{T}}{he classic} kingdom \emph{Plant\ae} (Haeckel, 1866
include all the multicellular green plants (\emph{Viridiplant\ae} in Latin) as flowering  
plants, conifers, ferns, mosses and green algae. The number of species 
are estimated\footnote{Largely underestimated according to many naturalist.} around 300,000 to 315,000. 
Usually red or brown seaweeds like kelp, fungi and bacteria have
excluded from this group.
This kingdom really exists since Carolus Linn\ae us (1707--1778) who 
divided the natural world into animals, plants and minerals. The kingdom \emph{Animalia}  and \emph{Plant\ae} remained 
in use by modern evolutionary biologists until some years.  

\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.26\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=.26]{Descargas/mobot31753002356449_0113.jpg}
\caption{\footnotesize \emph{Vallaris pergularia} from \emph{Icones plantarum}, vol. II., (Hooker, 1837).}
\label{fig1}
\end{wrapfigure}
But now, both kingkoms are considered only two brachs of the unicelular kingdom \emph{Protist} 
or \emph{Protozoa}\footnote{Although by tradition,  inconsistently the status of kingdom 
is maintained \emph{Animalia}  and \emph{Plant\ae}.}.  
\lipsum[2]

\lipsum[3]

\ornamento

\section{Fungi}

\lettrine[lines=3]{\initfamily\textcolor{darkgreen}{L}}{arlegy}, organism like \emph{Candida albicans} has
 been considered different of \emph{Protozoa} and related with green plants. However, today there 
 are evidences that animals and true fungi are indeed closer to each other than to any other group 
 in the eukaryote tree, far from the alveolates and other eukaryotic lineages.  

\begin{wraptable}{r}{7 cm}
\vspace{-.5cm}
\centering
\footnotesize
\caption{\label{wraptab}Estimated fungal species.}
\begin{tabular}{lr}\\\toprule  
Authors & Species \\\midrule
Bisby and Ainsworth (1943) & $10^5$ \\  
Martin (1951) &  $2.5\times10^5$  \\
Hawksworth (1991) & $1.5\times10^6$ \\ 
O’Brien \emph{et al.} (2005) & $>3.5\times10^6$ \\  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{wraptable} 


\lipsum[4-6]

\end{document}
```

Comment: (+1): Simply awesome!!! Would you like to share the sample code!

Comment: really very good!! can you share an example of the code please?

Comment: I'll third that: do you have a sample code? :)

Comment: Beautiful! Small typo, your darkgray is the same as darkgreen: `{0,80,0}`

Comment: I was messing around with your layout a little bit and I ran into a problem. It will not render images. When I use includegraphics it just makes a black box instead of the image I want. Anyone else have this problem?

Comment: @Slugger this is because the `[demo]` option, as explained in the last paragraph of the answer. Just remove it add change the .jpg file with your own image.

Comment: (Haeckel, 1866 https://xkcd.com/859/

Comment: @SeanAllred Yeah, It is a serious typographical problem  `:)` http://xkcd.com/541/

Comment: Very happy to be the 100th up-voter. :-)

Comment: @Mico, Coming from you, I am feel doubly honored :)

Comment: Hello, I would to see the same color background in your post but my book backgroud is white, please help me. How can I do it your yellow background in my book? thank you

Comment: @Juliperezor  As explained in the answer,  `\TileWallPaper` (just after `\begin{document}`) has been commented to make the example compilable without images. Use  that command with your own JPG or PNG image, or alternatively, for a  non texturized background color, you can use some like `\pagecolor{yellow!07}` after load `xcolor` package in the preamble.

Answer (score 164):

Here is a page from a simultaneous Romanian/English liturgy used in the Romanian Orthodox church that I typeset. I don't know if it qualifies for beautiful, but I'll let you decide. I used an archaich Romanian font for the headings, `parcolumns` for the side-by-side text, and LilyPond for the scores.

**edit**: There's now http://www.liturghie.net/ where the full PDFs are available (also in other languages besides English). Source code will eventually make its way on to GitHub as I clean it up. The whole thing is obviously work in progress.

> [image]

Comment: It definitely qualifies as beautiful!

Comment: Would be so great to do something similar using [Caeciliae](http://marello.org/caeciliae/)...

Comment: Awesome! I had no Idea LaTeX had made its way into everyday life at the BOR ^^

Comment: Too bad the LaTeX-Source hasn't surfaced. I've search all over http://www.liturghie.net/ and couldn't find that document. Any news about this answer?

Comment: +1 I would also like to see the source code on GitHub :)

Answer (score 155):

I may be a *little* biased, but I'm quite happy with the way my thesis [*Circuit Quantum Electrodynamics*](http://www.levbishop.org/thesis/) turned out.

EDIT: I have now [packaged up the source](http://www.levbishop.org/thesis/source) with a brief description of some of the tricks I used (tweaking your latex is a great way to procrastinate when you should be writing a thesis!)

If you find the sources useful, or further if you use my format as the basis of your own thesis, I would love to hear from you!

Comment: Looks excellent. Post the source if you don't mind.

Comment: Looks very good indeed.  Alas, it's *Feynman* not Feynmann!

Comment: Very nice- did you use a document class like memoir or did you roll your own?

Comment: @Sharpie It's based on the latex book class, but heavily customized

Comment: @José Figueroa-O'Farrill It's traditional to have a blatant typo on the first page of a thesis. Let's pretend that this was my [Persian Flaw](http://karelweijand.com/Persianrugsafamilyheirloom.html) (only Allah is perfect).

Comment: Lev, I'm still finding typos in my own thesis, written over 20 years ago.  (Let me just point out, though, that Feynman's name is inexplicably also misspelled in the references.  Don't tell me you wrote the bibliography by hand...)

Comment: @José I *normally* use Zotero for automating my bibliography. But in this case, I must have copied it from a some other source.

Comment: Looks great, I would have avoided the red color (but that is just me :)

Comment: Beautifully done, and the Introduction was a compelling read too.  Your comment above re. Persian Flaws provoked a LOL, thanks.

Comment: The entire table of contents is typeset in red. This is not very beautiful.

Comment: any licence restrictions to use it?

Comment: "tweaking your latex is a great way to procrastinate when you should be writing a thesis!" - So, so true.

Comment: I am absolutely amazed by the fact, that, after all this tweaking and procrastination, you deemed rgb(0,255,0) to be the .... adaequate color for ref links. You got your priorities straight and that's commendable! Beautifully done.

Comment: Lev, your lulu link is broken - you might want to fix it.

Comment: This is absolutely stupendous, what amazing work.  It looks like it took you a lot of time to set up — with options like <memoir> available, would you recommend aspiring thesis-writers to base their thesis on your format instead of <memoir>?

Answer (score 144):

A recent edition to the `pstricks` family is [a set of "Vectorian ornaments"](http://melusine.eu.org/syracuse/pstricks/vectorian/) used for decorating text. It At the moment (don't know whether it might be expanded) it includes 196 ornaments, listed by number:

[image: pstricks Vectorian ornaments]

The [documentation](http://melusine.eu.org/syracuse/pstricks/vectorian/psvectorian.pdf) showcases some of the styles around text.

108: [image]

158: [image]

Comment: I created the pgfornament package It's a pgf version of psvectorian. The version is still beta but seems to work. You can find the package here http://altermundus.com/pages/tkz/ornament/index.html

Comment: Any idea on how to get these working on http://writelatex.com ?

Comment: @francescostablum: If [writeLaTeX](http://writelatex.com) is anything like [ShareLaTeX](http://sharelatex.com), you should be able to upload files to your project. In this case, upload `psvectorian.pro` and `psvectorian.sty` from [`psvectorian.zip`](http://melusine.eu.org/syracuse/pstricks/vectorian/psvectorian.zip) to your project and compile away. The `.pro` file contains all the coordinate drawings for the ornaments in PostScript, while the `.sty` provides the LaTeX-side macros so you can use them.

Comment: @Werner: unfortunately I just discovered that writeLaTeX does not support pstricks :/

Comment: @francescostablum: [I see](https://www.writelatex.com/help/30-what-packages-do-you-support). Then you need to consider using [`pgfornaments`](http://altermundus.com/pages/tkz/ornament/index.html).

Comment: @AlainMatthes: [`psvectorian`](http://melusine.eu.org/syracuse/pstricks/vectorian/) now includes almost 200 constructions... do you plan on adding more of them to [`pgfornaments`](http://altermundus.com/pages/tkz/ornament/index.html)?

Comment: For anyone that uses overleaf.com: insert \usepackage{psvectorian} in the preamble and click on the menu button to change the compiler to XeLaTeX.

Answer (score 143):

One of the most interesting books typeset with TeX that I know, is "Trees, Maps, and Theorems" by Jean-Luc Doumont. It offers beautiful typography down to details such that each paragraph is typeset as a perfect rectangle (which means a lot of textual rewriting, so whether this is a good idea I leave open). But it makes a wonderful coffee-table book, with a lot of very useful advice inside.

[Link to some sample pages as pdf](https://www.principiae.be/pdfs/TM&Th-samplepages.pdf)

Comment: I have this book, and never realized that it is typeset with TeX. The perfect rectangular paragraphs are just amazing.

Comment: The rectangular paragraphs are not a TeX trick but the result of Jean-luc's perfectionnism :-)

Comment: @Ivaneesbeek they are actually both: you need a tool like TeX to offer you typesetting rectangles in the first place, but then you also need to have the patience and perfectionism to fill it "properly"

Comment: I SO want to have the source for this. This is perfect.

Comment: I'd thought that Barry Smith had worked up macros for this for the book _Life Cast: Behind the Mask_ by Willa Shalit. From the post https://groups.google.com/forum/#!original/comp.text.tex/j07Nc3AbRR0/rnmJ5JSIpJoJ ``Photos of life masks are on the right page with descriptive text on the 
left.  Each page of text is set in the same aspect ratio (even though the amount of text varies) with no indentation or breaks.  Periods end sentences and bullets separate paragraphs.  There is no hyphenation.''

Comment: Are you that it was made with TeX? Properties of sample (that you linked to) say something different.

Comment: What is the font used?

Comment: Anyone ever tried to implement a beamer template matching his recommendations?

Comment: @Eekhoorn This is not the source but it's better than nothing :-) http://principiae.be/pdfs/TUG-X-004-slideshow.pdf (go to page 17).
Mr. Doumont [says](https://www.linkedin.com/grp/post/4653707-5840603387543986177) "I do not use LaTeX and, in fact, not even plain.tex anymore".

Comment: @MarioS.E. the typefaces are Lucida Sans and Bright. They have a free alternative - by the same designers - in the Luxi fonts.

Comment: @anderstood not any longer ... thanks for the info

Answer (score 138):

Here are some pages of my end-of-post-obligatory-school work (*Travail de Maturité* in French). The whole source code can be found in [my Git repository](https://github.com/thib1235/LaTeX) under `examples/TM`. Some of this document typo are given as separated files in the `typographyArchive` folder. The document is in French, it's compiled using XeLaTeX. The main font is Lato (it's publish under the SIL open font licence).

The goal was to have a really "modern" design. It is inspired from the flat design that is used for websites.

It took me a lot of time and I hope the result was worth it. I spend some time on the table of content and the chapters headings. Besides, as I wanted something elegant, modern but still uncluttered, special efforts were made on the text look, and the document spacing. The tables are also customized to meet the flat style.

[image: TM typo example]

Comment: some clever ideas, especially flat tables.

Comment: cool! what is the name of the typeface you use?

Comment: @Bartholomaios As I said in the description, I used Lato (Lato Light to be precise) for the body, section title, etc. If you are referring to the title, they are type-setted using 'BIRTH OF A HERO'.

Comment: Gorgeous! This gives me flashbacks to MSDN.

Comment: EXCELLENT WORK!  I love it!

Comment: you have a small typo on page 4: "normes typographiques utilisées dans ce docume**n**t"

Answer (score 137):

The [coloredlettrine](https://github.com/raphink/coloredlettrine) package aims to provide beautiful colored drop caps to LaTeX, using the [EB Garamond](http://www.georgduffner.at/ebgaramond/) font:

[image: colored lettrine example]

Comment: Is it common that the second letter of the first word of a paragraph is a capital letter as well? Like "APres"?

Comment: I honestly don't know. This Bible I found does it after every lettrine, but I don't know if it was common at the time.

Comment: @Raphink: Well it was no offense or anything ;). The books I've seen (including some printed in the late 1700s) use a lowercase letter after the lettrine, but that probably means it differs with cultures I guess.

Comment: This one is from 1564 in Geneva https://github.com/raphink/geneve_1564

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I have looked at a couple of old books I have scanned, and they seem to mix only one letter in uppercase or a few words in small uppercase. Here is the start of every chapter from a book from 1605, where the first word is capitalised: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NqGla.jpg
And here is another from 1585, where it is not consistent between a word and a line: https://i.stack.imgur.com/g7zl9.jpg

Answer (score 131):

If you have time to spare, you can also have a look at my thesis [*Stochastic Multiplayer Games: Theory and Algorithms*](http://logic.rwth-aachen.de/~ummels/diss.pdf). The font is [Fedra Serif B](http://www.typotheque.com/fonts/fedra_serif_b), combined with [FdSymbol](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fdsymbol/).

Edit: My LaTeX class file is available at https://gist.github.com/3428745.

[image: sample pages]

Comment: Very impressive. My time for this is coming soon and I can't get enough of these :)

Comment: Very interesting thesis.  And cool font. Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 116):

For a project I had to typeset a text conversation between two people. I ended up writing a class that recreates the look and feel of the Kik messenger app.

[image]

Source of the class file (`kik-android.cls`):

```
% kik-android.cls
%   by Brian Jacobs (fixes by Maximilian Noethe).
%   April 10, 2018
%
% This document class emulates the user interface of the Kik messaging
% application running on an android Moto X.

\ProvidesClass{kik-android}

% Start with article. Eventually this should be removed,
% because I'm not actually using it for much of anything
\LoadClass{article}

% Load all necessary packages
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}


% Set up the page so that it matches phone size.
\usepackage[top=.55in,         bottom=.55in,
            right=.015in,      left=.015in,
            paperwidth=2.308in,paperheight=4.103in]{geometry}

% Style the page
\pagestyle{empty}
\setmainfont{DroidSans}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

% Color Definitions
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{backgroundgray}{RGB}{238,238,238}
\definecolor{linegray}{RGB}{212,212,212}
\definecolor{circgray}{RGB}{199,199,199}
\definecolor{circdarkgray}{RGB}{117,117,117}
\definecolor{arrowgray}{RGB}{107,107,107}
\definecolor{msggreen}{RGB}{185,224,97}
\definecolor{androidgray}{RGB}{191,191,191}
\definecolor{repwiregreen}{RGB}{71,146,53}
\definecolor{kikblue}{RGB}{103,142,233}
\definecolor{kiktimepalegray}{RGB}{158,169,184}
\definecolor{kiktimedarkgray}{RGB}{122,133,151}

% Customization Flags
\def\@hours{12}
\def\@minutes{11}
\def\@partnerName{Sample Name}

% Macros to draw the background
\def\@statusbar#1{
  \def\c{androidgray}
  \fill[\c]
    let \p1 = (current page.north east) in
      (\x1 - .42in - #1in, \y1 - 0.0415in - #1in) rectangle (\x1 - .43in -#1in, \y1 - 0.1409 in);
}

% Background Macro
\def\@drawBackground{
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    % Background
    \fill[backgroundgray] (current page.north east) rectangle (current page.south west);
    \fill[black]
    let \p1 = (current page.north east) in
    let \p2 = (current page.north west) in
    (\x1,\y1) rectangle (\x2,\y2 - 0.1667in);
    \fill[black]
    let \p1 = (current page.south east) in
    let \p2 = (current page.south west) in
    (\x1,\y1) rectangle (\x2,\y2 + 0.3141in);
    \fill[white]
    let \p1 = (current page.north east) in
    let \p2 = (current page.north west) in
    (\x1,\y1 - 0.1667in) rectangle (\x2,\y2 - .5289in);
    \draw[thick,linegray]
    let \p1 = (current page.north east) in
    let \p2 = (current page.north west) in
    (\x1,\y1 - .5289in) -- (\x2,\y2 - .5289in);
    \fill[white]
    let \p1 = (current page.south east) in
    let \p2 = (current page.south west) in
    (\x1,\y1 + 0.3141in) rectangle (\x2,\y2 + .6090in);
    \draw[thick,linegray]
    let \p1 = (current page.south east) in
    let \p2 = (current page.south west) in
    (\x1,\y1 + .6090in) -- (\x2,\y2 + .6090in);

    % Kik Top bar decorations
      % Circles
    \fill[circgray]
      let \p1 = (current page.north east) in
        (\x1 -.1987in,\y1-.359in) circle (0.04065in);
    \fill[circdarkgray]
      let \p1 = (current page.north east) in
        (\x1 -.15805in,\y1-.31835in) circle (0.04065in);

      % Name
    \draw
      let \p1 = (current page.north west) in
        (\x1 + .4647in, \y1 - .3481in) node[anchor=west] {\@partnerName};

      % Arrow
    \draw[thick,circdarkgray]
      let \p1 = (current page.north west) in
        (\x1 + .1314in, \y1 - .3397in) -- (\x1 + .2179in , \y1 - .3397in);
    \draw[thick,circdarkgray]
      let \p1 = (current page.north west) in
        (\x1 + .1795in, \y1 - .2981in) -- (\x1 + .1314in, \y1 - .3397in) --
        (\x1 + .1795in, \y1 - .3846in);

    % Kik Bottom Bar Decorations
      % Type a message...
    \draw
      let \p1 = (current page.south west) in
        (\x1 + .3141in, \y1 + .5524in) node[anchor=north west,scale=.85] {\color{androidgray}Type a message...};

      % Plus
    \draw[thick, androidgray]
      let \p1 = (current page.south west) in
        (\x1 + .1538in, \y1 + .5321in) -- (\x1 + .1538in,\y1 + .4135in);
    \draw[thick, androidgray]
      let \p1 = (current page.south west) in
        (\x1 + .0906in, \y1 + .4728in) -- (\x1 + .2088in, \y1 + .4728in);

    % Android Top Bar Decorations
      % Time
    \draw 
      let \p1 = (current page.north east) in
        (\x1,\y1-0.01in) node[anchor=north east,scale=0.75] {\color{androidgray}\@hours:\@minutes};

      % Republic Wireless
    \draw[very thick,repwiregreen]
      let \p1 = (current page.north west) in
        (\x1 + .0701in, \y1 - .0801in) to[bend left=90] (\x1 + .1603in, \y1 - .0801in);

      % Battery Indicator
    \fill[androidgray]
      let \p1 = (current page.north east) in
        (\x1 - .3974in, \y1 - .1406in) rectangle (\x1 - .3213in,\y1 - .0509in);
    \fill[androidgray]
      let \p1 = (current page.north east) in
        (\x1 - .3784in, \y1 - .0515in) rectangle (\x1 - .3403in,\y1 - .0379in);

      % Status Bars
      \@statusbar{0}
      \@statusbar{.02}
      \@statusbar{.04}
      \@statusbar{.06}
      \@statusbar{.08}

    % Android Bottom Bar Decorations
    % Home
    \draw[very thick,androidgray]
      let \p1 = (current page.south) in
        (\x1 - .1186in, \y1 + .08974in) -- (\x1 + .1186in, \y1 + .08974in) -- 
        (\x1 + .1186in, \y1 + .1795in)  -- (\x1, \y1 + .2115in) -- 
        (\x1 - .1186in, \y1 + .1795in) -- cycle;

    % Pages
    \draw[very thick,androidgray]
      let \p1 = (current page.south east) in
        (\x1 - .4391in, \y1 + .1058in) rectangle (\x1 - .6026in, \y1 + .1795in);
    \draw[very thick,androidgray]
      let \p1 = (current page.south east) in
        (\x1 - .3974in, \y1 + .1346in) -- (\x1 - .3974in, \y1 + .2219in) --
        (\x1 - .5545in, \y1 + .2219in);

    % Back arrow
    \draw[very thick,androidgray]
      let \p1 = (current page.south west) in
        (\x1 + .4199in, \y1 + 0.1635in) -- (\x1 + .5833in, \y1 + 0.1635in) to[bend left=90]
        (\x1 + .5833in, \y1 + .0993in) -- (\x1 + .5032in, \y1 + .0993in);
    \draw[very thick,androidgray]
      let \p1 = (current page.south west) in
        (\x1 + .4487in, \y1 + .1987in) -- (\x1 + .4199in, \y1 + .1635in) -- (\x1 + .4487in, \y1 + .1282in);

  \end{tikzpicture}
}

% Make the background appear on every page
\usepackage{everypage}
\AddEverypageHook{\@drawBackground}


% Commands for use by the user.
\def\setPartnerName#1{
  \def\@partnerName{#1}
}

\def\setPartnerPic#1{
  \def\@partnerPic{#1}
}

\def\setHours#1{
  \def\@hours{#1}
}

\def\setMinutes#1{
  \def\@minutes{#1}
}

\def\me#1{
  \hphantom{.}\hfill\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) node[anchor=north east,rectangle,rounded corners=2,fill=msggreen, scale=0.75,draw=circgray] {
      \hspace{.1in}\begin{varwidth}{1.5in}
        \vphantom{.}
        \raggedright #1\\
        \tiny \color{msggreen}.
      \end{varwidth}
      \hspace{.1in}
    };
    \fill[msggreen] (-0.01in,-0.06in) -- (0.06in,-0.12in) -- (-0.01in,-0.18in) -- cycle;
    \draw[circgray] (0,-0.06in) -- (0.06in,-0.12in) -- (0in,-0.18in);
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \vspace{.05in}\\
}

\def\you#1{
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \ifdefined\@partnerPic
    \draw (-.6,-.3) node[scale=1.825,circle, path picture={
        \node at (path picture bounding box.center){
          \includegraphics[width=.24in]{\@partnerPic}
        };
      }
    ] {};
    \else\fill[black] (-.6,-.3) circle (.12in);\fi
    \draw (0,0) node[anchor=north west,rectangle,rounded corners=2,fill=white, scale=0.75,draw=linegray] {
      \hspace{.1in}\begin{varwidth}[c]{1.5in}
        \vphantom{.}
        \raggedright #1\\
        \tiny \color{white}.
      \end{varwidth}
      \hspace{.1in}
    };
    \fill[white] (0.01in,-0.06in) -- (-0.06in,-0.12in) -- (0.01in,-0.18in) -- cycle;
    \draw[linegray] (0,-0.06in) -- (-0.06in,-0.12in) -- (0in,-0.18in);
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \vspace{.05in}\\
}

\def\time#1#2{
  \hphantom{.}\hfil\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) node[scale=.65] {\color{kiktimepalegray}#1 \color{kiktimedarkgray}@ #2};
  \end{tikzpicture}\hfil\\
}
```

Source for the conversation:

```
\documentclass{kik-android}

\setPartnerName{Dave Johnson}
\setPartnerPic{Man.jpg}
\setHours{12}
\setMinutes{11}

\begin{document}
\you{Knock knock}
\me{Who's there?}
\you{Canoe}
\me{Canoe who?}
\you{Canoe help me with my homework?}
\time{Fri}{12:03 PM}
\you{...please. I'm gonna fail calculus. :-(}
\me{...}
\end{document}
```

Comment: We prefer self-contained answers. If you could put here the full code (package/class + source of the document) it would be nice.

Comment: You do not need this `\makeatletter` in a class file, do you?

Comment: You don't need it, but it's customary to use @ in macro names of packages, classes, or other code which is likely to be included in other documents. This prevents casual users from accidentally redefining a command used in your package/class. \makeatletter changes the category code of the @ character so that it can be used in macro names. \makeatother undoes this.

Comment: I guess @MaxNoe's point was that `@` already has catcode 11 (letter) in packages/classes, so there is no need to explicitly add `\makeatletter`/`\makeatother`. It's if you want to use `@` in macro names in a preamble that `\makeatletter` is required.

Comment: Exactly. It is just not needed.

Comment: I had to add the line `\usepackage[defaultsans]{droidsans}` to the class file to make it work.

Comment: Using this with TL 2017 results in `! LaTeX Error: The font size command \normalsize is not defined:
               there is probably something wrong with the class file.`

Comment: Moving `LoadClass` directly below `ProvidesPackage` fixed it for me.

Answer (score 109):

I'd like to add two new "styles of typography" which I created recently. The content is not exactly impressive but perhaps the typography is.

The first example document contains more of a regular "book style", with strong influence from the "tufte"-class, although I used somewhat different body text and captions. Here are the first four pages of the second chapter:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wAlAR.png]
[image: http://i.imgur.com/0WMcNfn.png]

I also tried something more experimental. This more futuristic approach does not contain serifs, shows excessive use of notes in the margin, and it uses drop shadows for most figures. Also, I used a slightly less invasive colour pattern. Whatever, I just wanted to twist some rules. Here are some example pages (the real content has been substituted with sample text due to confidentiality issues):

[image: http://i.imgur.com/KSA6c07.png]
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ptKI0.png]
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/t8krM.png]

Comment: Looks great, but small suggestion use max three colors, have the subheadings same color as the headings.

Comment: Yes, too many colors: distracting. Surely interesting.

Comment: Is there a way to get a template? Looks great! I prefer the first version.

Comment: @ManuelKuehner Check your mail box.

Comment: Why don't you put it in a public space? I am interested in compiling it. :-)

Comment: @1010011010: Could you please send a copy of the template to me as well? (vdamanafshan /AT/ gmail.com)

Comment: @Everybody, I currently only have the source which is rather tedious to work with. I'll work on a class file and accompanying template and let you know when it's done.

Comment: I'd love to see a copy of this too if you don't mind!

Comment: A copy for me too! Better yet, why not put it on github? It looks really fantastic (the first one).

Comment: Is their way to download the stylesheet for this template. I think I could learn a lot!!

Comment: I understand that you posted this a long time ago, but I would really appreciate the source (or a stylesheet if you ever distilled it).

Comment: I'd love to get hold of this too... looks absolutely great!

Comment: You should totally put this up on Github with a Share-Alike, Attribution required CC license. Contact me if you are reading this, since I'm helping somebody work on something very similar!

Comment: @1010011010: Could you please send a copy of the template to me as well? (mauramz /AT/ gmail.com)

Comment: I would also love to have a source!

Comment: Looks great - especially the first one. Upload it to github, please ;)

Comment: @1010011010: I would love to get the templates for both. They look great!!

Comment: @1010011010: is it possible to get the templates for the four pages second chapter of the example posted above? Did you put somewhere? If don't, any chance to send by email to jrcarobarrera@gmai.com ? Thanks and regards.

Comment: @1010011010 I also would be very happy to have a template for your first example. This is perhaps the best-looking document I have seen by now.

Comment: @1010011010 same here, would love to get the template for the first style

Comment: @1010011010 Hi, I would like to get the template for the first style too ! (my email is yudhist87@gmail.com) Thanks !

Comment: @1010011010 Did you end up making a document class for this style?

Comment: @1010011010 Hello, Can you please send me a template of this.

Comment: @1010011010 I know it's one of many, but just to bumb the comment, I would also like a template/source for this.
grsrasmus/AT/gmail.com

Comment: @1010011010 Any source available please ? nakrule@protonmail.ch

Comment: @1010011010 Hello, I would like to get the template (my email is sayyidd25@hotmail.com) Thanks!

Comment: @1010011010 Hi, I'm also finding a latex template for my lecture notes on Calculus. Your template looks so nice! I like it. Could you please send me your source codes? Thanks! My email is lichang.hung@gmail.com

Comment: Note that 1010011010 is 666 in binary, and certainly posting such a beautiful work  without the source is nothing less than diabolical ;)

Comment: Hello, I know I'm one of many, but I am currently creating lecture notes for a physics course and your design is just beautiful. If there's any chance to send me a template, here's my email address: horst.depp42@gmail.com   Thanks!

Comment: Could you send me a copy as well? tobias-kolb( at ) hotmail ( dot ) de
I would love this

Comment: @1010011010 could you please send me the first one (email saab.hoq@gmail.com)

Comment: @1010011010 I would love to have this template. Would you please send me a copy? mauramzeta (at) gmail (dot) com. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @1010011010 Hi there! This is an amazing template and I'd be very happy to toy around with it. Could you please share it with me as well, I'd be incredibly grateful!

Comment: Hello, is there any way you could share source code? thank so much

Comment: Has anyone found a copy or tried to replicate the result? Anyone found any clue on who is this devil @1010011010? I have tried searching for the text in the image. But I couldn't find the reference.

Answer (score 108):

It's often said that the 19th century represented a nadir in typography, but I find many documents typeset in this period to be charmingly kitschy.  I've recently undertaken a project to reproduce ["Persecution of New Ideas"](http://www.davidrumsey.com/luna/servlet/s/8s969o), a [notorious quacksalver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C._L._Blood)'s advertisement from [an old 1875 railroad atlas](http://www.davidrumsey.com/luna/servlet/s/zgl5hq).  Here is the LaTeX reproduction, warts and all:

[image: "Persecution of New Ideas" by C. L. Blood, as reproduced in LaTeX]

And here is the original:

[image: "Persecution of New Ideas" by C. L. Blood (original)]

Though there were some tricky bits, on the whole this wasn't terribly difficult to reproduce.  The source code (and the generated PDF) is now available on GitHub: https://github.com/logological/blood

Comment: Only hipsters call a period of typography a nadir :P Very nice!!

Comment: Did you insert the line breaks  manually?

Comment: @Aditya: Yes, I did.  You can examine this yourself by checking the source code I linked to.

Comment: I just had a look at the code. Well done. I thought that the bottom picture would be more trouble.

Answer (score 101):

Personally, I love the ability to really use typography as part of storytelling, like as shown in the `\raisebox` example in [A (Not So) Short Introduction to LaTeX2e](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/lshort/english/lshort-letter.pdf):

```
\raisebox{0pt}[0pt][0pt]{\Large%
\textbf{Aaaa\raisebox{-0.3ex}{aa}%
\raisebox{-0.7ex}{a}%
\raisebox{-1.2ex}{r}%
\raisebox{-2.2ex}{g}%
\raisebox{-4.5ex}{h}}}
she shouted, but not even the next
one in line noticed that something
terrible had happened to her.
```

[image: \raisebox example from A (Not So) Short Introduction to LaTeX2e]

Or to show that `pi` is rather long... (based on `diminuendo` from from the [Tex showcase](http://www.tug.org/texshowcase/)):
[image]

Isn't that art?

Comment: I'll shamelessly plug my own version of Don K.'s pi here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/208426/how-do-i-display-pi-in-latex-like-don/208428#208428

Comment: Alfred Bester often used such devices in his short stories and science fiction.

Answer (score 86):

- The [TeX Showcase](http://www.tug.org/texshowcase/) contains many
  examples.
- The [AAUP SHOWBOOKS site](http://www.tsengbooks.com/) shows Humanities books typeset with TeX
- [tufte-latex](http://ctan.org/pkg/tufte-latex) contains two classes and examples dedicated to the Tufte style

Comment: Thanks. Do you happen to know how the "paper texture" is added (such as in the sample at http://www.tsengbooks.com/images/6176s.pdf)?

Comment: It's just a small image tiled to fill the entire page. You could do that using package atbegshi <http://www.ctan.org/pkg/atbegshi>.

Comment: Is the source code for any of the AAUP Showbooks available?

Answer (score 83):

I scarcely cannot believe, that Christoph Schiller’s herculean 20 years effort of writing a 
free physics textbook [Motion Mountain](http://www.motionmountain.net/) is not on this list. Despite his criticism of [LaTeX](http://www.motionmountain.net/onlatex.html), which itself is interesting to read, the six volumes are produced with LaTeX. Beautifully typeset in MinionPro and Myriad extended by [Johannes Küster’s](http://www.typoma.de) Minion Math.

If I had to choose one project of which I wanted to see the LaTeX source of, it would be this book.

Comment: duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1319/showcase-of-beautiful-typography-done-in-latex/3643#3643

Comment: oh dear, I searched for the title on the list with the space, and then it’s on it without the space...

Comment: Amazing book and typesetting!!! Thank you an information.

Comment: An attempt to reproduce the way the table of contents is built in the Motion Mountain books [can be found in this thread](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/162846/). Despite the presented source code is based on 'article' class, it compiles to something very similar in looks and functionality, including clickable hyperlinks and justified paragraphs. You will also enjoy the fact that unlike the original, the linked solution actually recognizes three levels of section depths.

Answer (score 74):

I try to pay attention to typography (and in particular [French typography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20493/french-typography-recommendations)) details in the books I edit. Hopefully, the result is not too bad (I don't pretend to a typographist nor a graphist):

- [Calvinisme, Arminianisme & Parole de Dieu](http://r.pinson.free.fr/calvary/pdf/calvinisme_digest.pdf) (published last year):

[image: Page 1] [image: Page 21]

- [Charismatique ou charismaniaque ?](http://r.pinson.free.fr/calvary/pdf/charismanie.pdf) (unpublished yet)

[image: Pages 16 and 17] [image: Page 25]

- [Sagesse pour Aujourd'hui](http://r.pinson.free.fr/calvary/pdf/sagesse_lulu.pdf) (unpublished yet)

[image: 2 days]

Lately, I've tried hard to bring acceptable typography to [EPUB publishing](http://cc-translators.github.com/), using the same [LaTeX source](https://github.com/cc-translators/) (and some TeX4HT tricks). Here are some examples taken on Android with Aldiko:

[image: charismanie in aldiko] [image: sagesse in aldiko]

And in Readium (Chrome extension):

[image: charismanie in readium]

[image: charismanie with footnote in readium]

Comment: Could you share instructions on how to obtain such nice epubs? They look amazing!

Answer (score 68):

Here's [ConTeXt + metapost rendition of Oliver Byrne's "The first six books of the Elements of Euclid"](https://github.com/jemmybutton/byrne-euclid)

[image: sample spread]

The idea was not to reproduce the original, but rather to implement its most important features. As a result, there's a metapost library to handle all the byrnian stuff, which can be used to produce similarly styled geometric proofs. I tried to make this lib extensible, and some extras are already there, e. g. there are optional text labels (as Tufte in "Envisioning information" have suggested):

[image: text labels]

And when I realized that there's no need to have pre-drawn linked graphics, I decided not to redraw lettrines from the original, but to make them generated. And so, they are, and by default there are no two identical initials (but it's easy to substitute generated ones with pictures):

[image: lettrines sample]

And even though I'm not quite content with how the book looks yet, I think that's one of the things TeX & friends are great for.

UPD:

There's also a Russian translation of the book now:

[image]

Comment: What a fantastic job, and so nice of you to put it online! Looks great!

Comment: Thank you! So far, the project only benefits from being online and open source.

Comment: The generated drop caps is a great idea!

Answer (score 62):

The thesis of Eivind Uggedal is very nice: [*Social Navigation on
the Social Web: Unobtrusive Prototyping
of Activity Streams in
Established Spaces*](https://www.duo.uio.no/handle/10852/9955)

The source is at http://bitbucket.org/uggedal/thesis/src/

Comment: Why the downvote? Except for the blurry screen shots, the thesis is pretty amazing. At the very least, it’s interesting.

Comment: "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space"

Comment: The direct link to PDF (http://www.duo.uio.no/sok/work.html?WORKID=81971&fid=40769) gives a database error, but this must be a server problem. I'll try again later.

Comment: Looks pretty much like the ClassicThesis (from CTAN).

Comment: @Leo mentioned the ClassicThesis, here is a direct link: http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/classicthesis/ClassicThesis.pdf

Answer (score 60):

I cannot resist to show what all kinds of documents can be done by LaTeX, and I add [this style for children books done by Paulo](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/63759/11002)

[image: Chapter 3]

Answer (score 53):

> **Update:** Template available under [Stack Exchange TeX Blog](http://tex.blogoverflow.com/2015/01/latex-thesis-template-manuel-kuehner/) and/or my [PHD project website](http://bedienhaptik.de/latex-template/).

I wrote a German PHD thesis in LaTeX. In addition I used the `beamer` class to create the slides for the final presentation. Both PDF files can be found [here](http://bedienhaptik.de/dissertation/) (Bedienhaptik.de).

**Thesis**

---

The *thesis* was made using the `koma` class *book* and all the diagrams are made with `pgfplots` and `tikz`. I also used the `hyperref` package of course.

I used **two colors** (red, blue) in the document that are used for structure elements like section and headings and the colors are also used in diagrams.

The colors are:

- `\definecolor[named]{myLayoutColorMain}{RGB}{0,26,153}` (**blue**)
- `\definecolor[named]{myLayoutColorAux}{RGB}{174,49,54}` (**red**)

I used sans serif fonts for captions (tables, figures) and in diagrams. I think this looks nicer.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

---

**Presentation**

---

The *presentation* was naturally done with the `beamer` class in combination with `tikz` and `pgfplots`.

On slide 10 the presentation contains an animation (`pgfplots` and `animate` package).

In order to use the official university font (Helvetica Neue) I had to use LuaLaTeX. With the help of the community here I managed to work it out.

[image]

[image]

[image]

---

Comment: How did you add those red extra texts in the margins left and right? and how did you do the small sub-TOC in under the chapters? And the page numbering with the vertical line, how did you do that? Many questions, but I'm really impressed with that work.

Comment: Hello. Thanks! I will post a blog (http://tex.blogoverflow.com/) soon where I describe the key features.

Comment: @polemon: The thesis template should be available in a few hours. I'll get back to you.

Comment: A template is available. Visit http://tex.blogoverflow.com/2015/01/latex-thesis-template-manuel-kuehner/ or http://bedienhaptik.de/latex-template/.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner: On your website  http://bedienhaptik.de/latex-template/ the link to the template at the bottom of the page is wrong, it links to a zip of other templates, not the one for your thesis, which should be https://bedienhaptik.de/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/latex-thesis-template-by-manuel-kuehner.zip . I tried emailing you but it failed.

Comment: @lblb Thanks. I just tested it and the zip file is correct as far as I can see. `manuel.kuehner [at] gmail.com`

Answer (score 49):

[Christoph Bier](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/10682/typokurz)'s [***typokurz***](https://zvisionwelt.files.wordpress.com/2012/01/typokurz.pdf) is beautiful *and* useful; it's a 15-page guide to (German) (micro)typography in a nutshell. While it's just an article lengthwise (`scrartcl`, to be precise), it masterfully modifies many features frequently discussed on Tex.SX: section-titles, tables, footnotes, marginnotes, header ...

[image: typokurz example page]

What's even better is that the [preamble](https://zvisionwelt.wordpress.com/downloads/#typokurz) is available as well, it even is extensively annotated, but – that will be the downside for most users here – in German, just like the entire document is. Nonetheless, non-German speakers might still find their way around as well as some inspiration in the source code.

Comment: Any possibility of our German friends here at TeX StackExchange translating this preamble?

Answer (score 47):

I got a directory "Beautiful TeX document" on my computer storing files that are beautiful and I might want to look at for inspiration when designing mine.

1. ArsClassica
2. ClassicThesis
3. the manual of pdfx
4. TKZdoc-linknodes-us

All of them can be found in CTAN. `fontinstallationguide` and `tufte-sample-book` have already been mentioned.

LaTeX companion 2nd edition has chapter-3 free on-line (http://www.latex-project.org/guides/tlc2-ch3.pdf). I think the typography is one of the finest.

Comment: All of them can be called up via `texdoc <name>` on a recent LaTeX distribution.

Comment: On Debian based systems, the examples (and a lot more like them) currently live in the package `texlive-publishers-doc` which is not installed by default, but no more than a click/command away. The classes themselves are in `texlive-publishers`.

Answer (score 44):

Here are some screenshots of the pdf output of my Persian class, `neveshtuft` (in Persian: نوشتافت): a class based on the `biditufte-book` class. A sample pdf can be downloaded [here](http://parsilatex.com/download/neveshtuft.pdf). Unfortunately I can't make the source free to download, so it can only be purchased [here](http://parsilatex.com/site/product/%D9%86%D9%88%D8%B4%D8%AA%D8%A7%D9%81%D8%AA-%D8%AD%D8%B1%D9%88%D9%81%E2%80%8C%DA%86%DB%8C%D9%86%DB%8C-%DA%A9%D8%AA%D8%A7%D8%A8-%D8%A8%D9%87-%D8%B3%D8%A8%DA%A9-%D8%AA%D8%A7%D9%81%D8%AA%DB%8C/).

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 44):

I know I'm late to the party, but I have to plug something I've just discovered a few days ago: [a style that mimics the book for Dungeons And Dragons 5e](https://github.com/evanbergeron/DND-5e-LaTeX-Template).

There's an image of the result in Github, but I'll add it here too so it can be easily enjoyed:

[image: D&D 5e LaTeX Template]

If the author reads this, know that you made my day when I found it. Awesome job!

Comment: One of the authors typing here - very happy to hear your like it :-) !

Comment: @Cathode I really do! :-) Though it's so packed with LaTeX stuff that I don't understand (my fault, I'm quite a newbie), that it's taking me some time to grasp it all. It would be great if you could dissect it into elements that could be easily cut-and-paste-able for DYI RPG manuals. Or better yet, easy-to-use macros. With explanations. And examples. And an unicorn, while you're at it ;-) (note that it's been a while since I read the template, and some of this could be already done; specially the unicorn part)

Comment: The example.tex should contain a number of useful examples though it could use some improvements. Maybe I'll find some time for that soon. If you have any specific questions feel free to contact me (https://github.com/anoderay)!

Answer (score 42):

I'm actually quite satisfied with how my Master thesis [*Synthesizing Software from a ForSyDe Model Targeting GPGPUs*](http://kth.diva-portal.org/smash/get/diva2:504941/FULLTEXT01.pdf) turned out.

[image: example pages]

Yes, another shameless plug...

**EDIT:**
There have been requests on making the source code available. Since I don't want to release the full source, I've instead made a [template](https://hjort.dev/publications/documents/thesis-template.tar.gz) available that you can then adapt to your own document. If you heavily base your own thesis report on this template I would appreciate if you made a small acknowledgement somewhere. Other than that - go nuts! =)

Comment: Inspired by the Motion Mountain, were you? It looks appealing.

Comment: @HarroldCavendish: Nope, never heard about _Motion Mountain_ before, but it does look similar. =)

Comment: @henrique: How could I not - it's half the reason why the thesis looks the way it does. =)

Comment: @gablin Siva Prasad Varma was asking in chat (http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5802151#5802151) how you created your thesis, is there any chance of making the source available?

Comment: @TorbjørnT.: Not the entire source, but I'd be happy to share a template. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: @gablin Great, I'm sure he'll appreciate it.

Comment: Looks great. Good one.

Comment: Great template, it's very similar to class `thesisclass`

Comment: @gablin Hey friend,

I'd like to say thanks for you uploading your thesis template for people to use. I'm currently using it for writing up class notes - it provides a good layout to review content. I'm struggling to change the section numbers and headings to be bolded, and preferably in a red color.. I've tried so many different things, but they appear not to work. Any recommendations? Also, I want to change the margins, like you have in \setlrmargins{*}{*}{1} - I'm trying to have the margins about 1 inch all around, but I can't seem to set this up.

Thanks!

Comment: @colonelk1 Hi! Sorry for taking so long to answer, didn't see your comment until now. Here's how to do it colorize and set section headings to bold: In `mypreamble.sty`, there is a macro called `\sectionStyle`. Change its definition to `\bfseries\color{red}` and you should get what you want.

Comment: The margins are a bit more difficult to set. I'll see if I can figure it out...

Comment: @gablin: The first link to your thesis pdf is broken

Comment: @lblb: Thanks for informing me. It's been fixed now.

Answer (score 42):

I dedicated quite a bit of time to the typesetting of my Master's thesis. Therefore I am more than happy to share it with you.

https://www.politesi.polimi.it/bitstream/10589/92341/1/2014_04_Colombo.pdf

It is open source and available at https://github.com/gcedo/master-thesis/tree/master

[image: Cover and colophon]

[image: Chapter opening]

[image: Images and headers]

Comment: Can you share with us your preamble? I supposed you use memoir class (my favourite).

Comment: Very nice. Could you be so kind to share the thesis (or template) with us?

Comment: This looks quite nice. Looking forward to reading it sometime.

Answer (score 38):

OK, so here is one "from the Friends". I am a great admirer of typographic skill of Hans Hagen and [Metafun manual](http://www.pragma-ade.com/general/manuals/metafun-s.pdf) is one of my favourites. Also available is  [Metafun manual source](http://context.aanhet.net/svn/manuals/metafun/).

[image: metafun manual example]

Answer (score 38):

I wonder why nobody suggested the original works of Donald Knuth. To me they are beautiful examples of typesetting. As far as I know, his books and papers are typeset using TeX (vs. LaTeX), but for the sake of the topic, I guess, it doesn't matter.

Some examples:

- The Art of Computer Programming (TAOCP)
- The TeXbook
- The METAFONTbook

The complete list of Knuth's publications as well as preliminary drafts of the TAOCP Vol 4a chapters (in post script files) can be found on his [home page](http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/%7Euno/books.html). The sources of the TaOCP book (tex files) are also available in peer-to-peer networks.

Comment: I have to agree with TAoCP (can’t speak for the rest). As for why nobody has posted them yet, I think the implied assumption in the question was that the source code is available so that one can see *how* the layout is produced.

Comment: And Concrete Mathematcis.

Comment: @Konrad At least for »The TeXbook«, the source is available, although rendered uncompilable. Just google it.

Answer (score 38):

> One of the most interesting books typeset with TeX that I know, is
>   "Trees, Maps, and Theorems" by Jean-Luc Doumont. It offers beautiful
>   typography down to details such that **each paragraph is typeset as a
>   perfect rectangle** (which means a lot of textual rewriting, so whether
>   this is a good idea I leave open).

I agree with [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/94380/11604) from Frank Mittelbach that this format is nice, but I was exhausted just thinking about the hard work to obtain only this "detail".  Write carefully a book and then rewrite it just to fit in rectangular paragraphs?  What a nightmare!

But LaTeX can make automatically rectangular paragrahs with no/minimal rewriting. With two columns, a simple `\parfillskip=0pt` and some reasonable tuning of `microtype` options make wonders. The trick is so simple that struck me not to have seen this solution anywhere. However, it was already explained in the  [egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4427/egreg)'s  long time ago in 
[Is there a tool that makes paragraphs into rectangles?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/116569/is-there-a-tool-that-makes-paragraphs-into-rectangles)).

The solution is not always perfect, specially in one column. The badness concentrated in the  last line of some paragraphs could be nicely scattered in the whole paragraph using `\emergencystretch` in many cases (explained also in the egreg's answer), but sometimes the best solution is still add or remove some words.

Nevertheless, even without `\emergencystretch` one can write the whole *Lore Ipsum* in two columns  with `\lipsum[1-150]` (22 pages) and obtain 150 paragraphs nicely formatted. So, you can also impress to your readers without working hard:

[image: MWE]

Comment: If I remember correctly, Trees, Maps, and Theorems does not use any hyphenation either.

Comment: @Aditya, Yes. Preventing the hyphenation, for example with  `\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}`, certainly add much more badness but still the automatic format with this trick is decent for many  paragraphs, al least for a document as the showed above.

Comment: While impressive, I have to say that I'm not sure I entirely approve ;). What happens to allowing the author to concentrate on the content? Isn't the whole point that the content should ***not*** be deformed for the sake of formatting?! [Why do I think that I've said this to somebody before? If it is you, I do apologise.]

Comment: @cfr I agree totally with you if the style is obtained "with a lot of textual rewritting", but the main point of the answer is that the author *still can focus* mainly on content with this simple trick. If the result worth is a separate issue, that IMHO depend of the type of document. Attract the reader's attention about the style could be a key objective  or totally counterproductive.

Comment: @Fran I really meant the original.

Answer (score 35):

I'm not sure this is exactly 'beautiful typography'. It is a TiKZ picture. However, [somebody urged me to publish it](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/159835/milestone-graphic-in-tikz/159856#comment487422_159856) a while ago and this is the first place I've seen where it might almost belong.

It originally began as a result of seeing [Claudio Fiandrino's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/159856/) but Claudio is in no way responsible for my subsequent mangling!

I modified some code from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/29154 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/41628, but the timeline is also based on ideas and techniques which I learnt from other questions and answers here. I am sorry that I cannot acknowledge everybody from whom I have learnt. If I have failed to acknowledge you, do let me know!

[image: timeline]

It isn't possible to post a very large image here without its being converted to JPG. However, [PDF is available here](http://cfrees.files.wordpress.com/2014/10/timeline-orig.pdf) and can be zoomed to inspect the details.

Comment: Cool! In my opinion it is begging for a condensed sans-serif font, something like PTSansNarrow.

Comment: @percusse I agree but it would throw everything out of place. That is, by the time I realised that, it was essentially too late. I'm not sure I have PTSansNarrow but I would have chosen something more appropriate if I'd realised how involved it was going to become! [It has to fit on A4, and the spacing is a little precise...] I was only really messing around to begin with...

Comment: Well should you accumulate enough courage, it's on CTAN :)

Comment: @percusse Thanks & I guess I do have it in that case ;).

Comment: Neat!  Reminds me in a way of [Adams Synchronological Chart or Map of History](http://www.worldhistorycharts.com/adams-synchronological-chart-or-map-of-history/), which is always fun to look at. (Requisite [Wikipedia link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adams_Synchronological_Chart_or_Map_of_History).) Also, his was handdrawn --- (just a guess, but) I'm not sure who had the harder time....

Comment: @cfr: It's just amazing! I support percusse's suggestion: you should definitely go for a package!

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino I'm not sure what you mean about going for a package. percusse is suggesting I change the font, which would require using a (different) package, but would also require redoing a whole bunch of fine-tuning of spacing. I'm not sure I can face that! (And it takes a *loooooooooong* time to compile so testing is painful.) ;)

Comment: @cfr: Not _that_ comment, but the other one ;) A package for CTAN :)

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino That's about the font...

Comment: @cfr: Ops... true! Never mind: think about make that a package in any case :)

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino A package to do what exactly? That is, I'm not clear which parts, if any, would be useful in a package.

Comment: @cfr: A package might provide the basic macros to draw blocks and connections in relation to the timeline. The scope is to allow any other user to potentially replicate the chart.

Comment: The problem with @percusse's suggestion, I'm finding, is that the text boxes come out with different heights, whereas small-caps kills the depth ....

Answer (score 35):

My two cents:

https://github.com/alexisflesch/nexus

It's a work in progress, but I'm quite satisfied with the result already. The little squares in the footers are clickable links to the corresponding chapters.

A big part of the code was borrowed to stackexchange contributors.

[image: Title page and TOC]
[image: One chapter]

Comment: I'd say, it's too much colorful. Reducing them a little may make it easier to read (which is the main purpose).

Comment: I liked the title page very much. Could show me the necessary and sufficient codes for the title page only?

Comment: There is a titlepage.tex file on my GitHub ;)

Comment: The tabs on the bottom fail to work when loading the mhchem package

Answer (score 33):

[Complete Source Code and Thesis](https://github.com/Ritterbecks/Hausarbeit)

Since I've got four more exams on my plate there was no time to tidy up the code and the way the chapter headings are written, they prevent the use of tikzexternalize.

An image from my end-of-term-thesis and the .pdf above (sadly only two links can be posted as new user):
[image]

It is mostly reverse engineered wherever I needed a solution for my ideas, but could have more easily been accomplished with classic thesis, I assume.

The data sctructure is from Matthias Posspiech's thesis template, but seems to have a good amount of redundant code in it. The headings are customized personally, while the chapter titles are a version from the Grande Orange Book (spelled correctly?).

Sadly I didn't get the full width floats right ;(

Comment: It would be interesting to have the .pdf and even the source code to such thesis.

Comment: All uploaded. Excuse the messy coding, but I had to get it out until my deadline.

Answer (score 32):

There are two templates for theses at CTU (Czech Technical University in Prague) and CU (Charles University in Prague). These templates provide remarkable design which differs from standard theses created by LaTeX. The first mentioned template is called [CTUStyle](http://petr.olsak.net/ctustyle-e.html) and the second is [CUStyle](http://petr.olsak.net/custyle-e.html). The title page of a bachelor's thesis created by CUStyle is shown here:
[image: CUStyle, first page]

Charles University is an ancient school so there is its logo created as Kings seal on the ribbon.

There are full examples of student's work. First two are from CTU (in
English) and the third is from CU.
[480.pdf](https://cyber.felk.cvut.cz/research/theses/papers/480.pdf) (or [480.pdf](http://cyberold.felk.cvut.cz/research/theses/papers/480.pdf)),
[339.pdf](http://cyber.felk.cvut.cz/research/theses/papers/339.pdf) (or [339.pdf](http://cyberold.felk.cvut.cz/research/theses/papers/339.pdf)),
[mirek-bakalarka](http://www.olsak.net/mirek/bakalarka/). The
third one is available including source code.

Both templates are based on 
[OPmac](http://petr.olsak.net/opmac-e.html).
Notice that students are able to use pure plainTeX + OPmac (no LaTeX were
used).

Answer (score 31):

I really like the documentation of Philipp Lehman. The [Font Installation Guide](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/Type1fonts/fontinstallationguide/fontinstallationguide.pdf) was mentioned in the question, but I also think for a simpler article (rather than the book style) his package documentation is hard to beat aesthetically, e.g. [`biblatex`'s](http://tug.org/svn/texlive/branches/branch2012/Master/texmf-dist/doc/latex/biblatex/biblatex.pdf?revision=26942&view=co)

In *[biblatex manual [was: Can I make a document that looks like this?]](http://newsgroups.derkeiler.com/Archive/Comp/comp.text.tex/2008-06/msg00210.html)*, the author explains how to recreate this style (fonts and such).

Answer (score 31):

I'd like to add our main project report, which was created the last semester at a 2-year technical college.

[Main Report as pdf (OneDrive link)](https://1drv.ms/b/s!Av4BJMpCL3Jo_TWh2CfYen-HTp0_)

[Stripped-down example/template (needs XeLaTex)](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Av4BJMpCL3Jo-xzsNE6G_Pqk7ey0/MotoLift_Template.zip?dl=0)

(Note: This template bears some marks from being taken from a paper written under a constant time-pressure with multiple revisions, and was never meant to be shown off in public)

Here are some outtakes:
[image: Table of Contents]
[image: Tables, math and figures]
[image: Explanation of some parts]

Comment: Sadly, your template link does not work for me (anymore). Any chance that you could update it / send me the template another way?

Answer (score 31):

My humble contribution, using Memoir and EB Garamond.

```
% !TeX program = xelatex
\let\counterwithout\relax
\let\counterwithin\relax
\documentclass[a6paper,12pt,final]{memoir}
\usepackage[top=0.4in,bottom=0.3in,right=0.78in,left=0.78in]{geometry}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}


%dark red defined as \h{}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\newcommand{\h}[1]{\textcolor{FireBrick}{#1}}
\definecolor{bblue}{rgb}{0.74,0.80,0.84}
\usepackage{psvectorian,fancyhdr,lipsum,multido}


%to open PDFs in full H-Fit
\usepackage[hidelinks,bookmarks=false]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{pdfstartview={XYZ null null 1.22}}
\usepackage{bbding}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont[Ligatures={Required,Common,Contextual,Rare,Historic,TeX},Numbers=OldStyle,RawFeature={+ss05,+dlig,+hlig,+calt,+liga},ItalicFeatures={RawFeature={+cv04,+clig,+swsh,+calt,+liga,+hlig,+ss05},CharacterVariant=5:0}]{EB Garamond}


\usepackage{pgfornament}
\usepackage[final]{microtype}
\begin{document}
    \pagecolor{bblue}
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \topskip0.01pt
    \large

    \begin{center}\Large
    \textsc{the paradox of}\\   \rput[r](-3pt,3pt){\psvectorian[width=2em, 
     color=Maroon]{102}} \textit{Epimenides}    \rput[l](0pt,3pt) 
     {\psvectorian[width=2em,mirror, color=Maroon]{102}}\\

        \large
    \end{center}
    \vskip.25cm

    \lettrine[loversize=0.3,
    lines=3,
    slope=-0.1em,
    nindent=5pt,
    lhang=0.35]{E}p\textsc{imenides} was a Cretan and a philosopher (600 
    \textsc{bc})
    who made an \emph{immortal} statement:

    \begin{quote}
        \emph{``All Cretans are liars.''}
    \end{quote} 

    but, Epimenides, was a Cretan and therefore, a liar. A statement by a liar, cannot be true and it meant, Cretans did \emph{not} lie, but spoke \emph{truth}.\\

    Now, if, Epimenides speaks \emph{truth,} then by his own statement, he, a Cretan, is a liar. Does Epimenides \emph{speak truth} or \emph{lie?}\h{\pgfornament[width=17pt]{1}}\hfil\\

    \begin{tiny}
        \begin{center}
            \textsc{typeset in latex by ajay kd}
        \end{center}
    \end{tiny}


    \vspace*{\fill}



\end{document}
```

[image: Paradox of Epimenides]

Comment: The spacing around the ornaments could be a little wider, but otherwise, nice! I especially like the way the lettrine hangs out into the margin.

Comment: Very nice. Would be much better if you showed the code you used to produce this :)

Answer (score 30):

While writing it, I really liked my bachelor thesis [*Implementation of a Read Mapping Tool
Based on the Pigeon-hole Principle*](http://madrat.net/my/bachelor/thesis), even though the margins (and some other things) were all wrong.

Looking back, I probably wouldn’t use such a heavy font again (Hoefler Text). But I still like the chapter headings a lot:

[image: chapter heading]

Comment: The font for the equation numbers does not look good enough.

Comment: @xport Yup, that’s still using the Computer Modern font.

Comment: They look nice, I'll create a `memoir` version of it for a later edition of my memoir chapter style showcase document

Comment: @usr1234567 Thanks for pointing this out. I’ll try to find a copy of my thesis later and upload it somewhere else. Unfortunately my alma mater does not seem to archive undergrad theses (at least there’s nothing public facing).

Answer (score 27):

I wrote both my PhD thesis and presentation in LaTeX.
Most images were directly created in LaTeX, using tikz/pgfplots.

A particularity of my template is that it features one page turning animation on each side (hourglass on the left and a glider on the right).
Both animations were also generated using LaTeX.

The source code is available at [GitHub](https://github.com/npcardoso/PhDThesis).

### Thesis

[image]

### Presentation

[image]

Comment: Welcome and thank you for your contribution.

Comment: Your documents are very colourful. Some people are colourblind and might miss one of your points. [Colorblind, links hard to see](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/6795)

Comment: Thank you for your comment, you are absolutely right. I did not think about that problem. However, since a lot of us print stuff black and white, I always tried to be redundant in the places colors are really important, e.g., the plots redundantly have colors and symbols to depict the same subjects.

Answer (score 26):

I made an abstract book for a conference on this webpage, using LuaLaTeX and TikZ, and automating the process from a database: [Abstract Book](http://sccs2015.soton.ac.uk/downloads/abstract_book.pdf)

The book also has comment fields to add comments and save them on the PDF

[image: Cover]
[image: Abstract]

Comment: Could you please share a copy of the template to me? (mauramz /AT/ gmail.com)

Comment: Sorry, I will try to organise the files and send it to you when I have some free time

Comment: Nice work, I'm curious about how you're accessing the database and the whole automation. Have you considered sharing a GitHub repository, please?

Comment: The access to the database is a long process, so it requires time to tidy up the files, maybe I will do that in the future. I created a repository with the LaTex style and how to generate the abstract book here https://github.com/davidcortesortuno/conference_style . Regards.

Answer (score 24):

[*A Brief Introduction to Neural Networks*](http://www.dkriesel.com/en/science/neural_networks) is a beautiful one.

Comment: When I just found this thread, I was thinking of that exact same document. I would have added it if you hadn't. It also looks interestingly un-TeX-like I think.

Comment: Sure, this is really marvellous. Except that the ToC doesn't fit into the design imho (it's pretty default too).

Comment: ...2 inch margins. Does that count as padding?

Comment: Nice document, but not that impressive.  I see different figures using different font and font sizes (compare p.22 to p.38) and even font size larger font than that of the main text (p.22, p.63).  Figures that overflow under the next column (p.40).  Tables with rules that disappear around colored cells (p.41).  Pages with 2-word widows (p.49).  Paragraphs mixing `-` with `--` where I would have used `---` (p.59).

Answer (score 24):

Since there are very few "and friends" entries, let me point out to my PhD thesis [*Sequential decomposition of sequential dynamic teams: applications to real-time communication and networked control systems*](http://www.ece.mcgill.ca/~amahaj1/projects/thesis/mahajan-thesis.pdf). It is, by no means, unique or beautifully typeset; but if one takes into consideration that I had to follows all the horrible typographic guidelines laid out by the university (margins, fonts, headings, interline spacing, and what not), I think that the result is rather pleasant.

[image: example pages]

The thesis is typeset using ConTeXt + LuaTeX (0.43). I think that it might be the first thesis  typeset using LuaTeX. This was before ConTeXt was split into MkII and MkIV, and before LuaTeX had Opentype math font support.

I do use a rather unconventional style for typesetting multi-line equations with subscripts (see, for example, pages 27-29). Most of this was done manually (wrapped behind macros, of course). I also had to do some manual tweaking to get the bibliography just as I wanted it.

The ConTeXt [source](http://www.ece.mcgill.ca/~amahaj1/projects/thesis/thesis.tar.gz) is available, although so much has changed in LuaTeX and ConTeXt MkIV in the last three years, that I doubt it will compile without some tweaks to the environment files.

Answer (score 23):

I would like also to show something, which isn't that sophisticated but I believe it's a nice way to make simple but fancy covers with spine and flaps. I hope you find it usefull. What it's going to follow is some covers I made for my thesis using `zwpagelayout` package which can fe found [here](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/zwpagelayout) 
and `pgfornaments` which can be found [here](http://altermundus.com/pages/tkz/ornament/index.html)

The preamble is the following

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfornament}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage[iso-8859-7]{inputenc}
\usepackage{kerkis}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.fractals}
\usepackage{multicol}
%^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
\usepackage[papersize={,297mm}, strictheight=false,topmargin=0mm, botmargin, flap=50mm, textwidth=209mm, spine=13mm, cropmarks, cropframe, croptitle=Εξώφυλλο Διπλωματικής]{zwpagelayout}
\usepackage{rotating}
 %^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
\linespread{1}
\begin{document}
%There goes the code!
\end{document}
```

The following lines contain code for four covers as well as the output of each code. Each code is placed between `begin{document}` and `end{document}` in the aforementioned preamble.

**First Cover**

*Code*

```
\hbox to \textwidth{%
\vbox to \textheight{\hsize \CropFlap \centering \textcolor{white}{Front Flap}
}\hss
\vbox to \textheight{\hsize \UserWidth \vfill \leavevmode \textcolor{white}{ISBN+EAN}}\hss
\vbox to \textheight{\hsize \CropSpine \vfill
\begin{sideways}\hspace{-10cm}Αθανάσιος Ν. Σταματόπουλος \hspace{5cm}{\Large Μελέτη     Ανιχνευτή \latintext{MicroMEGAS}}  \end{sideways}\vfill}\hss
\vbox to \textheight{\hsize \UserWidth \vspace{1cm} 
\setlength{\unitlength}{1cm}
\begin{picture}(20,27)

\put(0.7,1){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(1.7,1){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(0.7,2){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(1.7,2){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(0.7,3){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(1.7,3){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(0.7,4){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(1.7,4){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(0.7,5){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(1.7,5){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(0.7,6){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(1.7,6){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(0.7,7){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(1.7,7){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(0.7,8){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(1.7,8){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(0.7,9){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(1.7,9){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(0.7,10){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(1.7,10){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(0.7,11){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(1.7,11){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(0.7,12){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(1.7,12){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(0.7,13){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(1.7,13){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(0.7,14){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(1.7,14){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(0.7,15){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(1.7,15){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(0.7,16){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(1.7,16){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(0.7,17){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(1.7,17){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(0.7,18){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(1.7,18){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(0.7,19){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(1.7,19){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(0.7,20){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(1.7,20){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(0.7,21){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(1.7,21){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(0.7,22){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(1.7,22){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(0.7,23){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(1.7,23){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(0.7,24){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(1.7,24){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(0.7,25){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(1.7,25){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(0.7,26){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(1.7,26){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
%-----------------------------------------------------------
\put(3.4,23){\includegraphics[width=3.3cm]{ntua-logo}}
\put(7.1,25.4) {{\Large Εθνικό Μετσόβιο Πολυτεχνείο}}
\put(7.1,24.9) {{\Large Σχολή Εφαρμοσμένων Μαθηματικών\&Φυσικών Επιστημών}}
\put(7.1,24.4) {{\Large Τομέας Φυσικής}}
\put(7.1,23.9) {{\Large Εργαστήριο Πειραματικής Φυσικής Υψηλών Ενεργειών}}
\put(6,14){{\huge Μελέτη ανιχνευτή \latintext{MicroMEGAS}}}
\put(7.5,7.5){{\Large Σταματόπουλος Ν. Αθανάσιος}}
\put(9,1.5){{\Large Οκτώβριος 2012}}
\end{picture}}\hss
\vbox to \textheight{\hsize \CropFlap \textcolor{white}{Back Flap}
}}
```

*Output*

[image]

**Second Cover**

*Code*

```
\hbox to \textwidth{%
\vbox to \textheight{\hsize \CropFlap \centering
\textcolor{white}{Back flap}\vfill}\hss
\vbox to \textheight{\hsize \UserWidth \vfill \leavevmode \textcolor{white}{ISBN+EAN}}\hss
\vbox to \textheight{\hsize \CropSpine \vfill
\begin{sideways}\hspace{-10cm}Αθανάσιος Ν. Σταματόπουλος \hspace{5cm}{\Large Μελέτη     Ανιχνευτή \latintext{MicroMEGAS}}  \end{sideways}\vfill}\hss
\vbox to \textheight{\hsize \UserWidth \vspace{1cm} 
\setlength{\unitlength}{1cm}
\begin{picture}(20,27)


\put(0.7,1){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(1.7,1){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(0.7,2){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(1.7,2){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(0.7,3){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(1.7,3){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(0.7,4){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(1.7,4){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(0.7,5){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(1.7,5){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(0.7,6){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(1.7,6){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(0.7,7){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(1.7,7){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(0.7,8){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(1.7,8){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(0.7,9){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(1.7,9){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(0.7,10){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(1.7,10){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(0.7,11){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(1.7,11){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(0.7,12){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(1.7,12){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(0.7,13){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(1.7,13){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(0.7,14){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(1.7,14){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(0.7,15){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(1.7,15){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(0.7,16){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(1.7,16){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(0.7,17){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(1.7,17){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(0.7,18){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(1.7,18){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(0.7,19){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(1.7,19){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(0.7,20){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(1.7,20){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(0.7,21){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(1.7,21){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(0.7,22){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(1.7,22){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(0.7,23){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(1.7,23){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(0.7,24){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(1.7,24){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(0.7,25){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(1.7,25){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(0.7,26){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
\put(1.7,26){\pgfornament[width=1cm]{25}}
%-----------------------------------------------------------
\put(9.5,23){\includegraphics[width=3.3cm]{ntua-logo}}
\put(8,22) {{\Large Εθνικό Μετσόβιο Πολυτεχνείο}}
\put(5,21.5) {{\Large Σχολή Εφαρμοσμένων Μαθηματικών\&Φυσικών Επιστημών}}
\put(9.5,21) {{\Large Τομέας Φυσικής}}
\put(5.5,20.5) {{\Large Εργαστήριο Πειραματικής Φυσικής Υψηλών Ενεργειών}}
\put(6,14){{\huge Μελέτη ανιχνευτή \latintext{MicroMEGAS}}}
\put(7.5,7.5){{\Large Σταματόπουλος Ν. Αθανάσιος}}
\put(9,1.5){{\Large Οκτώβριος 2012}}
\end{picture}}\hss
\vbox to \textheight{\hsize \CropFlap \centering
\textcolor{white}{Front flap}\vfill}}
```

*Output*

[image]

**Third Cover**

*Code*

```
\hbox to \textwidth{%
\vbox to \textheight{\hsize \CropFlap 
\vspace{20.5cm} \begin{tikzpicture}\draw[color=gray!50,fill=gray!50] (0,0) rectangle     (5,-2);\end{tikzpicture}\vfill}\hss
\vbox to \textheight{\hsize \UserWidth \vspace{20.5cm}     \begin{tikzpicture}\draw[color=gray!50,fill=gray!50] (-2,0) rectangle     (30,-2);\end{tikzpicture}}\hss
\vbox to \textheight{\hsize \CropSpine \vfill
\begin{sideways}\hspace{-10cm}Αθανάσιος Ν. Σταματόπουλος  \hspace{5cm}{\Large Μελέτη     Ανιχνευτή \latintext{MicroMEGAS}}  \end{sideways}\vfill}\hss
\vbox to \textheight{\hsize \UserWidth \vspace{1cm} \line(1,0){40}{} \Large Σταματόπουλος     Ν. Αθανάσιος \line(1,0){320}\\ \setlength{\unitlength}{1cm}\begin{picture}(27,17)
\put(1,7){\includegraphics[width=3.5cm]{ntua-logo}}
\put (5.5,9.5){\Large Εθνικό Μετσόβιο Πολυτεχνείο}
\put (5.5,9){\Large Σχολή Εφαρμοσμένων Μαθηματικών\&Φυσικών Επιστημών}
\put (5.5,8.5) {\Large Τομέας Φυσικής}
\put (5.5,8) {\Large Εργαστήριο Πειραματικής Φυσικής Υψηλών Ενεργειών}
\put (1,1) {\huge Μελέτη ανιχνευτή \latintext{MicroMEGAS}}\end{picture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[color=white,opacity=1] (0,2) -- (10,2);
\draw[color=gray!50,fill=gray!50] (0,0) rectangle (25,-2);
\node at (3,-6) {\large Οκτώβριος 2012};
\end{tikzpicture}
}\hss
\vbox to \textheight{\hsize \CropFlap \vspace{20.5cm}     \begin{tikzpicture}\draw[color=gray!50,fill=gray!50] (0,0) rectangle     (4.5,-2);\end{tikzpicture}\vfill}}
```

*Output*

[image]

**Fourth Cover**

*Code*

```
 \hbox to \textwidth{%
 \vbox to \textheight{\hsize \CropFlap 
 \vspace{20.5cm} \begin{tikzpicture}\draw[color=red,fill=red] (0,0) rectangle     (5,-2);\end{tikzpicture}\vfill}\hss
\vbox to \textheight{\hsize \UserWidth \vspace{20.5cm}     \begin{tikzpicture}\draw[color=red,fill=red] (-2,0) rectangle     (30,-2);\end{tikzpicture}}\hss
\vbox to \textheight{\hsize \CropSpine \vfill
\begin{sideways}\hspace{-10cm}\textcolor{blue}{Αθανάσιος Ν. Σταματόπουλος}  \hspace{5cm}    {\Large \textcolor{blue}{Μελέτη Ανιχνευτή \latintext{MicroMEGAS}}}      \end{sideways}\vfill}\hss
\vbox to \textheight{\hsize \UserWidth \vspace{1cm} \begin{tikzpicture}\draw[red,very     thick] (0,0) --(3,0); \node at (6.3,0) {\Large Σταματόπουλος Ν. Αθανάσιος}; \draw[red,very     thick] (9.6,0) -- (20,0); \end{tikzpicture}\\ \setlength{\unitlength}{1cm}\begin{picture}    (27,17)
\put(1,7){\includegraphics[width=3.5cm]{ntua-logo}}
\put (5.5,9.5){\Large Εθνικό Μετσόβιο Πολυτεχνείο}
\put (5.5,9){\Large Σχολή Εφαρμοσμένων Μαθηματικών\&Φυσικών Επιστημών}
\put (5.5,8.5) {\Large Τομέας Φυσικής}
\put (5.5,8) {\Large Εργαστήριο Πειραματικής Φυσικής Υψηλών Ενεργειών}
\put (1,1) {\huge Μελέτη ανιχνευτή \latintext{MicroMEGAS}}\end{picture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[color=white,opacity=1] (0,2) -- (10,2);
\draw[color=red,fill=red] (0,0.2) rectangle (25,-1.8);
\node at (3,-6) {\large Οκτώβριος 2012};
\end{tikzpicture}
}\hss
\vbox to \textheight{\hsize \CropFlap \vspace{20.5cm}     \begin{tikzpicture}\draw[color=red,fill=red] (0,0) rectangle     (4.5,-2);\end{tikzpicture}\vfill}}
```

*Output*

[image]

Comment: you should read about the \foreach command, it enables you to use for loops in an easy way (even outside a tikzpicture environment). See section 44 of the pgfmanual.

Answer (score 22):

Admittedly, you asked for LaTeX, not TeX, but the TeXbook is quite nice. Its source is freely available, but you are not allowed to compile it.

The source file, [texbook.tex](http://mirrors.ctan.org/systems/knuth/dist/tex/texbook.tex), starts with the following code.

```
% This manual is copyright (C) 1984 by the American Mathematical Society.
% All rights are reserved!
% The file is distributed only for people to see its examples of TeX input,
% not for use in the preparation of books like The TeXbook.
% Permission for any other use of this file must be obtained in writing
% from the copyright holder and also from the publisher (Addison-Wesley).
\loop\iftrue
  \errmessage{This manual is copyrighted and should not be TeXed}\repeat
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'not allowed to compile'?

Comment: @pushpen.paul, I updated the answer to address your question.

Answer (score 22):

I know two nice repositories (the last one has already been listed here):

1. [Dario Taraborelli](http://nitens.org/taraborelli/latex) shows some of the elegant and beautiful features of LaTeX.
2. There is the [TeX Showcase](http://www.tug.org/texshowcase/), edited by Gerben Wierda, which contains examples of what you can do with LaTeX. Most, if not all, of these examples are of exceptionally high quality.

Comment: Tex Showcase!  I saw, and was impressed by that years ago, and wanted to refer to it again some time ago and couldn't find it.  +1, thanks.

Answer (score 21):

Perhaps a little off the track of beautiful *document* typography per se, but I often turn to the [TikZ and PGF examples](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/) pages when I'm seeking inspiration or solutions re snazzy and relatively easy to produce vector graphics typography.

Comment: I'm not sure I think there is such a thing as "vector graphics typography", but +1, I do agree that these examples are good: the intergration of PGF into Latex, like the integration of Metapost into Context, does help with the visual organisation of content, and can help typography.

Answer (score 21):

The articles from the online journal ['Semantics & Pragmatics'](http://semprag.org/index) seem to come out very well.

[image: example pages]

Comment: Nice example of Lucida fonts.

Answer (score 21):

I think [Lorenzo Pantieri](http://www.lorenzopantieri.net/LaTeX.html)'s books and articles very nice. He uses his package ArsClassica and are written in italian.

At [aprende matematicas](http://www.aprendematematicas.org.mx/profesores/latex.html) (learn mathematics) you will find some mathematical books also written with LaTeX.

And at the [Malaysian LaTeX User Group Blog](http://latex-my.blogspot.com/2009/10/true-or-false-latex-can-produce-only.html) there is a tutorial explaining how to design a *not so boring* book.

[image: L15 pdf]

Comment: The second link ends with an error.

Comment: @xport: It works for me. The link to the pdf is http://www.aprendematematicas.org.mx/obras/L15.pdf but you can also try through scribd at http://www.scribd.com/doc/17909256/LaTeX2e-en-15-Sesiones

Comment: the book layout is very good. :)

Comment: does the english vesion exist for that book?

Comment: @xport, I don't know it. I don't think so, but you can ask to the author, it's email address is shown at the bottom of the web page.

Answer (score 19):

Here's another shameless plug for one's own thesis: [*Narrowband CARS spectroscopy in the molecular fingerprint region*](http://purl.org/utwente/e58346)

[image: screenshot]

Here's some of the typographically relevant code I used, plus the code for the abstract page: http://pastebin.com/JWFjbZ1q

Answer (score 18):

The last document I opened that made me say "wow" was the [`elsarticle` document class documentation](https://www.elsevier.com/__data/assets/pdf_file/0008/56843/elsdoc-1.pdf).

The layout is highly nonstandard, and it wouldn't be suitable for most purposes, but it sure displays beautifully.

Comment: It's a matter of taste. River valley obviously wants to show off their latex skills and make something that looks completely unlike people's preconceptions of a latex-produced document. Which is fine. But I personally find this a very over-the-top format, distracting and not at all easy to read, so it fails my definition for 'beautiful typography', which to my mind should mostly get out of the way and let you _read the document_.

Comment: I agree with Lev. It is more like a poster.

Comment: While I agree with @Lev and @Leo that there are a lot of distracting elements (it’s (intentionally) more like a website than a print document), the main text body still has a very appealing format in my opinion. Also, I like everything that challenges preconceptions.

Answer (score 16):

[The Latex Font Catalogue](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/alphfonts.html) is a wonderful resource.  <del>For some reason</del> it is missing the [Zapfino](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zapfino) font (as it is nonfree), which was [packaged by Walter Schmidt](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/metrics/w-a-schmidt/zap.txt).

Comment: Zapfino is a commercial font: quite an expensive one at that. The package just provides support for the font assuming you have the font files. It doesn’t contain the font files.

Answer (score 16):

1. I would not say that it is very nice but probably interesting in terms of coding [Light and matter](http://www.lightandmatter.com/books.html)

[image: LM1]
[image: LM2]
[image: LM3]

---

2. This one is very nice but with no sources [motionmountain](http://www.motionmountain.net/download.html)

[image: MM1]
[image: MM2]
[image: MM3]

Comment: Ad.2: an attempt to reproduce the way the table of contents is built in the [Motion Mountain](http://www.motionmountain.net/index.html) books [can be found in this thread](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/162846/). Despite the presented source code is based on 'article' class, it compiles to something very similar in looks and functionality, including clickable hyperlinks and justified paragraphs. You will also enjoy the fact that unlike the original, the linked solution actually recognizes three levels of section depths.

Answer (score 16):

Shameless plug for my own thesis [*Learning from Samples Using Coherent Lower Previsions*](http://hdl.handle.net/1854/LU-495650), done with `memoir`, `biblatex`, a host of smaller packages, and custom hacking too horrible to share (It’s the layout example that counts).

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Speaking of plugs, here's [my own](http://goo.gl/b1MER) too, typesetted in XeTeX.

Comment: I really like what you did with it, specially the arrow cues to look at recto/verso pages. Care to share how you did it? Or even better, the source code (I'm sure I've done worse things :)

Comment: @AlbertoMiranda: I used `varioref` (it badly interacts with other packages, sadly enough). The basic thing to do is `\renewcommand*{\reftextcurrent}{\unskip}`, `\renewcommand*{\reftextbefore}{\unskip$_\curvearrowleft$}`, `\renewcommand*{\reftextfacebefore}{\unskip}`, and `\renewcommand*{\reftextfaraway}[1]{\unskip\textsubscript{\reallythepageref{#1}}}`, and furthermore `\newcommand*{\reallythepageref}[1]{\hyperref{\getrefbykeydefault{#1}{url}{}}{page}{\getpagerefnumber{#1}}{\pageref*{#1}}}` using `hyperref` and `refcount` (don't remember why).

Comment: I also like what you did! How did you flow the text around figures when they are too wide to be fully put in the margin, like on page 46 or 90? How did you position those images?

Comment: @MarcelKorpel Also with wrapfigure; it allows you to extend into the margin: `\begin{wrapfigure}{o}[\headextend]{0pt}<content>\end{wrapfigure}`, where `\headextend` is appropriately defined. I advise you to read the wrapfigure documentation (in the style file) and play with it a bit to get to know it.

Answer (score 16):

If I may be so bold to also plug my own project, here are some documents created with my TeX macro package "DocScape" (Warning: sometimes large downloads!)

[budget plan of german federal state](http://www.mf.niedersachsen.de/download/64507)

[Lighting Product Catalogue](http://www.erco.com/download/data/10_catalogues/10_catalogue/120_en/en_0_catalogue_2012.pdf)

[Tools Product Catalogue](http://www.wolfcraft.de/workarea/supplier/sWolfcraft/documents/Leaflets/Hauptkatalog_2012_en.pdf)

[Touristic Catalogue](http://flipcat2.giata-web.de/index.php?fc=MTI1MjQ4ODExMHynHW8H50oYK7cnKJQzdTWt9YO/xBmsXp51SFqnb%2bNtqJdcANgfh5bPj5gT5l1Sf6KI2DR0voLsdROot1DjQo7WxtVKalBBSGBhEdoPV6RLb9C/xGuI7Gn9eU4Jz6hppis&xl=1&width=954&height=706)

[Camping Guide](http://www.campingwijzer.nl/campinggidsdownloaden/) (sorry, no direct download link)

[Games Catalogue](http://pdf.akspiele.de/pdf/katalog2009_deu.pdf)

[Newsletter](http://www.epd.de/sites/default/files/pdf/epd-Ost-Wochenspiegel_2011_35.pdf)

While these may not all be highest quality by the typographic standards usually applied to TeX documents (after all, all of them are generated from data bases), they might be stretching a bit the imagination what one would consider to be the typical TeX document :-)

Comment: So how many light years does it take to compile that Erco catalogue?  :)

Comment: LOL In fact they moved more or less entirely to LED technology by now, so their light has to be measured in decades rather than years (you won't believe how much product knowledge one picks up working on such a project ;-)

Comment: I really like the Asia catalogue! Is it completely automatically generated? Wow!

Comment: @jake Well there may be a couple of pages (intro & such) which are not based on database content which have been made by hand and included. But the country and region intros (with the maps) are generated.

Comment: @StephanLehmke: Very impressive! The maps aren't generated automatically within the document generation tool, though?

Comment: @Jake no, they're included as images.

Comment: @StephanLehmke I know this is two years old but I find it pretty hard to believe that the touristic and games catalogues are made in TeX. The text isn't even justified.

Comment: Most of the links give 404. Is it possible to fix the broken links?

Comment: Unfortunately, most of the links are dead. However, I have found some insights on http://www.docscape.de/opencms/web/docscape/de/referenzen/ and http://www.docscape.de/opencms/web/docscape/en/references/.

Answer (score 16):

not really as beautiful, but more careful.

To be publsihed at [Holborn Project](http://www.holbornproject.org) soon!

[image: spread2]

[image: spread1]

Comment: Where can I find this template above?

Answer (score 16):

This will look narcissistic for sure, but here's the current version of my *curriculum vitae*. It's basically a single full-page tikzpicture, compiled with XeLaTeX. Lots of randomized coordinates here and there (I got slightly influenced by the interface of the game *Persona 5*).

[image: screenshot of the document]

I recreated the union jack by hand for fun (you can choose between 1:2 and 3:5 ratios and the width of the stripes and stuff remains correct):

```
\newcommand{\unionjack}{%
    \begingroup%
        \def\urationum{3}%
        \def\uratioden{5}%
        \def\uheight{2ex}%
        \definecolor{ublue}{RGB}{0, 39, 118}%
        \definecolor{ured}{RGB}{198, 12, 48}%
        \colorlet{uwhite}{white}%
        \begin{tikzpicture}[
                    draw = none,
                    line width = 0pt
                ]
            \coordinate (sw) at (0, 0);
            \coordinate (nw) at (0, \uheight);
            \coordinate (ne) at (\uheight * \uratioden / \urationum, \uheight);
            \coordinate (se) at (\uheight * \uratioden / \urationum, 0);
            \clip (sw) rectangle (ne);
            \fill[ublue] (sw) rectangle (ne);
            %
            \coordinate (nwsebegtop) at ($(nw)!\uheight / 10!90:(se)$);
            \coordinate (nwsebegbot) at ($(nw)!\uheight / 10!-90:(se)$);
            \coordinate (nwseendtop) at ($(se)!\uheight / 10!-90:(nw)$);
            \coordinate (nwseendbot) at ($(se)!\uheight / 10!90:(nw)$);
            \fill[uwhite]
                (nwsebegtop) -- (nwsebegbot) -- (nwseendbot)
                -- (nwseendtop) -- cycle;
            \coordinate (swnebegtop) at ($(sw)!\uheight / 10!90:(ne)$);
            \coordinate (swnebegbot) at ($(sw)!\uheight / 10!-90:(ne)$);
            \coordinate (swneendtop) at ($(ne)!\uheight / 10!-90:(sw)$);
            \coordinate (swneendbot) at ($(ne)!\uheight / 10!90:(sw)$);
            \fill[uwhite]
                (swnebegtop) -- (swnebegbot) -- (swneendbot)
                -- (swneendtop) -- cycle;
            %
            \begin{scope}
                \clip (nw) -- (ne) -- (sw) -- cycle;
                \coordinate (nwsebegtopred) at (nw);
                \coordinate (nwsebegbotred) at ($(nw)!\uheight / 30 * 2!-90:(se)$);
                \coordinate (nwseendtopred) at (se);
                \coordinate (nwseendbotred) at ($(se)!\uheight / 30 * 2!90:(nw)$);
                \fill[ured]
                    (nwsebegtopred) -- (nwsebegbotred) -- (nwseendbotred)
                    -- (nwseendtopred) -- cycle;
            \end{scope}
            \begin{scope}
                \clip (sw) -- (se) -- (ne) -- cycle;
                \coordinate (nwsebegtopred) at ($(nw)!\uheight / 30 * 2!90:(se)$);
                \coordinate (nwsebegbotred) at (nw);
                \coordinate (nwseendtopred) at ($(se)!\uheight / 30 * 2!-90:(nw)$);
                \coordinate (nwseendbotred) at (se);
                \fill[ured]
                    (nwsebegtopred) -- (nwsebegbotred) -- (nwseendbotred)
                    -- (nwseendtopred) -- cycle;
            \end{scope}
            \begin{scope}
                \clip (sw) -- (se) -- (nw) -- cycle;
                \coordinate (swnebegtopred) at (sw);
                \coordinate (swnebegbotred) at ($(sw)!\uheight / 30 * 2!-90:(ne)$);
                \coordinate (swneendtopred) at (ne);
                \coordinate (swneendbotred) at ($(ne)!\uheight / 30 * 2!90:(sw)$);
                \fill[ured]
                    (swnebegtopred) -- (swnebegbotred) -- (swneendbotred)
                    -- (swneendtopred) -- cycle;
            \end{scope}
            \begin{scope}
                \clip (nw) -- (se) -- (ne) -- cycle;
                \coordinate (swnebegtopred) at ($(sw)!\uheight / 30 * 2!90:(ne)$);
                \coordinate (swnebegbotred) at (sw);
                \coordinate (swneendtopred) at ($(ne)!\uheight / 30 * 2!-90:(sw)$);
                \coordinate (swneendbotred) at (ne);
                \fill[ured]
                    (swnebegtopred) -- (swnebegbotred) -- (swneendbotred)
                    -- (swneendtopred) -- cycle;
            \end{scope}
            %
            \coordinate (n) at ($(nw)!0.5!(ne)$);
            \coordinate (s) at ($(sw)!0.5!(se)$);
            \fill[uwhite]
                ($(nw)!1/3!(sw)$) -- ($(ne)!1/3!(se)$)
                -- ($(se)!1/3!(ne)$) -- ($(sw)!1/3!(nw)$) -- cycle;
            \fill[uwhite]
                ($(s)!\uheight / 6!90:(n)$)
                -- ($(s)!\uheight / 6!-90:(n)$)
                -- ($(n)!\uheight / 6!90:(s)$)
                -- ($(n)!\uheight / 6!-90:(s)$)
                -- cycle;
            \fill[ured]
                ($(nw)!2/5!(sw)$) -- ($(ne)!2/5!(se)$)
                -- ($(se)!2/5!(ne)$) -- ($(sw)!2/5!(nw)$) -- cycle;
            \fill[ured]
                ($(s)!\uheight / 10!90:(n)$)
                -- ($(s)!\uheight / 10!-90:(n)$)
                -- ($(n)!\uheight / 10!90:(s)$)
                -- ($(n)!\uheight / 10!-90:(s)$)
                -- cycle;
        \end{tikzpicture}%
    \endgroup%
}
```

The weird fuzziness of the header's background was obtained by mistake, by asking for random steps as a decoration (`decorate, decoration = {random steps, segment length = 2pt, amplitude = 1.5pt}`) and setting `rounded corners` to a high value (`8pt`, which is far more than the length of the steps). I liked the result and kept it after a few tweaks.

The lists' bullets are two circles filled in an even / odd fashion:

```
\newcommand{\bulcircsz}{0.65ex}
\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \fill[
            even odd rule,
            lighter!75
        ]
            (0, 0) circle (\bulcircsz)
            (\bulcircsz*0.525, \bulcircsz*0.45) circle (\bulcircsz);
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}
```

And here's the code for the stars (this is far from perfect, though):

```
\newcommand{\starwidth}{1em}
% Maximal number of stars.
\newcommand{\starnumber}{3}

% Stars with #1 filled.
\newcommand*{\stars}[1]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
                scale = 1,
                x = \starwidth,
                y = \starwidth,
                every node/.style = {
                    draw = maincolour,
                    line width = 0.75pt,
                    star,
                    star points = 5,
                    star point ratio = 2,
                    minimum width = \starwidth * 0.95,
                    text width = 0pt,
                    inner sep = 0pt,
                    rounded corners = 0.5pt,
                    anchor = center
                },
                baseline = {([yshift = 0.15ex] current bounding box.south)}
            ]
        \foreach \k in {1, ..., \starnumber}
            \node (s\k) at (\k, 0) {};
        \clip (current bounding box.south west) rectangle (#1 + 0.5, 0.5);
        \foreach \k in {1, ..., \starnumber}
            \node[fill = maincolour!50] at (\k, 0) {};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}
```

Damn, my post is long. Is there no way to put stuff (especially code) in a little “spoiler” thingy?

Answer (score 16):

Just finished writing my PhD thesis, which is written using the `memoir` class and all figures are drawn using `TikZ`. The PDF is available on http://kth.diva-portal.org/smash/get/diva2:1185339/FULLTEXT03.pdf, and the source code is freely available on https://github.com/gablin/ghb-thesis.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 15):

> If you were asked to show examples of beautifully typeset documents in LaTeX, what would you suggest?

[This](http://www.ctan.org/documents/bcs/bcs.pdf) is my rendering of a long-ago torture test of technical text (say that three times fast!).

[image: benchmark1]
[image: benchmark2]

I think the technical material came out fine-looking, certainly up to anyone's professional standards, but the biggest point for me is that getting LaTeX to do it was straightforward.

Personally, when I was first shown some of the wonderful things that TeX could put out I was amazed at what other people could do.  But when I saw the original version of this document in the AMS Notices then I was delighted at what *I* could do.  :-)

> Preferably documents available online ... Extra bonus for documents whose LaTeX source is available.

Yes, in the same directory.

Comment: The link does not work.

Comment: Dunno.  Works for me now.

Comment: @JimHefferon: The link is still broken.

Comment: The following link seems to have the document, plus a zip of the source. I'm on an iPad so couldn't check the source. http://joshua.smcvt.edu/bcs/

Answer (score 15):

I had to make a large poster for a conference and I used the style file `baposter` ([link](http://www.brian-amberg.de/uni/poster/)) to do it. Here's a preview:

[image: Poster]

The options look like:

```
\begin{poster}%
  % Poster Options
  {
  % Show grid to help with alignment
  grid=no,
  % Column spacing
  colspacing=1em,
  % Color style
  bgColorOne=lighteryellow,
  bgColorTwo=lightestyellow,
  borderColor=reddishyellow,
  headerColorOne=yellow,
  headerColorTwo=reddishyellow,
  headerFontColor=black,
  boxColorOne=lightyellow,
  boxColorTwo=lighteryellow,
  % Format of textbox
  %textborder=roundedleft,
  textborder =rounded,
%  textborder=rectangle,
  % Format of text header
  eyecatcher=no,
  headerborder=open,
  headerheight=0.14\textheight,
  headershape=roundedright,
  headershade=plain,
  headerfont=\Large\textsf, %Sans Serif
  boxshade=plain,
%  background=shade-tb,
  background=plain,
  linewidth=2pt
  }
```

The **PDF version** can be downloaded [**here**](http://bedienhaptik.files.wordpress.com/2014/06/haptic-perception-of-viscous-friction-of-rotary-switches_poster.pdf).

You place the boxes using relative coordinates such as `below contribution` (where `contribution` is the name of a box). Here's a example:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
  \headerbox{\bfseries Results}{name=Results,column=0,span=2,above=Procedure,below=Contribution}{
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

Answer (score 15):

While studying engineering mechanics I’ve come across a beautiful integral combination chart (german “Koppeltafel”) that is used to calculate the integral of two given functions multiplied. Sadly it was a bad quality scan. So I rebuilt the whole thing with lots of attention to detail in the math and the drawings and using accurate graphs. The LaTeX / TikZ code is approx. 1000 lines long and at some points I even use custom symbols embedded as pdf files (e.g. the `\ell` is customized).

[PDF download here](http://lucasbosch.de/latex/koppeltafel.pdf)

[image: integrals combination chart]

Answer (score 14):

Check this out. Reply if you want the TeX file or instructions.

[image]

Comment: Well if you have the source code couldn't you just post it? I, for sure, am interested :-)

Comment: I second that thought.

Comment: Its nice, please share the code

Comment: Beautiful, please share the source code.

Answer (score 13):

This is only somewhat related, but Springer lets you search their journals for strings of latex.  This can help you understand how to format certain commands (and decide whether it is done well or not):
http://www.latexsearch.com/

Answer (score 13):

Some of you may be interested in [*Cours d’analyse*](http://cel.archives-ouvertes.fr/cel-00519301/fr/) although it is far from being as fancy as some of documents already mentioned. It is a bit too dense and comments are welcome. The final code is probably very nasty. Anyway.

Comment: +1 for CC licensed. I also love the use of orange hues in the document. Really great.

Comment: I do appreciate, even if I agree about the density of the text... *et que cela ne me rappelle pas que des bons souvenirs de prépa !* Anyway, I'd like to know more about the way you achieve the rendering of *Exercices* or *Lemmes* blocks!

Comment: This is inspired by The Legrand Orange Book.

Answer (score 13):

A good comparison of MS Word vs. LaTex was done by [Matthias Mühlich](https://web.archive.org/web/20121019140251/http://user.uni-frankfurt.de/~muehlich/tex/wordvslatex.html) who wrote twice the same text (without any formula or table or anything one expects LaTex to shine) in both formats and converted them to pdf.

Just print out [1](https://web.archive.org/web/20120710212232/http://user.uni-frankfurt.de/~muehlich/tex/Word-LaTeX-Vergleich1.pdf) and [2](https://web.archive.org/web/20120710212244/http://user.uni-frankfurt.de/~muehlich/tex/Word-LaTeX-Vergleich2.pdf), and decide for yourself.

[image]

Comment: I love this explicit juxtaposition of the results. It speaks for itself!

Comment: Indeed, with a good use of interline spacing, I think that World could do in this case a good job too.

Comment: @projetmbc Could do, yes. But isn't part of the point what the default looks like? I'm guessing that the LaTeX version is not far from default - presumably `babel` or something must be loaded with German hyphenation, and it is using type1 fonts rather than the defaults, but I doubt there is much by way of tweaking line spacing going on. And it is not just the line spacing - it is also the line breaks and lack of hyphenation in the Word version. But I would for sure be interested to see what this looks like with Word's current defaults. (At least the font would differ.)

Answer (score 13):

I just picked these three from our archives.

- Matthew Mac Namara, La Textualisation de Madame Bovary, Rodopi, New York, 2004, 9042009845

[image: Page from the transcription of Flaubert's manuscript, collating the notes to show the sequence of authorial progress]

- [Carlo Collodi], Éachtra Phinocchio, tr. Pádraig Ó Buachalla, ed Seán Ó Suilleabháin ⁊ Dáibhí Ó Cróinín, Random House / Coiste Litriochta Mhuscrai, 2nd ed, 2003, 0954455401

[image: Chapter 2 of Pinocchio (in Irish). This edition was typeset to fit exactly the page layout and numbering of all the other language versions, with the images added afterwards by the printer. The challenge was that the Irish language version contains many more words than any other version!]

- Seán Connolly, Bede: On The Temple, Liverpool University Press, 1995, B001DP4V3S

[image: A page from the analysis of Bede's book, with an authorial requirement that the footnote contained a triangular arrany of numbers.]

Comment: Any chance Pinocchio's adventures could be typeset using the 'eiad' characters ( irish alphabet to the uninitiated)...

Comment: I don't see why not, but Yannis' decorative initial would probably be better replaced with a different one. The problem with that edition was that we were constrained to keep the same illustrations on the same pages in the same place as all the other language editions, which meant a lot of fiddling with point sizes of text to make it fall in the right places. I'd have to do the same with the eiad font. I'll have a look. [edit] I would of course have to check with the editor about copyright before I could actually distribute it.

Answer (score 13):

I'm working on an etymological approach of the Wycliffe's translation of the Bible to English language.

The project's been written mostly in `lua` and compiled with `LuaLaTeX` engine, and can be checked here: [The Wycliffe Holy Bible Project](https://github.com/LevyMarfim/Wycliffe_Holy_Bible).

[image: Fist sprite]

[image: Second sprite]

Answer (score 12):

A page from class notes I used to teach differential equations. Figure created with `pgfplots`. Colors are easily matched with color definitions. Done with a humble experience/knowledge in LaTeX.

[image: class notes]

Comment: Nice! Is the source available?

Comment: For 'pgfplots'?

Comment: Would you be willing to share the code for your class notes? I am very interested in the plots. Bu the book code would also be very useful. THANKS!!!

Answer (score 12):

([Pentagonal tiling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentagonal_tiling))

I draw 15 type of pentagonal tiling.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[line join=round,scale=1.1]
\foreach \x in {0,3,6,9,12,15} 
    \draw[line width=1pt,pink] (0,\x) -- (9,\x);
\foreach \x in {0,3,6,9}
    \draw[line width=1pt,pink] (\x,0) -- (\x,15);
\draw[line width=1pt,pink] (0,0) -- (9,0) -- (9,15) -- (0,15) -- cycle;  

\foreach \x in {0,3,6} 
  \foreach \y in {3,6,...,15}
  \draw[pink,line width=1pt] (\x,\y-.3) rectangle (\x+.3,\y);


\draw[pink,line width=1pt] (.15,2.85)  node {\tiny $1$}; 
\draw[pink,line width=1pt] (3.15,2.85)  node {\tiny $2$}; 
\draw[pink,line width=1pt] (6.15,2.85)  node {\tiny $3$}; 


\draw[pink,line width=1pt] (.15,5.85)  node {\tiny $4$}; 
\draw[pink,line width=1pt] (3.15,5.85)  node {\tiny $5$}; 
\draw[pink,line width=1pt] (6.15,5.85)  node {\tiny $6$}; 

\draw[pink,line width=1pt] (.15,8.85)  node {\tiny $7$}; 
\draw[pink,line width=1pt] (3.15,8.85)  node {\tiny $8$}; 
\draw[pink,line width=1pt] (6.15,8.85)  node {\tiny $9$};

\draw[pink,line width=1pt] (.15,11.85)  node {\tiny $10$}; 
\draw[pink,line width=1pt] (3.15,11.85)  node {\tiny $11$}; 
\draw[pink,line width=1pt] (6.15,11.85)  node {\tiny $12$};

\draw[pink,line width=1pt] (.15,14.85)  node {\tiny $13$}; 
\draw[pink,line width=1pt] (3.15,14.85)  node {\tiny $14$}; 
\draw[pink,line width=1pt] (6.15,14.85)  node {\tiny $15$};


    \draw (1.5,1.5) node {
%%%%%%Pentagon Type 1
\begin{tikzpicture}[line join=round,line width=1.2pt,scale=.5]
\begin{tiny}
\draw (0,0) coordinate (A) node[below] {$A$};
\draw ($ (A) + (15:27mm) $) coordinate (B) node[right] {$B$};
\draw ($(B)!26mm!-67:(A)$) coordinate (C) node[above] {$C$};
\draw ($(C)!11mm!-113:(B)$) coordinate (D) node [left] {$D$};
\draw ($(D)!17mm!-125:(C)$) coordinate (E) node [left] {$E$};

\draw[fill=yellow!20,yellow!20] (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- (D) -- (E) -- cycle;


\draw [pink] (A) -- (B) node[pos=.5,below] {$b$};
\draw [blue](B) -- (C) node[pos=.5,above right] {$c$};
\draw [green](C) -- (D) node[pos=.5,above] {$d$};
\draw (D) -- (E) node[pos=.5,left] {$e$};
\draw[red](E) -- (A) node[pos=.5,below left] {$a$};

\draw[fill] (A) circle (.6pt); 
\draw[fill] (B) circle (.6pt);
\draw[fill] (C) circle (.6pt);
\draw[fill] (D) circle (.6pt);
\draw[fill] (E) circle (.6pt);


\draw (1,-.9) node{$\widehat{B}+\widehat{C}=180^\circ$};
\draw (1,-1.5) node{$\widehat{A}+\widehat{D}+\widehat{E}=360^\circ$};
\end{tiny}


\end{tikzpicture}    
    };

\draw (4.5,1.5) node {%
%%%%%%Pentagon Type 2
\begin{tikzpicture}[line join=round,line width=1.2pt,scale=.5]
\begin{tiny}
\draw (0,0) coordinate (A) node[below] {$A$};
\draw ($ (A) + (25:15mm) $) coordinate (B) node[right] {$B$};
\draw ($(B)!14mm!-120:(A)$) coordinate (C) node[above] {$C$};
\draw ($(C)!30mm!-95:(B)$) coordinate (D) node [left] {$D$};
\draw ($(D)!14mm!-60:(C)$) coordinate (E) node [left] {$E$};

\draw[fill=yellow!20,yellow!20] (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- (D) -- (E) -- cycle;


\draw [pink] (A) -- (B) node[pos=.5,below] {$b$};
\draw [blue](B) -- (C) node[pos=.5,right] {$c$};
\draw [green](C) -- (D) node[pos=.5,above] {$d$};
\draw [blue](D) -- (E) node[pos=.5,left] {$e$};
\draw[red](E) -- (A) node[pos=.5,below left] {$a$};

\draw[fill] (A) circle (.6pt); 
\draw[fill] (B) circle (.6pt);
\draw[fill] (C) circle (.6pt);
\draw[fill] (D) circle (.6pt);
\draw[fill] (E) circle (.6pt);


\draw (.4,-.9) node{$c=e$};
\draw (.4,-1.5) node{$\widehat{B}+\widehat{D}=180^\circ$};
\end{tiny}


\end{tikzpicture}
};
\draw (7.5,1.5) node {%
%%%%%%Pentagon Type 3
\begin{tikzpicture}[line join=round,line width=1.2pt,scale=.5]
\begin{tiny}
\draw (0,0) coordinate (A) node[below] {$A$};
\draw ($ (A) + (-18:24mm) $) coordinate (B) node[below] {$B$};
\draw ($(B)!8mm!-105:(A)$) coordinate (C) node[right] {$C$};
\draw ($(C)!26mm!-120:(B)$) coordinate (D) node [above] {$D$};
\draw ($(D)!18mm!-120:(C)$) coordinate (E) node [left] {$E$};

\draw ($(C)!8mm!-120:(B)$) coordinate (BC);



\draw[fill=yellow!20,yellow!20] (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- (D) -- (E) -- cycle;


\draw [pink] (A) -- (B) node[pos=.5,below] {$b$};
\draw [blue](B) -- (C) node[pos=.5,below right] {$c$};
\draw [green](C) -- (D) node[pos=.5,above right] {$d$};
\draw (D) -- (E) node[pos=.5,above] {$e$};
\draw[pink](E) -- (A) node[pos=.5,below left] {$a$};

\draw[blue] (C) -- (BC);
\draw (D) -- (BC);

\draw[fill] (A) circle (.6pt); 
\draw[fill] (B) circle (.6pt);
\draw[fill] (C) circle (.6pt);
\draw[fill] (D) circle (.6pt);
\draw[fill] (E) circle (.6pt);

\draw[fill] (BC) circle (.6pt);

\draw (1,-1.5) node{$a=b,\;d=c+e$};
\draw (1,-2.2) node{$\widehat{A}=\widehat{C}=\widehat{D}=120^\circ$};
\end{tiny}


\end{tikzpicture}
};


\draw (1.5,4.5) node {%
%%%%%%Pentagon Type 4
\begin{tikzpicture}[line join=round,line width=1.2pt,scale=.5]
\begin{tiny}
\draw (0,0) coordinate (A) node[left] {$A$};
\draw ($ (A) + (-90:11mm) $) coordinate (B) node[below] {$B$};
\draw ($(B)!11mm!-90:(A)$) coordinate (C) node[below] {$C$};
\draw ($(C)!22mm!-140:(B)$) coordinate (D) node [right] {$D$};
\draw ($(D)!22mm!-90:(C)$) coordinate (E) node [above] {$E$};

\draw[fill=yellow!20,yellow!20] (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- (D) -- (E) -- cycle;


\draw [pink] (A) -- (B) node[pos=.5,left] {$b$};
\draw [pink] (B) -- (C) node[pos=.5,below] {$c$};
\draw [blue] (C) -- (D) node[pos=.5,below right] {$d$};
\draw [blue] (D) -- (E) node[pos=.5,above right] {$e$};
\draw   (E) -- (A) node[pos=.5,left] {$a$};

\draw[fill] (A) circle (.6pt); 
\draw[fill] (B) circle (.6pt);
\draw[fill] (C) circle (.6pt);
\draw[fill] (D) circle (.6pt);
\draw[fill] (E) circle (.6pt);


\draw (1,-1.9) node{$b=c,\;d=e$};
\draw (1,-2.5) node{$\widehat{B}=\widehat{D}=90^\circ$};
\end{tiny}


\end{tikzpicture}
};
\draw (4.5,4.5) node {%
%%%%%%Pentagon Type 5
\begin{tikzpicture}[line join=round,line width=1.2pt,scale=.5]
\begin{tiny}
\draw (0,0) coordinate (A) node[below] {$A$};
\draw ($ (A) + (0:29mm) $) coordinate (B) node[below] {$B$};
\draw ($(B)!7mm!-120:(A)$) coordinate (C) node[right] {$C$};
\draw ($(C)!15mm!-135:(B)$) coordinate (D) node [right] {$D$};
\draw ($(D)!15mm!-120:(C)$) coordinate (E) node [above] {$E$};

\draw[fill=yellow!20,yellow!20] (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- (D) -- (E) -- cycle;


\draw [pink] (A) -- (B) node[pos=.5,below] {$b$};
\draw (B) -- (C) node[pos=.5,below right] {$c$};
\draw [blue](C) -- (D) node[pos=.5,right] {$d$};
\draw [blue](D) -- (E) node[pos=.5,above] {$e$};
\draw[pink](E) -- (A) node[pos=.5,left] {$a$};

\draw[fill] (A) circle (.6pt); 
\draw[fill] (B) circle (.6pt);
\draw[fill] (C) circle (.6pt);
\draw[fill] (D) circle (.6pt);
\draw[fill] (E) circle (.6pt);


\draw (1.2,-.9) node{$a=b,\;d=e$};
\draw (1.2,-1.5) node{$\widehat{A}=60^\circ,\;\widehat{D}=120^\circ$};
\end{tiny}


\end{tikzpicture}
};
\draw (7.5,4.5) node {%
%%%%%%Pentagon Type 6
\begin{tikzpicture}[line join=round,line width=1.2pt,scale=.6]
\begin{tiny}
\draw (0,0) coordinate (A) node[below] {$A$};
\draw ($ (A) + (0:22mm) $) coordinate (B) node[below] {$B$};
\draw ($(B)!22mm!-40:(A)$) coordinate (C) node[above] {$C$};
\draw ($(C)!9mm!-125:(B)$) coordinate (D) node [above] {$D$};
\draw ($(D)!9mm!-140:(C)$) coordinate (E) node [left] {$E$};

\draw[fill=yellow!20,yellow!20] (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- (D) -- (E) -- cycle;


\draw [pink] (A) -- (B) node[pos=.5,below] {$b$};
\draw [blue](B) -- (C) node[pos=.5,above right] {$c$};
\draw [blue](C) -- (D) node[pos=.5,above] {$d$};
\draw [pink](D) -- (E) node[pos=.5,left] {$e$};
\draw[pink](E) -- (A) node[pos=.5,below left] {$a$};

\draw[fill] (A) circle (.6pt); 
\draw[fill] (B) circle (.6pt);
\draw[fill] (C) circle (.6pt);
\draw[fill] (D) circle (.6pt);
\draw[fill] (E) circle (.6pt);


\draw (.8,-.9) node{$a=d=e,\;b=c$};
\draw (.8,-1.5) node{$\widehat{B}+\widehat{D}=180^\circ,\;2\widehat{B}=\widehat{E}$};
\end{tiny}


\end{tikzpicture}

};


\draw (1.5,7.5) node {%
%%%%%%Pentagon Type 7
\begin{tikzpicture}[line join=round,line width=1.2pt,scale=.5]
\begin{tiny}
\draw (0,0) coordinate (A) node[below] {$A$};
\draw ($ (A) + (0:17mm) $) coordinate (B) node[below] {$B$};
\draw ($(B)!17mm!-140:(A)$) coordinate (C) node[right] {$C$};
\draw ($(C)!17mm!-135:(B)$) coordinate (D) node [above] {$D$};
\draw ($(D)!17mm!-90:(C)$) coordinate (E) node [above] {$E$};

\draw[fill=yellow!20,yellow!20] (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- (D) -- (E) -- cycle;


\draw [pink] (A) -- (B) node[pos=.5,below] {$b$};
\draw [pink](B) -- (C) node[pos=.5,below right] {$c$};
\draw [pink](C) -- (D) node[pos=.5,right] {$d$};
\draw [pink](D) -- (E) node[pos=.5,above] {$e$};
\draw[blue](E) -- (A) node[pos=.5,left] {$a$};

\draw[fill] (A) circle (.6pt); 
\draw[fill] (B) circle (.6pt);
\draw[fill] (C) circle (.6pt);
\draw[fill] (D) circle (.6pt);
\draw[fill] (E) circle (.6pt);


\draw (1,-.9) node{$b=c=d=e$};
\draw (1,-1.6) node{$\widehat{B}+2\widehat{E}=2\widehat{C}+\widehat{D}=360^\circ$};
\end{tiny}


\end{tikzpicture}
};
\draw (4.5,7.5) node {%
%%%%%%Pentagon Type 8
\begin{tikzpicture}[line join=round,line width=1.2pt,scale=.4]
\begin{tiny}
\draw (0,0) coordinate (A) node[below] {$A$};
\draw ($ (A) + (0:22mm) $) coordinate (B) node[below] {$B$};
\draw ($(B)!22mm!-110:(A)$) coordinate (C) node[right] {$C$};
\draw ($(C)!22mm!-140:(B)$) coordinate (D) node [above] {$D$};
\draw ($(D)!22mm!-70:(C)$) coordinate (E) node [left] {$E$};

\draw[fill=yellow!20,yellow!20] (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- (D) -- (E) -- cycle;


\draw [pink] (A) -- (B) node[pos=.5,below] {$b$};
\draw [pink](B) -- (C) node[pos=.5,right] {$c$};
\draw [pink](C) -- (D) node[pos=.5,right] {$d$};
\draw [pink](D) -- (E) node[pos=.5,above left] {$e$};
\draw[blue](E) -- (A) node[pos=.5,left] {$a$};

\draw[fill] (A) circle (.6pt); 
\draw[fill] (B) circle (.6pt);
\draw[fill] (C) circle (.6pt);
\draw[fill] (D) circle (.6pt);
\draw[fill] (E) circle (.6pt);


\draw (1,-.9) node{$b=c=d=e$};
\draw (1,-1.6) node{$2\widehat{B}+\widehat{C}=\widehat{D}+2\widehat{E}=360^\circ$};
\end{tiny}


\end{tikzpicture}
};
\draw (7.5,7.5) node {%
%%%%%%Pentagon Type 9
\begin{tikzpicture}[line join=round,line width=1.2pt,scale=.4]
\begin{tiny}
\draw (0,0) coordinate (A) node[below] {$A$};
\draw ($ (A) + (0:25mm) $) coordinate (B) node[below] {$B$};
\draw ($(B)!25mm!-75:(A)$) coordinate (C) node[right] {$C$};
\draw ($(C)!25mm!-150:(B)$) coordinate (D) node [above] {$D$};
\draw ($(D)!25mm!-60:(C)$) coordinate (E) node [left] {$E$};

\draw[fill=yellow!20,yellow!20] (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- (D) -- (E) -- cycle;


\draw [pink] (A) -- (B) node[pos=.5,below] {$b$};
\draw [pink](B) -- (C) node[pos=.5,right] {$c$};
\draw [pink](C) -- (D) node[pos=.5,above right] {$d$};
\draw [pink](D) -- (E) node[pos=.5,left] {$e$};
\draw[blue](E) -- (A) node[pos=.5,left] {$a$};

\draw[fill] (A) circle (.6pt); 
\draw[fill] (B) circle (.6pt);
\draw[fill] (C) circle (.6pt);
\draw[fill] (D) circle (.6pt);
\draw[fill] (E) circle (.6pt);


\draw (1,-1) node{$b=c=d=e$};
\draw (1,-1.7) node{$2\widehat{A}+\widehat{C}=\widehat{D}+2\widehat{E}=360^\circ$};
\end{tiny}


\end{tikzpicture}
};


\draw (1.5,10.5) node {%
%%%%%%Pentagon Type 10
\begin{tikzpicture}[line join=round,line width=1.2pt,scale=.5]
\begin{tiny}
\draw (0,0) coordinate (A) node[below] {$A$};
\draw ($ (A) + (0:29.9mm) $) coordinate (B) node[below] {$B$};
\draw ($(B)!6mm!-110:(A)$) coordinate (C) node[right] {$C$};
\draw ($(C)!18mm!-125:(B)$) coordinate (D) node [right] {$D$};
\draw ($(D)!23mm!-145:(C)$) coordinate (E) node [above] {$E$};

\draw ($ (A) + (0:23mm) $) coordinate (AA);
\draw ($(A) + (90:6mm)$) coordinate (EE);

\draw[fill=yellow!20,yellow!20] (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- (D) -- (E) -- cycle;


\draw [pink] (A) -- (B) node[pos=.5,below] {$b$};
\draw [blue](B) -- (C) node[pos=.5,below right] {$c$};
\draw [pink](C) -- (D) node[pos=.5,right] {$d$};
\draw [pink](D) -- (E) node[pos=.5,above] {$e$};
\draw[white](E) -- (A) node[pos=.5,left] {\color{pink} $a$};


\draw[pink] (A) -- (AA);
\draw[blue] (B) -- (AA);
\draw (C) -- (D); 
\draw[pink] (D) -- (E);
\draw[pink] (E) -- (EE); 
\draw[blue] (A) -- (EE);

\draw[fill] (A) circle (.6pt); 
\draw[fill] (B) circle (.6pt);
\draw[fill] (C) circle (.6pt);
\draw[fill] (D) circle (.6pt);
\draw[fill] (E) circle (.6pt);

\draw[fill] (AA) circle (.6pt);
\draw[fill] (EE) circle (.6pt);

\draw (1.3,-.9) node{$a=b=c+e$};
\draw (1.3,-1.55) node{$\widehat{A}=90^\circ,\;\widehat{B}+\widehat{E}=180^\circ$};
\draw (1.3,-2.2) node{
$\widehat{B}+2\widehat{C}=360^\circ$};
\end{tiny}


\end{tikzpicture}

};
\draw (4.5,10.5) node {%
%%%%%%Pentagon Type 11
\begin{tikzpicture}[line join=round,line width=1.2pt,scale=.7]
\begin{tiny}
\draw (0,0) coordinate (A) node[below] {$A$};
\draw ($ (A) + (0:23.4mm) $) coordinate (B) node[below] {$B$};
\draw ($(B)!9mm!-150:(A)$) coordinate (C) node[right] {$C$};
\draw ($(C)!18mm!-60:(B)$) coordinate (D) node [above] {$D$};
\draw ($(D)!18mm!-120:(C)$) coordinate (E) node [above] {$E$};


\draw ($(C)!9mm!-60:(B)$) coordinate (CC);
\draw ($(CC)!4.5mm!0:(D)$ ) coordinate (CCC);
\draw ($(D)!4.5mm!0:(E)$) coordinate (DD);
\draw ($(DD)!4.5mm!0:(E)$) coordinate (DDD);



\draw[fill=yellow!20,yellow!20] (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- (D) -- (E) -- cycle;


\draw (A) -- (B) node[pos=.5,below] {$b$};
\draw [pink](B) -- (C) node[pos=.5,below right] {$c$};
\draw [pink](C) -- (D) node[pos=.5,above] {$d$};
\draw [pink](D) -- (E) node[pos=.5,above] {$e$};
\draw[blue](E) -- (A) node[pos=.5,left] {$a$};


\draw[blue] (D) -- (DD);
\draw[blue] (DDD) -- (DD);
\draw[blue] (CC) -- (CCC);
\draw[blue] (CCC) -- (D);


\draw[fill] (A) circle (.6pt); 
\draw[fill] (B) circle (.6pt);
\draw[fill] (C) circle (.6pt);
\draw[fill] (D) circle (.6pt);
\draw[fill] (E) circle (.6pt);






\draw[fill] (CC) circle (.6pt);
\draw[fill] (CCC) circle (.6pt);
\draw[fill] (DD) circle (.6pt);
\draw[fill] (DDD) circle (.6pt); 



\draw (1.5,-.8) node {$2a+c=d=e$ };
\draw (1.5,-1.45) node {$\widehat{A}=90^\circ,\;2\widehat{B}+\widehat{C}=360^\circ$};
\draw (1.5,-2.1) node {$\widehat{C}+\widehat{E}=180^\circ$};
\end{tiny}


\end{tikzpicture}
};
\draw (7.5,10.5) node {%
%%%%%%Pentagon Type 12
\begin{tikzpicture}[line join=round,line width=1.2pt,scale=.6]
\begin{tiny}
\draw (0,0) coordinate (A) node[below] {$A$};
\draw ($ (A) + (0:15mm) $) coordinate (B) node[below] {$B$};
\draw ($(B)!17mm!-155:(A)$) coordinate (C) node[right] {$C$};
\draw ($(C)!26mm!-50:(B)$) coordinate (D) node [above] {$D$};
\draw ($(D)!9mm!-115:(C)$) coordinate (E) node [left] {$E$};

\draw ($(C)!17mm! 0:(D)$) coordinate (CC);


\draw[fill=yellow!20,yellow!20] (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- (D) -- (E) -- cycle;


\draw  (A) -- (B) node[pos=.5,below] {$b$};
\draw [pink](B) -- (C) node[pos=.5,below] {$c$};
\draw [pink](C) -- (D) node[pos=.5,above] {$d$};
\draw [pink](D) -- (E) node[pos=.5,above left] {$e$};
\draw[green](E) -- (A) node[pos=.5,left] {$a$};

\draw[pink] (C) -- (CC);
\draw[blue] (CC) -- (D);
\draw[blue] (D) -- (E);


\draw[fill] (A) circle (.6pt); 
\draw[fill] (B) circle (.6pt);
\draw[fill] (C) circle (.6pt);
\draw[fill] (D) circle (.6pt);
\draw[fill] (E) circle (.6pt);

\draw[fill] (CC) circle (.6pt);

\draw (1.4,-.9) node{$2a=d=c+e$};
\draw (1.4,-1.55) node{$\widehat{A}=90^\circ,\;2\widehat{B}+\widehat{C}=360^\circ$}; 
\draw (1.4,-2.2) node{$\widehat{C}+\widehat{E}=180^\circ$};
\end{tiny}


\end{tikzpicture}
};


\draw (1.5,13.5) node {%
%%%%%%Pentagon Type 13
\begin{tikzpicture}[line join=round,line width=1.2pt,scale=.6]
\begin{tiny}
\draw (0,0) coordinate (A) node[below] {$A$};
\draw ($ (A) + (0:25mm) $) coordinate (B) node[below] {$B$};
\draw ($(B)!4.5mm!-90:(A)$) coordinate (C) node[above] {$C$};
\draw ($(C)!24mm!-120:(B)$) coordinate (D) node [above] {$D$};
\draw ($(D)!12mm!-120:(C)$) coordinate (E) node [left] {$E$};

\draw ($(C)!12mm!0:(D)$) coordinate (CC);

\draw[fill=yellow!20,yellow!20] (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- (D) -- (E) -- cycle;


\draw  (A) -- (B) node[pos=.5,below] {$b$};
\draw [blue](B) -- (C) node[pos=.5,right] {$c$};
\draw [pink](C) -- (D) node[pos=.5,above] {$d$};
\draw [pink](D) -- (E) node[pos=.5,above] {$e$};
\draw[pink](E) -- (A) node[pos=.5,below left] {$a$};

\draw[fill] (A) circle (.6pt); 
\draw[fill] (B) circle (.6pt);
\draw[fill] (C) circle (.6pt);
\draw[fill] (D) circle (.6pt);
\draw[fill] (E) circle (.6pt);

\draw[fill] (CC) circle (.6pt);

\draw (1,-.9) node{$d=2a=2e$};
\draw (1,-1.55) node{$\widehat{B}=\widehat{E}=90^\circ$};
\draw (1,-2.2) node{$2\widehat{A}+\widehat{D}=360^\circ$};
\end{tiny}


\end{tikzpicture}
};
\draw (4.5,13.5) node {%
%%%%%%Pentagon Type 14
\begin{tikzpicture}[line join=round,line width=1.2pt,scale=.6]
\begin{tiny}
\draw (0,0) coordinate (A) node[below] {$A$};
\draw ($ (A) + (0:24.3mm) $) coordinate (B) node[below] {$B$};
\draw ($(B)!9mm!-145.34:(A)$) coordinate (C) node[right] {$C$};
\draw ($(C)!18mm!-69.32:(B)$) coordinate (D) node [above] {$D$};
\draw ($(D)!18mm!-124.66:(C)$) coordinate (E) node [left] {$E$};

\draw[fill=yellow!20,yellow!20] (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- (D) -- (E) -- cycle;

\draw ($(E)!9mm!0:(D)$) coordinate (EE);
\draw ($(D)!9mm!0:(C)$) coordinate (DD);

\draw (A) -- (B) node[pos=.5,below] {$b$};
\draw [pink](B) -- (C) node[pos=.5,below right] {$c$};
\draw [pink](C) -- (D) node[pos=.5,above] {$d$};
\draw [pink](D) -- (E) node[pos=.5,above] {$e$};
\draw[blue](E) -- (A) node[pos=.5,left] {$a$};

\draw[fill] (A) circle (.6pt); 
\draw[fill] (B) circle (.6pt);
\draw[fill] (C) circle (.6pt);
\draw[fill] (D) circle (.6pt);
\draw[fill] (E) circle (.6pt);

\draw[fill] (EE) circle (.6pt);
\draw[fill] (DD) circle (.6pt);


\draw (1.4,-.9) node{$2a=2c=d=e,\,\widehat{A}=90^\circ$};
\draw (1.4,-1.55) node{$\widehat{B}\simeq 145.34^\circ,\, 
\widehat{C}\simeq 69.32^\circ$};
\draw (1.4,-2.2) node{$
 \widehat{D}\simeq 124.66^\circ,\, 
\widehat{E}\simeq 110.68^\circ$
%%(2\widehat{B}+\widehat{C}=360^\circ,\; \widehat{C}+\widehat{E}=180^\circ)
};
\end{tiny}


\end{tikzpicture}
};
\draw (7.5,13.5) node {%
%%%%%%Pentagon Type 15
\begin{tikzpicture}[line join=round,line width=1.2pt,scale=.6]
\begin{tiny}
\draw (0,0) coordinate (A) node[below] {$A$};
\draw ($ (A) + (0:21mm) $) coordinate (B) node[below] {$B$};
\draw ($(B)!10.5mm!-60:(A)$) coordinate (C) node[right] {$C$};
\draw ($(C)!21mm!-135:(B)$) coordinate (D) node [above] {$D$};
\draw ($(D)!10.5mm!-105:(C)$) coordinate (E) node [left] {$E$};

\draw ($(A)!10.5mm!0:(B)$) coordinate (AA);


\draw[fill=yellow!20,yellow!20] (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- (D) -- (E) -- cycle;


\draw [pink] (A) -- (B) node[pos=.5,below] {$b$};
\draw [pink](B) -- (C) node[pos=.5,right] {$c$};
\draw [blue](C) -- (D) node[pos=.5,above] {$d$};
\draw [pink](D) -- (E) node[pos=.5,left] {$e$};
\draw[pink](E) -- (A) node[pos=.5,below left] {$a$};

\draw[fill] (A) circle (.6pt); 
\draw[fill] (B) circle (.6pt);
\draw[fill] (C) circle (.6pt);
\draw[fill] (D) circle (.6pt);
\draw[fill] (E) circle (.6pt);

\draw[fill] (AA) circle (.6pt);

\draw (.7,-.9) node{$a=c=e,\;b=2a$};
\draw (.7,-1.55) node{$
\widehat{E}=90^\circ,
\widehat{A}=150^\circ,
\widehat{B}=60^\circ$};
\draw (.7,-2.2) node{$
\widehat{C}=135^\circ,\;\widehat{D}=105^\circ$};
\end{tiny}
\end{tikzpicture}
};    
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 11):

A few years ago I struggled with the problem of annotating Byron's comic masterpiece "Don Juan". I finally managed to torture the Memoir class sufficiently to produce the attached. Beautiful? The only reason I claim your attention is because I've never seen an adequate annotation of extended verse (in terra-rima stanzas or in any other format). My objective was, once, to emulate the fabulous Isaac Asimov annotation (Doubleday, 1972. Illus. Milton Glaser). But, in a way, I'm content that wonderful work remains non-pareil.
[image]
[image]

The annotated Canto III (pdf, 2.1mb) is [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/s7w7wz6mlmz55o4/DonJuanCantoIIIAnnotated.pdf?dl=0)

Answer (score 10):

The handbook for the memoir class showcases quite a few different layouts, some of which I would call quite beautiful.

Answer (score 10):

I think this list shoul definitely include [The Not So Short Introduction to LaTeX 2e](http://mirror.unl.edu/ctan/info/lshort/english/lshort.pdf). It is the book with which I started to learn LaTeX. It has no bells and whistles, but a very clean and pleasant layout, which is the philosophy of LaTeX. If I wanted to show off fonts and fancy pictures I would probably rather go for a document created in Adobe InDesign.

[image: example]

Answer (score 10):

I like to get ideas from http://data.imf.au.dk/system/latex/bog/version3/beta/ltxb-2011-09-13-20-10.pdf

[image: example1]
[image: example2]

Although it's in Danish and sometimes maybe a bit too colorful or crowded, I really like what he has done.

Comment: That is indeed *so much* color. Hm.

Comment: Is the template available anywhere?

Answer (score 10):

A poster about "Automata and Computability" for my students. It's in Dutch thus most people wont understand that much about it. It is an A0 poster, something most WYSIWIG magic will never achieve to edit conveniently.

[image: poster on automata and computibility]

[pdf](http://willemvanonsem.ulyssis.be/posterab.pdf) and [tex](https://github.com/KommuSoft/publications/tree/master/poster_automaten_en_berekenbaarheid) are available. Feel free to fork/issue/pull request.

In order to make typesetting more conveniently, I wrote a package called `preziposters`, although it is still under development.

A physical copy is hanging in my office.

Using the same package, this poster - about *Graph theory and Combinatorial Optimization* - was made (still in beta):

[image: poster graph theory and combinatorial optimization]

[(pdf)](http://willemvanonsem.ulyssis.be/poster_gtco.pdf)

Comment: The pdf file contains 0 bytes.

Comment: Fixed, a `cron` script normally compiles the poster each day (to synchronize updates), but apparently, something went wrong this time.

Comment: Thanks. BTW, I looked at other posters (which are very nice) in your git repository and ‘Fundamentals of Computer Science’ is rather empty. Is it not finished (yet)?

Comment: Indeed, I was planning to finish the poster in june. But my PhD supervisor asked me to focus more on my research than helping my students ;). Now each year per subject I give a poster to the the student that was most active (in a positive sense). ;)

Comment: The pdf is still 0 bytes.

Comment: @Sverre: no, it was *again* 0 bytes. The automatic script unfortunately sometimes builds and uploads the project in an inconsistent state. Now it should work again. Modified the script as well.

Comment: Still 0 bytes ... you might wanna reconsider your approach of generating this pdf automatically, since this appears to be a reoccurring problem.

Comment: @Sverre: how about now. Apparently it takes some time before the webserver accepts new content.

Comment: @Willem Van Onsem: "This account has been disabled"

Answer (score 10):

Here's an example from a series of posters I designed, displaying quotes about science. The posters all have the same basic design and are to be printed on A3 paper.

[image: Poster]

Comment: Interesting quote! is there a link to the source/list of quotes?

Answer (score 10):

Not sure if this counts as "great typesetting" but I am quite satisfied of how my lecture notes turned out. I am using the `tufte-book` document class and used `titlesec` and `titletoc` to modify the appearance of the sections. I do heavy usage of `tcolorbox` for theorems, examples and definitions. Most of the drawings are made in Inkscape and then imported, the commutative diagrams are made with `tikzcd` and finally some Asymptote is present. Here are some pages of them:

[image: pic1]

[image: pic2]

[image: pic3]

They definitely are not top-tier but I still am quite satisfied with the result.

Comment: So nice design. Would you like to share the template? My e-mail is mauramz at gmail.com Thank you.

Comment: I am not too sure how to share a template or how to even create one. I put together the relevant commands for the sections and the theorems and put them [here](https://pastebin.com/tSapJRAK). Alongside these I also use some other commands to manage my figures but they are not really relevant with the design you see here. As for the document class I use `\documentclass[symmetric,nobib,notoc, a4paper]{tufte-book}`. I hope this suffices!

Comment: @gjkf  Kindly share this template with me: jongaro at ictp.it

Comment: https://pastebin.com/7bzqaXPf This is the common preamble I used, the document class is right above. The preamble it's all but well done, hope it helps though!

Answer (score 10):

I used to make my own `documentclass` for my master's degree. It is not perfect, but I feel confortable with it. It is still in progress. I would probably add a GitHub repository this summer for sharing it.

There's 2 main classes:

The `MasterNotes` class:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

The `MasterArticle` class: (only the title changes)

[image]

The `MasterLessons` class: (a variant of `MasterArticle` for my preparation for Agrégation oral exam)

[image]

**EDIT** The code is now available on GitHub [here](https://github.com/MrStrumff/MasterNotes). I will no longer support it. I have another project instead.

Comment: This looks beautiful! Is there any chance one can get the source code of your MasterNotes class with some dummy text?

Comment: I will create a Github Repo. for this class, maybe the next week. It is no longer supported though. I will edit the post once done.

Comment: Link to the GitHub added.

Answer (score 10):

I would like to present my humble example here: Kochański's Approximation published in Acta Eruditorum 1685.

https://danieldelimata.github.io/kochanski/

[image]

Comment: Done in TeX? Note that 1685 is too early even for WordStar and Electric Pencil...  `:)` (nice, anyway).

Answer (score 8):

Is this the shameless plug place?
Ok then! Here's my [PhD thesis](https://yelkhatib.github.io/papers/Elkhatib2011gridmap.pdf) which, 4+ years later, I am still happy with the way it turned out. Style is available [here](https://yelkhatib.github.io/assets/phd_style.tex). It's an amalgamation of different things I got off the interwebs and tweaked when procrastinating.

Comment: would you please give us a template or part of the code you used in your Thesis. I looks really nice.

Comment: Overall is a nice design, but I think you have been too brave using illuminated capitals at start of chapters in a computer science thesis! I beat that this was a bit controversial with your advisor ;)

Comment: @zunbeltz Not really. Even the examiners were pretty pleased with it aesthetically (as well as content wise!).

Comment: @Yehia Good for you! Maybe I will try to use them in my tech reports ;)

Comment: https://yelkhatib.github.io/papers/Elkhatib2011gridmap.pdf

Answer (score 8):

This is a [preprint of an article](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/329352497_Modeling_Conflicting_Unreliable_and_Varying_Information) I am working on, which makes use of the wonderful (but sadly defunct) [tufte-latex](https://github.com/Tufte-LaTeX/tufte-latex) and its tufte-handout class, together with the pgfpages package. It's rather simplistic, but given the few modifications made, the result is quite nice and clean. Just wanted to post this an example of what can be achieved without being a LaTeX templating guru, but still looks distinguishably different from the standard templates, thanks to the great work of others.

The article is available on [github](https://github.com/Roenbaeck/transitional) if anyone wants to dive into the code.

[image: First page]
[image: Second page]
[image: Third page]

Comment: I am not fond of Tufte's use of margin figures. The reader may find it difficult to know in what order to read the material. I prefer to put the illustrations into the flow of the text as much as possible. Your example doesn't suffer from this problem, but most people who follow Tufte have that problem.

Comment: @BenjaminMcKay: how does that differ from standard LaTeX's floats, though? If the figure is labeled `Figure n`, and you refer to it as such in the text, I fail to see the problem. The output looks absolutely beautiful, but I wonder if the lines are on grid.

Comment: I edited the post and added a link to the github page where the code for the article can be found.

Comment: @morbusg: I agree; LaTeX's floats give a similar problem, but Tufte's style encourages large numbers of margin figures. Large numbers of floats would have the same problem, but people usually don't have very many floats.

Answer (score 8):

I am a member of the National University of Singapore Astronomical Society, and we hold competitions for secondary and pre-university students. I typeset [the exam papers](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1eStVXHtDB-HZ6ofQIFZnQpNNagdeyHBu) for this year's iteration. The preamble is admittedly extremely messy, with plenty of possibly unnecessary code, but the product looks good. The `exam` class was used to great effect.

Nearly every single diagram was hand-coded in separate `.tikz` files, compiled and imported in; I am especially pleased with the diagrams for the bielliptical transfer and orbital parameters:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Last year, during University Physics Competition, I was trying to draw some Hoffman transfer orbit diagrams. But due to lack of time and proficiency, I ended up using Geogebra to draw them.
Do you mind showing the tikz codes of the diagrams?

Comment: @raf, please find [a pastebin](https://pastebin.com/JRbvm0Mc) of the code here. It is meant to be used with [this preamble](https://pastebin.com/0XmSW2rn): please comment out the Minion Pro and MnSymbol packages for compatibility. It is not the best code, and I would like to change much of it (like optimising the radii of the orbits), but this is how I set up the images when I typeset them two years ago.

Comment: Thanks for sharing, @SRSR333

Answer (score 7):

Not a big one, but it illustrates how easy it can be to integrate various styles of music with LaTeX ([source on GitHub](https://github.com/jperon/Magnificat)):

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Tom Lehrer has put his [songs](https://tomlehrersongs.com/) in the public domain. I have typeset a book from his lyrics (and actually orderd a printed copy).

The book is based on the [memoir class](https://ctan.org/pkg/memoir) and the font is a Palatino clone provided by the [New PX font package](https://ctan.org/pkg/newpx). Everything is set on a grid.

The [full pdf](https://nuntius35.gitlab.io/res/TomLehrer_Songs.pdf) and the [LaTeX source code](https://gitlab.com/nuntius35/tom_lehrer) is available online.

[image: The Elements by Tom Lehrer]

[image: Tom Lehrer – Songs and Lyrics]

Answer (score 6):

Philip A. Ebert and Marcus Rossberg's translation of Frege's *Grundgesetze der Arithmetik* features some of the most complex notation devised.  The TeX source is not available, but one can view much of the work on the "preview" link at the [OUP page](https://global.oup.com/academic/product/gottlob-frege-basic-laws-of-arithmetic-9780199281749?lang=en&cc=us) for the book.

Edited by **Ben McKay**: Here is a little sample (which won't give us copyright problems, as it is fair use):
[image]

Comment: Could you please add an image?

Comment: I have included a link for the interested reader, copying an image from there might have copyright implication, so I have not done so.

Comment: I think one or two pages would probably be fine? Those proof trees seem fancy.

Answer (score 6):

After finally managing to read Bringhurst's *The Elements of Typographic Style* this past weekend, I felt the urge to try out a few new fonts. This was one of the byproducts … The font is Cochineal, the drop cap comes from some CD they had at the office. Full code below.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[portrait,a5paper,hmargin=2.5cm,vmargin=4cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[babel,activate={true,nocompatibility},protrusion=true,expansion=true,tracking=true,factor=750,stretch=5,shrink=5]{microtype}
\usepackage{fontspec}
    \defaultfontfeatures{SmallCapsFeatures = {
        Letters = SmallCaps,
        LetterSpace = 2.25,
        Numbers = Lining}}

    \setmainfont{Cochineal}[Numbers={Proportional,OldStyle}]
    \providefontfamily\dropcaps{TypographerWoodcut01.ttf}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pagecolor}
    \definecolor{MyCrimson}{HTML}{880000}
    \definecolor{MyGrey}{HTML}{080808}
    \definecolor{MyBackground}{HTML}{FFFFEB}
    \pagecolor{MyBackground}

\usepackage{lettrine}
\renewcommand{\LettrineFontHook}{\dropcaps}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
    \begin{quote}
        \begin{flushright}
            \itshape\large\textcolor{MyCrimson}
            {{\LARGE Everything~}{\Large written symbols can say has already passed \rlap{by\,…}}}
        \end{flushright}
    \end{quote}

    \lettrine[lines=4,findent=.25em,nindent=0em,lhang=.04,loversize=-.01]
    {\textcolor{MyCrimson}{T}}{\textcolor{MyGrey}{\kern .25pt hey are like tracks left by
    animals.} }\\[2pt]{\textcolor{MyGrey}{That is why the masters of
    meditation re\-fuse to accept that writings are final. The aim is to reach
    true being by means of those tracks, those letters, those signs; but
    reality itself is not a sign, and it leaves no tracks. It doesn't come to
    us by way of letters or words. We can go toward it, by following those
    words and letters back to whence they came from.}

\vspace{1ex}

    \noindent {\textcolor{MyGrey}{ But so long as we are preoccupied with symbols, theories and opinions, we will fail to reach the principle.}

\vspace{1ex}

    \noindent{}\kern .5pt—~But when we give up symbols and opinions, aren't we left in the utter nothingness of being?

\vspace{-3.5ex}

    \begin{quote}
        \hfill\itshape\large\textcolor{MyCrimson}{\noindent{}\kern .5pt—~Yes.}
    \end{quote}

\vspace{2\baselineskip}

    \begin{flushleft}
        {\textcolor{MyGrey}{
        \small
        \noindent\textsc{Kimura Kyūho} — \emph{Kenjutsu Fushigi Hen} \newline
        [On the Mysteries of Swordsmanship], 1768}}
    \end{flushleft}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

The book [Engineering Design Optimization](https://flowlab.groups.et.byu.net/mdobook.pdf) by Martins and Ning is a perfect example of beautiful typesetting.

[image]

Comment: +1: Can you please add some kind of explanation why you think that the book is created with LaTeX?

Comment: I admit I have no proof that created with LaTeX. However, the layout seems to be tufte-latex and the plots all look as created with pgfplots. The `\intercal` symbol for the transpose in the image, etc.

Answer (score 5):

At the first reduction of the Gaussian elimination using the Gauss transform, the resulting matrix will have 0 below the first entry in the first column, the first row will not change and the trailing matrix will be updated accordingly. A clear way to see this is to visualize the process in a block-portioned matrix. I wrote a code that demonstrates this providing beautiful visualization. The code is really big but if you wish to have the code just "@me" in the comments of any of my questions/answers and I will provide you with the link to the code. Enjoy!!!
[image]

Answer (score 5):

Not much by way of typography (it's `URW Classico` for sans-serif and `Baskervaldx` for serif), but I hope you find the book that I'm writing worth of this thread. (Latest version here: http://bit.ly/2JuJxTJ)

It relies on a heavy use of `tcolorbox` for definitions, exercises, examples, and end-of-chapter projects.

Book cover: [image: cover] Table of contents: [image: table of contents] Beginning of chapter: [image: beginning of chapter]
Exercise and definition: [image: exercise and definition] Table: [image: table] End-of-chapter project: [image: end of chapter project] End-of-chapter summary: [image: end of chapter summary]

I still have some issues to solve, as seen in the second of these "example" boxes:

[image: example boxes]

But by and large, I hope that the use of the different kinds of boxes makes the different kinds of contents easier to localize, as well as making the flow of the text somewhat less... tedious?

Comment: Tables with vertical rules and "ejemplo 50" without the 0 are not examples of beautiful typography, sorry.

Comment: @CarLaTeX I disagree about the vertical rules, but agree about "ejemplo 50". As I said, I still don't know how to fix the latter.

Comment: Search for `/tcb/height=⟨length⟩` in the `tcolorbox` documentation, it sets a minimum box height. (Professional tables don't have vertical rules).

Comment: @CarlosRomero is it possible please to share the source Tex file? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

A book that has been authored and formatted using the typesetting system LaTeX
[image]

Comment: Very nice looking. Can you provide a link to the book?

Answer (score 5):

Here are some pages from my new personnal class for my courses dispensed in class. There're two main classes ([see the GitHub page](https://github.com/MrStrumff/MyCourse)).

The `MyBook` class (mostly for a translation project):

Title page:
[image: Title page]

Chapter head style:
[image]

Main text style:
[image]

The `MyCourse` class (for my students):

Title page:
[image]

Main text with some figures:
[image]

Some text with exercises and code environment:
[image]

Comment: Beautiful design!

Comment: Beautifully done. Any possibility of sharing the class file?

Comment: The class file is a little messy for now. I will clean it up and add the GitHub link in the next few weeks.

Comment: Link added [also here](https://github.com/MrStrumff/MyCourse).

Answer (score 4):

Easy. The [TeX showcase](http://www.tug.org/texshowcase/) from the TeX Users' Group.

Answer (score 4):

We recently created a LaTeX package for the Physics branch of my student union (at KTH, the Royal Institute of Technology in Stockholm, Sweden) that allows anyone to typeset a document in compliance with our graphical profile. The code is quite messy, but except for the implementation listing at the end (which will change when we move to `dtx` deployment in the next release) I'm quite happy with the output it produces.

[image: fstil.pdf]

Both the package code, the examples and the output pdf are available [on Github](http://github.com/Fysiksektionen/latex-fstil).

Answer (score 3):

...and for a great example of TeX typesetting in an open access scholarly journal, check out the [Australasian Journal of Logic](http://philosophy.unimelb.edu.au/ajl/).

Comment: Very nice, but I can't find the LaTeX package anywhere in the site.

Comment: I don't like the design of the journal: The font is harder to read and misses good sans-serif variant, moreover e.g. the usage of italics in  section headers makes the font significantly inconsistent. _Generally, I think that unwise changes of the font faces does not make the design any better._ (This is just my opinion, I don't say that someone made a wrong template, I just point out some issues I see there.)

Answer (score 3):

I found the pocket books from the brazilian publisher "Hedra" to be very beautiful. For example, Conrad's *Heart of Darkness* [translation](http://books.google.com.br/books?id=rY127YESjTQC&lpg=PP1&hl=en&pg=PA9#v=onepage&q&f=false).  However, there's no source.

Comment: Is there any reason to believe this was produced with TeX?

Comment: The editors say so in the book's colophon, which unfortunately is not available in google books anymore (by the time I posted it, the whole book was available). There's another pocket book from the same collection (a collection of short stories by Ryūnosuke Akutagawa) available at http://download.uol.com.br/diversao/rashomon_e_outros_contos_akutagawa.pdf. The chief editor was very active in the old brazilian tex mailing list (TeX-BR) also.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for replying. I just couldn't tell from what the link showed me which was basically the front cover!

Answer (score 3):

An example of combining 4 graphs from different datasheets results in this:

[image]

If there is any interest in it, I will post de tex file.

Answer (score 2):

How about sesamath's book class ?https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/sesamanuel

Available with `texdoc sesamath` on distributions such as TeX Live

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to add Leon Harkleroad's [*The Math Behind The Music*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521009359), an impressive example of fine page layout.

Comment: Could you please add an image?

Answer (score -2):

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{dvipsnames,table,svgnames,xcdraw,showerrors}{xcolor}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}  % Allows the definition of hex colors}
\usepackage{pst-blur}
\usepackage{pst-circ}
\usepackage{pst-tree}
\usepackage{fp}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{paper=a4paper,left=25mm,right=25mm,top=5mm,bottom=15mm,includeheadfoot}

\xdefinecolor{dunkelgrau}{rgb}{0.8,0.8,0.8}
\xdefinecolor{hellgrau}{rgb}{0.95,0.95,0.95}

                \def\PSBB#1#2{\begin{pspicture}(#2,0.40)%
                \psTextFrame[blur=true, shadow=true,fillcolor=hellgrau,fillstyle=solid,linecolor=black,framearc=0.3](0,0)(#2,0.40){%
                    \shortstack{\tiny{#1}}}\end{pspicture}
                    }%
                %
                % \def\psedge{\ncdiag[armA=0cm,angleB=180,armB=1cm]}
                \def\PSBF#1#2#3{\begin{pspicture}(#2,0.40)%
                \psTextFrame[blur=true, blursteps=50, shadow=true,fillcolor=#3,fillstyle=solid,linecolor=black,framearc=0.3](0,0)(#2,0.40){%
                    \shortstack{\tiny{#1}}}\end{pspicture}
                    }%


\parindent=0pt
% \usepackage{syntonly} \syntaxonly
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{morewrites}
\label{sec:morewrites}
\begin{itemize}
\item Parent: None
\item Children: expl3, primargs, atbegshi
\end{itemize}
\multido{\r=100+-5}{1}
{
    \begin{pspicture}(9,-2.0)(26,1.85)
        \rput(30.25,0.5){%
            \begin{pspicture*}(9,-2.0)(26,1.85)
            %
            % \xdefinecolor{treedesigncolor}{rgb}{1,0,0}
                %
                % \xdefinecolor{treelightgrey}{RGB}{0,191,255}
                %
                \FPset\armAsepvalue{0.35}
                \FPset\armBsepvalue{0.35}
                \FPset\angelAvalue{180}
                \FPset\angelBvalue{180}
                %
                %armAsepvalue
                \FPset\armAsepvalue{0.45}
                \FPset\armBsepvalue{0.45}
                \FPset\angelAvalue{180}
                \FPset\angelBvalue{180}
                %
                \FPset\rootlevelsep{1.2}
                \FPset\onelevelsepv{0.9}
                \FPset\twolevelsepv{0.5}
                \FPset\threelevelsepv{0.0}
                \FPset\fourlevelsepv{0.0}
                \FPset\fivelevelsepv{-0.5}
                \FPset\sixlevelsepv{0.4}
                \FPset\sevenlevelsepv{0.4}
                \FPset\distfactor{0.5}
                \FPset\defaultsz{2.85}
                \FPset\levelzero{2.25}
                \FPset\levelzerob{3.05}
                \FPset\rootlevelsepva{4.05}
                % \FPset\rootlevelsepva{0.0}
                \FPset\onelevelsepva{3.65}
                \FPset\twolevelsepva{3.65}
                \FPset\threelevelsepva{3.65}
                \FPset\fourlevelsepva{3.65}
                \FPset\fivelevelsepva{3.65}
                \FPset\sixlevelsepva{3.65}
                \FPset\levelone{2.85}
                \FPset\leveloneb{3.05}
                \FPset\leveltwo{3.45}
                \FPset\leveltwob{2.55}
                \FPset\levelthree{4.75}
                \FPset\levelthreeb{4.25}
                \FPset\levelfour{5.55}
                \FPset\levelfourb{2.05}
                \FPset\levelfive{3.65}
                \FPset\levelsix{3.05}
                \FPset\levelseven{2.55}
                \FPset\leveleight{7.65}
                \FPset\levelfiveb{2.35}
                %
                \FPset\levelonestamp{3.75}
                \FPset\leveltwostamp{3.25}
                \FPset\levelthreestamp{3.25}
                \FPset\levelfourstamp{3.25}
                %
                %onelevelsepastamp
                \FPset\onelevelsepastampA{4.85}
                \FPset\twolevelsepastampA{7.85}
                %
                \FPset\onelevelsepastamp{4.85}
                \FPset\twolevelsepastamp{7.85}
                \FPset\threelevelsepastamp{9.85}
                %
                \FPupn{onelevelsepastamp}{levelonestamp 2 + 2 round}
                \FPupn{twolevelsepastamp}{leveltwostamp 2 + 2 round}
                %
                %
                \FPupn{twolevelsepastampt}{twolevelsepastamp 5.5 + 2 round}
                \FPupn{armAsepvaluet}{armAsepvalue 5.5 + 2 round}
                %
                \FPupn{rootlevelsepa}{rootlevelsep distfactor + 2 round}
                \FPupn{defaultsza}{defaultsz 1.15 + distfactor + 2 round}
                \FPupn{onelevelsep}{rootlevelsep onelevelsepv - neg 2 round}
                \FPupn{onelevelsepa}{levelone onelevelsep + armAsepvalue + armBsepvalue + distfactor + 2 round}
                %
                \FPupn{twolevelsep}{onelevelsep twolevelsepv  - neg 2 round}
                \FPupn{twolevelsepa}{leveltwo twolevelsep + armAsepvalue + armBsepvalue + distfactor + 2 round}
                % \FPset\signsz{3.05}
                %
                \FPupn{threelevelsep}{twolevelsep threelevelsepv  - neg 2 round}
                \FPupn{threelevelsepa}{levelthree threelevelsep + armAsepvalue + armBsepvalue + distfactor + 2 round}
                %
                \FPupn{fourlevelsep}{threelevelsep fourlevelsepv  - neg 2 round}
                \FPupn{fourlevelsepa}{levelfour fourlevelsep + armAsepvalue + armBsepvalue + distfactor + 2 round}
                %
                %
                \FPupn{fivelevelsep}{fourlevelsep fivelevelsepv  - neg 2 round}
                \FPupn{fivelevelsepa}{levelfive fivelevelsep + armAsepvalue + armBsepvalue + distfactor + 2 round}
                %
                % A3
                \FPupn{sixlevelsep}{fivelevelsep sixlevelsepv  - neg 2 round}
                \FPupn{sixlevelsepa}{levelsix sixlevelsep + armAsepvalue + armBsepvalue + distfactor + 2 round}
                %
                %
                %
                \FPupn{sevenlevelsep}{sixlevelsep sevenlevelsepv  - neg 2 round}
                \FPupn{sevenlevelsepa}{levelseven sevenlevelsep + armAsepvalue + armBsepvalue + distfactor + 2 round}
                %
                % Second Rootnode
                \FPupn{rootlevelsepaa}{rootlevelsepva distfactor + 2 round}
                \FPupn{onelevelsepaaa}{rootlevelsepva onelevelsepva - neg 2 round}
                \FPupn{onelevelsepaab}{leveloneb onelevelsepaaa + armAsepvalue + armBsepvalue + distfactor + 2 round}
                % \onelevelsepaab
                %
                %
                \FPupn{twolevelsepaaa}{onelevelsepva twolevelsepva - neg 2 round}
                \FPupn{twolevelsepaab}{leveltwob twolevelsepaaa + armAsepvalue + armBsepvalue + distfactor + 2 round}
                %
                %
                %
                \FPupn{threelevelsepaaa}{twolevelsepva threelevelsepva - neg 2 round}
                \FPupn{threelevelsepaab}{levelthreeb threelevelsepaaa + armAsepvalue + armBsepvalue + distfactor + 2 round}
                %
                \FPupn{fourlevelsepaaa}{threelevelsepva fourlevelsepva - neg 2 round}
                \FPupn{fourlevelsepaab}{levelfourb fourlevelsepaaa + armAsepvalue + armBsepvalue + distfactor + 2 round}
                %
                %
                \def\psedge{\ncdiag[armA=\armAsepvalue cm,angleB=\angelBvalue,armB=\armBsepvalue cm]}
                \pstree[treemode=R,levelsep=\onelevelsepastamp cm,treesep=0.15cm]{\Tr[ref=lc]{%
                    \PSBB{\nameref{sec:morewrites}.sty [2013/01/08] 0.2e}{\levelonestamp}\pnode(0,0.20){morewrites}{}}}
                        {
                        \def\pspred{morewrites}%
                            \pstree[treemode=R,levelsep=\twolevelsepastamp cm,treesep=0.15cm]{\Tr[ref=lc]{%
                                \PSBB{\textbf{R} expl3.sty [2012/08/14]}{\leveltwostamp}\pnode(0,0.20){expl3}{}}}%
                                    {%
                                    % \def\pspred{expl3}\Tr[ref=lc]{\PSBB{Tätigkeit}{\levelthreestamp}}
                                    % \def\pspred{expl3}\Tr[ref=lc]{\PSBB{Rechtsform}{\levelthreestamp}}
                                    % \def\pspred{expl3}\Tr[ref=lc]{\PSBB{Eintragung}{\levelthreestamp}}
                                    % \def\pspred{expl3}\Tr[ref=lc]{\PSBB{Normative Kraft der Zeit}{\levelthreestamp}}
                                    }%
                        %
                        \def\pspred{morewrites}%
                            \pstree[treemode=R,levelsep=\twolevelsepastamp cm,treesep=0.15cm]{\Tr[ref=lc]{%
                                \PSBB{\textbf{R} primargs.sty [2013/01/08]}{\leveltwostamp}\pnode(0,0.20){primeargs}{}}}%
                                    {%
                                    \def\pspred{primeargs}\Tr[ref=lc]{\PSBB{expl3.sty [2012/08/14]}{\levelthreestamp}}
                                    % \def\pspred{primeargs}\Tr[ref=lc]{\PSBB{Rechtsform}{\levelthreestamp}}
                                    % \def\pspred{primeargs}\Tr[ref=lc]{\PSBB{Eintragung}{\levelthreestamp}}
                                    %
                                    }%
                        %[2010/04/08
                        \def\pspred{morewrites}%
                            \pstree[treemode=R,levelsep=\twolevelsepastamp cm,treesep=0.15cm]{\Tr[ref=lc]{%
                                \PSBB{\textbf{O} atbegshi.sty [2011/10/05]}{\leveltwostamp}\pnode(0,0.20){atbegshi}{}}}%
                                    {%
                                    \def\pspred{atbegshi}\Tr[ref=lc]{\PSBB{infwarerr.sty [2007/09/09]}{\levelthreestamp}}
                                    \def\pspred{atbegshi}\Tr[ref=lc]{\PSBB{\nameref{subsec:ltxcmds}.sty \textcolor{red}{[2010/03/01]}}{\levelthreestamp}}
                                    \def\pspred{atbegshi}\Tr[ref=lc]{\PSBB{\nameref{subsec:ifpdf}.sty \textcolor{red}{[2011/01/30]}}{\levelthreestamp}}
                                    %[2011/01/30]
                                    }%
                                    % \def\pspred{morewrites}%
                            % \pstree[treemode=R,levelsep=\twolevelsepastamp cm,treesep=0.15cm]{\Tr[ref=lc]{%
                                % \PSBF{Schuldrecht}{\leveltwostamp}{Cyan}{}}}{}
                        %
                        % \def\pspred{morewrites}
                            % \pstree[treemode=R,levelsep=\twolevelsepastamp cm,treesep=0.15cm]{\Tr[ref=lc]{%
                                % \PSBB{Familienrecht}{\leveltwostamp}{}}}{}
                        %
                        % \def\psedge{\ncdiag[armA=\armAsepvalue cm,angleB=\angelBvalue,armB=\armBsepvalue cm]}
                        %
                        % \def\pspred{morewrites}
                            % \pstree[treemode=R,levelsep=\twolevelsepastamp cm,treesep=0.15cm]{\Tr[ref=lc]{%
                                % \PSBB{Erbrecht}{\leveltwostamp}{}}}{}%
                        %
                        }
            \end{pspicture*}
        }
    \end{pspicture}
}
\subsection{ltxcmds}
\label{subsec:ltxcmds}
\begin{itemize}
\item Parent: atbegshi
\item Children: eolgrab
\end{itemize}
\multido{\r=100+-5}{1}
{
    \begin{pspicture}(9,-0.67)(26,1.85)
        \rput(30.25,0.75){%
            \begin{pspicture*}(9,-0.67)(26,1.85)
            %
            % \xdefinecolor{treedesigncolor}{rgb}{1,0,0}
                %
                % \xdefinecolor{treelightgrey}{RGB}{0,191,255}
                %
                \FPset\armAsepvalue{0.35}
                \FPset\armBsepvalue{0.35}
                \FPset\angelAvalue{180}
                \FPset\angelBvalue{180}
                %
                %armAsepvalue
                \FPset\armAsepvalue{0.45}
                \FPset\armBsepvalue{0.45}
                \FPset\angelAvalue{180}
                \FPset\angelBvalue{180}
                %
                \FPset\rootlevelsep{1.2}
                \FPset\onelevelsepv{0.9}
                \FPset\twolevelsepv{0.5}
                \FPset\threelevelsepv{0.0}
                \FPset\fourlevelsepv{0.0}
                \FPset\fivelevelsepv{-0.5}
                \FPset\sixlevelsepv{0.4}
                \FPset\sevenlevelsepv{0.4}
                \FPset\distfactor{0.5}
                \FPset\defaultsz{2.85}
                \FPset\levelzero{2.25}
                \FPset\levelzerob{3.05}
                \FPset\rootlevelsepva{4.05}
                % \FPset\rootlevelsepva{0.0}
                \FPset\onelevelsepva{3.65}
                \FPset\twolevelsepva{3.65}
                \FPset\threelevelsepva{3.65}
                \FPset\fourlevelsepva{3.65}
                \FPset\fivelevelsepva{3.65}
                \FPset\sixlevelsepva{3.65}
                \FPset\levelone{2.85}
                \FPset\leveloneb{3.05}
                \FPset\leveltwo{3.45}
                \FPset\leveltwob{2.55}
                \FPset\levelthree{4.75}
                \FPset\levelthreeb{4.25}
                \FPset\levelfour{5.55}
                \FPset\levelfourb{2.05}
                \FPset\levelfive{3.65}
                \FPset\levelsix{3.05}
                \FPset\levelseven{2.55}
                \FPset\leveleight{7.65}
                \FPset\levelfiveb{2.35}
                %
                \FPset\levelonestamp{3.75}
                \FPset\leveltwostamp{3.25}
                \FPset\levelthreestamp{3.25}
                \FPset\levelfourstamp{3.25}
                %
                %onelevelsepastamp
                \FPset\onelevelsepastampA{4.85}
                \FPset\twolevelsepastampA{7.85}
                %
                \FPset\onelevelsepastamp{4.85}
                \FPset\twolevelsepastamp{7.85}
                \FPset\threelevelsepastamp{9.85}
                %
                \FPupn{onelevelsepastamp}{levelonestamp 2 + 2 round}
                \FPupn{twolevelsepastamp}{leveltwostamp 2 + 2 round}
                %
                %
                \FPupn{twolevelsepastampt}{twolevelsepastamp 5.5 + 2 round}
                \FPupn{armAsepvaluet}{armAsepvalue 5.5 + 2 round}
                %
                \FPupn{rootlevelsepa}{rootlevelsep distfactor + 2 round}
                \FPupn{defaultsza}{defaultsz 1.15 + distfactor + 2 round}
                \FPupn{onelevelsep}{rootlevelsep onelevelsepv - neg 2 round}
                \FPupn{onelevelsepa}{levelone onelevelsep + armAsepvalue + armBsepvalue + distfactor + 2 round}
                %
                \FPupn{twolevelsep}{onelevelsep twolevelsepv  - neg 2 round}
                \FPupn{twolevelsepa}{leveltwo twolevelsep + armAsepvalue + armBsepvalue + distfactor + 2 round}
                % \FPset\signsz{3.05}
                %
                \FPupn{threelevelsep}{twolevelsep threelevelsepv  - neg 2 round}
                \FPupn{threelevelsepa}{levelthree threelevelsep + armAsepvalue + armBsepvalue + distfactor + 2 round}
                %
                \FPupn{fourlevelsep}{threelevelsep fourlevelsepv  - neg 2 round}
                \FPupn{fourlevelsepa}{levelfour fourlevelsep + armAsepvalue + armBsepvalue + distfactor + 2 round}
                %
                %
                \FPupn{fivelevelsep}{fourlevelsep fivelevelsepv  - neg 2 round}
                \FPupn{fivelevelsepa}{levelfive fivelevelsep + armAsepvalue + armBsepvalue + distfactor + 2 round}
                %
                % A3
                \FPupn{sixlevelsep}{fivelevelsep sixlevelsepv  - neg 2 round}
                \FPupn{sixlevelsepa}{levelsix sixlevelsep + armAsepvalue + armBsepvalue + distfactor + 2 round}
                %
                %
                %
                \FPupn{sevenlevelsep}{sixlevelsep sevenlevelsepv  - neg 2 round}
                \FPupn{sevenlevelsepa}{levelseven sevenlevelsep + armAsepvalue + armBsepvalue + distfactor + 2 round}
                %
                % Second Rootnode
                \FPupn{rootlevelsepaa}{rootlevelsepva distfactor + 2 round}
                \FPupn{onelevelsepaaa}{rootlevelsepva onelevelsepva - neg 2 round}
                \FPupn{onelevelsepaab}{leveloneb onelevelsepaaa + armAsepvalue + armBsepvalue + distfactor + 2 round}
                % \onelevelsepaab
                %
                %
                \FPupn{twolevelsepaaa}{onelevelsepva twolevelsepva - neg 2 round}
                \FPupn{twolevelsepaab}{leveltwob twolevelsepaaa + armAsepvalue + armBsepvalue + distfactor + 2 round}
                %
                %
                %
                \FPupn{threelevelsepaaa}{twolevelsepva threelevelsepva - neg 2 round}
                \FPupn{threelevelsepaab}{levelthreeb threelevelsepaaa + armAsepvalue + armBsepvalue + distfactor + 2 round}
                %
                \FPupn{fourlevelsepaaa}{threelevelsepva fourlevelsepva - neg 2 round}
                \FPupn{fourlevelsepaab}{levelfourb fourlevelsepaaa + armAsepvalue + armBsepvalue + distfactor + 2 round}
                %
                %\RequirePackage{eolgrab}[2011/01/12]%
                %
                \def\psedge{\ncdiag[armA=\armAsepvalue cm,angleB=\angelBvalue,armB=\armBsepvalue cm]}
                \pstree[treemode=R,levelsep=\onelevelsepastamp cm,treesep=0.15cm]{\Tr[ref=lc]{%
                    \PSBB{\nameref{subsec:ltxcmds}.sty \textcolor{red}{\rnode{B}{[2010/03/01]}}}{\levelonestamp}\pnode(0,0.20){ltxcmds}{}}}
                        {
                        \def\pspred{ltxcmds}%
                            \pstree[treemode=R,levelsep=\twolevelsepastamp cm,treesep=0.15cm]{\Tr[ref=lc]{%
                                \PSBB{\textbf{R} eolgrab.sty [2011/01/12]}{\leveltwostamp}\pnode(0,0.20){eolgrab}{}}}%
                                    {%
                                    \def\pspred{eolgrab}\Tr[ref=lc]{\PSBB{\textbf{R} \nameref{subsec:ltxcmds}.sty \textcolor{red}{\rnode{A}{[2010/12/04]}}}{\levelthreestamp}}
                                    \def\pspred{eolgrab}\Tr[ref=lc]{\PSBB{\textbf{R} infwarerr.sty \textcolor{red}{[2010/04/08]}}{\levelthreestamp}}
                                    % \def\pspred{expl3}\Tr[ref=lc]{\PSBB{Eintragung}{\levelthreestamp}}
                                    % \def\pspred{expl3}\Tr[ref=lc]{\PSBB{Normative Kraft der Zeit}{\levelthreestamp}}
                                    }%[2010/04/08]
                        %  \RequirePackage{ltxcmds}[2010/12/04]%
  % \RequirePackage{infwarerr}[2010/04/08]%
                        %
                                    % \def\pspred{morewrites}%
                            % \pstree[treemode=R,levelsep=\twolevelsepastamp cm,treesep=0.15cm]{\Tr[ref=lc]{%
                                % \PSBF{Schuldrecht}{\leveltwostamp}{Cyan}{}}}{}
                        %
                        % \def\pspred{morewrites}
                            % \pstree[treemode=R,levelsep=\twolevelsepastamp cm,treesep=0.15cm]{\Tr[ref=lc]{%
                                % \PSBB{Familienrecht}{\leveltwostamp}{}}}{}
                        %
                        % \def\psedge{\ncdiag[armA=\armAsepvalue cm,angleB=\angelBvalue,armB=\armBsepvalue cm]}
                        %
                        % \def\pspred{morewrites}
                            % \pstree[treemode=R,levelsep=\twolevelsepastamp cm,treesep=0.15cm]{\Tr[ref=lc]{%
                                % \PSBB{Erbrecht}{\leveltwostamp}{}}}{}%
                        %
                        }
                        \nccurve[angleB=135,angleA=50,linecolor=red]{<->}{A}{B}
                        % \ncbar[angleB=90,offsetA=-4pt]{<->}{A}{B}
                        % \pccurve[angleB=135,angleA=50]{<->}{A}{B}
            \end{pspicture*}
        }
    \end{pspicture}
}
\subsection{ifpdf}
\label{subsec:ifpdf}
\begin{itemize}
\item Parent: atbegshi
\item Children: ifluatex
\end{itemize}
\multido{\r=100+-5}{1}
{
    \begin{pspicture}(9,-0.27)(26,0.85)
        \rput(29.25,0.75){%
            \begin{pspicture*}(9,-0.27)(26,0.85)
            %
            % \xdefinecolor{treedesigncolor}{rgb}{1,0,0}
                %
                % \xdefinecolor{treelightgrey}{RGB}{0,191,255}
                %
                \FPset\armAsepvalue{0.35}
                \FPset\armBsepvalue{0.35}
                \FPset\angelAvalue{180}
                \FPset\angelBvalue{180}
                %
                %armAsepvalue
                \FPset\armAsepvalue{0.45}
                \FPset\armBsepvalue{0.45}
                \FPset\angelAvalue{180}
                \FPset\angelBvalue{180}
                %
                \FPset\rootlevelsep{1.2}
                \FPset\onelevelsepv{0.9}
                \FPset\twolevelsepv{0.5}
                \FPset\threelevelsepv{0.0}
                \FPset\fourlevelsepv{0.0}
                \FPset\fivelevelsepv{-0.5}
                \FPset\sixlevelsepv{0.4}
                \FPset\sevenlevelsepv{0.4}
                \FPset\distfactor{0.5}
                \FPset\defaultsz{2.85}
                \FPset\levelzero{2.25}
                \FPset\levelzerob{3.05}
                \FPset\rootlevelsepva{4.05}
                % \FPset\rootlevelsepva{0.0}
                \FPset\onelevelsepva{3.65}
                \FPset\twolevelsepva{3.65}
                \FPset\threelevelsepva{3.65}
                \FPset\fourlevelsepva{3.65}
                \FPset\fivelevelsepva{3.65}
                \FPset\sixlevelsepva{3.65}
                \FPset\levelone{2.85}
                \FPset\leveloneb{3.05}
                \FPset\leveltwo{3.45}
                \FPset\leveltwob{2.55}
                \FPset\levelthree{4.75}
                \FPset\levelthreeb{4.25}
                \FPset\levelfour{5.55}
                \FPset\levelfourb{2.05}
                \FPset\levelfive{3.65}
                \FPset\levelsix{3.05}
                \FPset\levelseven{2.55}
                \FPset\leveleight{7.65}
                \FPset\levelfiveb{2.35}
                %
                \FPset\levelonestamp{3.75}
                \FPset\leveltwostamp{3.25}
                \FPset\levelthreestamp{3.25}
                \FPset\levelfourstamp{3.25}
                %
                %onelevelsepastamp
                \FPset\onelevelsepastampA{4.85}
                \FPset\twolevelsepastampA{7.85}
                %
                \FPset\onelevelsepastamp{4.85}
                \FPset\twolevelsepastamp{7.85}
                \FPset\threelevelsepastamp{9.85}
                %
                \FPupn{onelevelsepastamp}{levelonestamp 2 + 2 round}
                \FPupn{twolevelsepastamp}{leveltwostamp 2 + 2 round}
                %
                %
                \FPupn{twolevelsepastampt}{twolevelsepastamp 5.5 + 2 round}
                \FPupn{armAsepvaluet}{armAsepvalue 5.5 + 2 round}
                %
                \FPupn{rootlevelsepa}{rootlevelsep distfactor + 2 round}
                \FPupn{defaultsza}{defaultsz 1.15 + distfactor + 2 round}
                \FPupn{onelevelsep}{rootlevelsep onelevelsepv - neg 2 round}
                \FPupn{onelevelsepa}{levelone onelevelsep + armAsepvalue + armBsepvalue + distfactor + 2 round}
                %
                \FPupn{twolevelsep}{onelevelsep twolevelsepv  - neg 2 round}
                \FPupn{twolevelsepa}{leveltwo twolevelsep + armAsepvalue + armBsepvalue + distfactor + 2 round}
                % \FPset\signsz{3.05}
                %
                \FPupn{threelevelsep}{twolevelsep threelevelsepv  - neg 2 round}
                \FPupn{threelevelsepa}{levelthree threelevelsep + armAsepvalue + armBsepvalue + distfactor + 2 round}
                %
                \FPupn{fourlevelsep}{threelevelsep fourlevelsepv  - neg 2 round}
                \FPupn{fourlevelsepa}{levelfour fourlevelsep + armAsepvalue + armBsepvalue + distfactor + 2 round}
                %
                %
                \FPupn{fivelevelsep}{fourlevelsep fivelevelsepv  - neg 2 round}
                \FPupn{fivelevelsepa}{levelfive fivelevelsep + armAsepvalue + armBsepvalue + distfactor + 2 round}
                %
                % A3
                \FPupn{sixlevelsep}{fivelevelsep sixlevelsepv  - neg 2 round}
                \FPupn{sixlevelsepa}{levelsix sixlevelsep + armAsepvalue + armBsepvalue + distfactor + 2 round}
                %
                %
                %
                \FPupn{sevenlevelsep}{sixlevelsep sevenlevelsepv  - neg 2 round}
                \FPupn{sevenlevelsepa}{levelseven sevenlevelsep + armAsepvalue + armBsepvalue + distfactor + 2 round}
                %
                % Second Rootnode
                \FPupn{rootlevelsepaa}{rootlevelsepva distfactor + 2 round}
                \FPupn{onelevelsepaaa}{rootlevelsepva onelevelsepva - neg 2 round}
                \FPupn{onelevelsepaab}{leveloneb onelevelsepaaa + armAsepvalue + armBsepvalue + distfactor + 2 round}
                % \onelevelsepaab
                %
                %
                \FPupn{twolevelsepaaa}{onelevelsepva twolevelsepva - neg 2 round}
                \FPupn{twolevelsepaab}{leveltwob twolevelsepaaa + armAsepvalue + armBsepvalue + distfactor + 2 round}
                %
                %
                %
                \FPupn{threelevelsepaaa}{twolevelsepva threelevelsepva - neg 2 round}
                \FPupn{threelevelsepaab}{levelthreeb threelevelsepaaa + armAsepvalue + armBsepvalue + distfactor + 2 round}
                %
                \FPupn{fourlevelsepaaa}{threelevelsepva fourlevelsepva - neg 2 round}
                \FPupn{fourlevelsepaab}{levelfourb fourlevelsepaaa + armAsepvalue + armBsepvalue + distfactor + 2 round}
                %
                %\RequirePackage{eolgrab}[2011/01/12]%
                %
                \def\psedge{\ncdiag[armA=\armAsepvalue cm,angleB=\angelBvalue,armB=\armBsepvalue cm]}
                \pstree[treemode=R,levelsep=\onelevelsepastamp cm,treesep=0.15cm]{\Tr[ref=lc]{%
                    \PSBB{\nameref{subsec:ifpdf}.sty [2011/01/30] v2.3}{\levelonestamp}\pnode(0,0.20){ifpdf}{}}}
                        {
                        \def\pspred{ifpdf}%
                            \pstree[treemode=R,levelsep=\twolevelsepastamp cm,treesep=0.15cm]{\Tr[ref=lc]{%
                                \PSBB{\textbf{O} ifluatex [2009/04/10]}{\leveltwostamp}\pnode(0,0.20){ifluatex}{}}}%
                                    {%
                                    % \def\pspred{expl3}\Tr[ref=lc]{\PSBB{Tätigkeit}{\levelthreestamp}}
                                    % \def\pspred{expl3}\Tr[ref=lc]{\PSBB{Rechtsform}{\levelthreestamp}}
                                    % \def\pspred{expl3}\Tr[ref=lc]{\PSBB{Eintragung}{\levelthreestamp}}
                                    % \def\pspred{expl3}\Tr[ref=lc]{\PSBB{Normative Kraft der Zeit}{\levelthreestamp}}
                                    }%
                        %
                        %
                                    % \def\pspred{morewrites}%
                            % \pstree[treemode=R,levelsep=\twolevelsepastamp cm,treesep=0.15cm]{\Tr[ref=lc]{%
                                % \PSBF{Schuldrecht}{\leveltwostamp}{Cyan}{}}}{}
                        %
                        % \def\pspred{morewrites}
                            % \pstree[treemode=R,levelsep=\twolevelsepastamp cm,treesep=0.15cm]{\Tr[ref=lc]{%
                                % \PSBB{Familienrecht}{\leveltwostamp}{}}}{}
                        %
                        % \def\psedge{\ncdiag[armA=\armAsepvalue cm,angleB=\angelBvalue,armB=\armBsepvalue cm]}
                        %
                        % \def\pspred{morewrites}
                            % \pstree[treemode=R,levelsep=\twolevelsepastamp cm,treesep=0.15cm]{\Tr[ref=lc]{%
                                % \PSBB{Erbrecht}{\leveltwostamp}{}}}{}%
                        %
                        }
            \end{pspicture*}
        }
    \end{pspicture}
}           
\end{document}
```

compile with
   latex -> dvips -> ps2pdf but this example is maybe not worth to publish, delete if you want. /2 threadowner

[image]

Comment: Care to post the output of your example as an image? Some people aren't that fluent in tex to immediately get your post.