# Results that need LaTex

Tags: tools

What are the concrete effects that can only be reached with LaTex systems? 
I am not asking if some LaTex systems are more userfriendly, or if you can work faster with wysiwy**m** systems, once you learned them. It's about a comparison between results using LaTex (with Kile, for example) and using other professional tools, like Scribus or QuarkXPress.

Comment: For what reason did you mention Kile? The Editor has nothing to do with the result. Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1756/why-should-i-use-latex

Comment: I don't think this is really an answerable question, since in principle any tool that can do arbitrary positioning can mimic the results of TeX and vice versa. So then issues about usability invariably come into play.  I've voted to close as not constructive.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Your question is in fact too general for a question for here. Starting from *What is a LaTeX system?* there are many points that needs to be patched and to be limited in scope to able to be answered. So I voted as Alan Munn too since @bloodworks gave a nice example of a similar question.