# Latex users make more mistakes

Tags: typography, latex3

Article Source: An Efficiency Comparison of Document Preparation Systems Used in Academic Research and Development 
Knauff M, Nejasmic J (2014) An Efficiency Comparison of Document Preparation Systems Used in Academic Research and Development. PLOS ONE 9(12): e115069. https://doi.org/10.1371/journal.pone.0115069
I am surprised to read this research paper. But if it’s the truth, the change is needed in a way the frontends are being designed. The research findings defeats the very purpose of latex : focus on content more than the formatting.
This question is likely to be downvoted, blocked saying too wide or out of context. 
But still I would like to have comments from experts!

Comment: ?? I am sure non native speakers will find some difficulties in reading a block of text. Try rephrasing your question.

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/219576/35864

Comment: The article you refer to is utter nonsense. We had that question some years ago, see the comment of moewe above (https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/219576/35864). The article is not about academic research, but about copying.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: LOL the article had to be republished a year later (2015) due to numerous errors whilst it used the much more expensive  Arbortext publishing system https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbortext_Advanced_Print_Publisher

Comment: @KJO Ha! That is funny indeed!¡!