# Plain TeX vs. “primitive” TeX

Tags: tex-core, plain-tex, initex

I'm using LaTeX for my day-to-day needs, but in order to avoid cargo-cult document creation, I'm trying to gain a better understanding of the TeX engine itself. As part of this I'm experimenting with TeX (i.e. `tex`, and as opposed to LaTeX).

Now `tex` actually loads plain TeX. That's fine, but sometimes I find myself wondering if a command (I'm using the term in a loose sense here) is a primitive or a macro defined by plain TeX, so what I'd like to know is whether there is a way to run TeX that does not load `plain.fmt`.

Having found [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/97520/what-is-plain-tex/) I assumed that this could be done by using `virtex` rather than `tex`, but in my MiKTeX installation `virtex` also loads `plain.fmt`:

```
$ virtex
This is TeX, Version 3.14159265 (MiKTeX 2.9.7250 64-bit)
**\relax

*\show\fmtname
> \fmtname=macro:
->plain.
<*> \show\fmtname

? x
No pages of output.
Transcript written on texput.log.
$
```

So, am I doing something wrong (misunderstanding the exact purpose of `virtex`, perhaps), or is this a bug in MiKTeX? And what can I do to tinker around with ,,primitive`` TeX, rather than (or in addition to) plain TeX?

Comment: in texlive you can use `tex --ini` to start up initex with no format preloaded, you could then use that as is or \dump a "empty" format to use with a normal tex (but I dont l know how miktex is configured) texlive doesn't distribute virtex anymore either.

Comment: you almost always want some format even if it is just a custom one you made that doesn't define any commands, at least setting catcodes so you can use `{` and `}` and setting an output routine and some non zero page size will make experiments a lot less painfull

Comment: With Miktex the --ini switch should imho work too.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, `tex --ini` works in MiKTeX, as does `initex`. I was under the (perhaps mistaken) impression that INITEX was _only_ for creating format dumps and could not be used to produce documents at all.

Comment: “gain a better...”: is something missing?

Comment: @DaG yes, ,,understanding``. Thanks, fixed.

Comment: You can discriminate between a primitive and a defined control sequence by doing `\show\cs`; in case of a primitive, TeX would answer with `\cs=\cs`. Note that plain TeX redefines no primitive (this is not the case of LaTeX).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`virtex` isn't distributed with texlive either, you can use the `--ini` option to start up tex in initex mode for such experiments. This is texlive 2019 but I understand miktex would be the same

```
$ tex --ini
This is TeX, Version 3.14159265 (TeX Live 2019) (INITEX)
**\relax

*\show\fmtname
> \fmtname=undefined.
<*> \show\fmtname

? 

*\showthe\hsize
> 0.0pt.
<*> \showthe\hsize

? 

*a

*\end
[0]
Output written on texput.dvi (1 page, 128 bytes).
Transcript written on texput.log.
```

You could either always use initex or use it once to `\dump` a custom virtex format and then use

```
tex \&myvirtex
```

to use that format with a normal tex run.

Comment: Excellent, thanks. What's `virtex`for, then? Does it differ from `tex` at all? (In either TeX Live or MiKTeX; I'm assuming that the two do not differ in these regards for now.)

Comment: virtex was just tex with a format with no defs so it exactly as I show above, if you renamed the file to `virtex.fmt` and made a symbolic link (or copy) of tex executable to an executable called virtex in the same folder then virtex would work as described in the older documents

Comment: Thanks again. You say ,,virtex was just tex with a format with no defs`` --- so it isn't anymore? Why is that?

Comment: @chsk you'd have to ask the miktex and texlive people, but note in the beginning you could not have a command like `latex` the feature of being able to make the format default from the program name was added later, similarly there were no options like `--ini` or `-fmt` so you had to have `initex latex.tex` to make `latex.fmt` and then  `tex &latex` to use latex,  so the command line options and default format selection has changed. Given a 40 year time span these things happen:-)

Comment: I suppose they do. :) Thanks again for all your help!

Comment: @chsk just noticed your first comment virtex is just what tex would have been if tex hadn't been set up to default to loading plain.fmt, so there used to be an executable that did not try to add a default, but the behaviour is exactly as above if now you start up initex, dump an empty format and then use that as virtex.fmt.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle And to compile a text file already written, how do we do that?

Comment: @AndréC just as always. as with pdflatex command: you give a filename on the commandline it uses that., or if you don't give a file you can interactively give commands to the `*` prompt.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle So, I can launch a compilation like this `tex --ini hello.tex`, as I understand it.

Comment: @AndréC yes if `hello.tex` contains `\font\z=cmr10 \z zzz \end`  thenthat command would produce a dvi file with zzz typeset.

Comment: @AndréC related https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/388352/core-tex-hello-world