# Best compiler for writing a thesis?

Tags: compiling, incompatibility, thesis, comparison

Which LaTeX compiler supports best writing a thesis? Which one provides the best compatibility with commonly used classes and packages?

The compilers that I frequently use are:

- latex
- pdflatex

Examples of classes I use to write a thesis are:

- memoir
- report
- scrrprt

The packages I most frequently used are:

- environ, etoolbox, calc
- geometry, changepage
- amsmath, amsthm, amssymb, bbm, mathtools
- colorx
- longtable, multicol
- graphicx, graphics, placeins, grffile, epstopdf, psfrag
- wrapfig
- tikz, pstricks, pgfplots
- pdfpages
- siunits
- glossaries
- hyperref

Comment: Isn't this the same question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13593/the-differences-between-tex-engines

Comment: There are three engines in common use: `LuaTeX`, `pdfTeX`, and `XeTeX`.  They can be used to work with different macro formats like plain TeX, ConTeXt, and LaTeX.  `pdfTeX` may be the 'most commonly used', but I'm not sure.  If using ConTeXt, then you are (now) really using `LuaTeX` as the engine.  I often use `pdfTeX` while drafting the document, but then switch to `LuaTeX` for the final version(s), so compatibility is not really an issue except for how you load fonts (and that is easily taken care of via the package `ifluatex`; there is also `ifxetex` for the same purpose).