# Why does the switch to ClearSans font fails in LuaLateX?

Tags: fonts, pdftex, luatex

At the moment I am experimenting with a sans-serif font for figures and a serif font for the rest of the document. When compiling this MWE with `pdflatex` everything seems to work smoothly. Switching to `lualatex` (on Texlive 2014) leads to error messages (`Font shape OT1/ClearSans(0)/m/sl undefined`) that some characters cannot be found and they are replaced by the standard serif font.

Why is the font handling different in this case and how can I fix this?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\usepackage{ClearSans}

\usepackage[eulergreek]{sansmath}

\pgfplotsset{
    tick label style = {font=\sansmath\sffamily},
    every axis label = {font=\sansmath\sffamily},
    legend style = {font=\sansmath\sffamily},
    label style = {font=\sansmath\sffamily},
    /tikz/font=\sansmath\sffamily
}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \begin{sansmath}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
                \begin{axis}
                        \addplot [blue] coordinates { (0,0) (1,2) };
                \end{axis}
                \node at (4, 1) { $\Delta T_{\mathrm S} + 25 + \alpha + \beta + a^2$};
                \node at (2, 5) {normal sans serif text};
        \end{tikzpicture} 
    \end{sansmath}
\caption{Some caption text.}
\end{figure}


text text text...

\begin{equation}
a^2 + b^2 = c^2
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Did you forget something in your question title?

Comment: "Why is the font handling different in this case and how can I fix this?" Tautological answer: because `lualatex` and `pdflatex` handle font in different ways. You can see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13593/the-differences-between-tex-engines for some more details (not a dupe). [This comment is less relevant now that your title is complete, I'm afraid]

Comment: @StephanLehmke: Thanks, that last bit got lost somehow before saving.

Comment: @egreg: That almost solves it, now the numbers are sans-serif but in italics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `sansmath` does

```
\providecommand\sansmathencoding{OT1}
```

at the beginning; this can so be overridden by adding

```
\newcommand\sansmathencoding{\encodingdefault}
```

before loading the package. You also must ensure that `fontspec` doesn't hijack math codes and fix another setting where `sansmath` hardwires `OT1`. For uppercase Greek, `EULERGREEK` is needed.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\usepackage{ClearSans}

\newcommand{\sansmathencoding}{\encodingdefault}
\usepackage[EULERGREEK]{sansmath}
\SetSymbolFont{operators}{sans}{\encodingdefault}{\sfdefault}{m}{n}

\pgfplotsset{
    tick label style = {font=\sansmath\sffamily},
    every axis label = {font=\sansmath\sffamily},
    legend style = {font=\sansmath\sffamily},
    label style = {font=\sansmath\sffamily},
    /tikz/font=\sansmath\sffamily
}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{sansmath}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
  \addplot [blue] coordinates { (0,0) (1,2) };
\end{axis}
\node at (4, 1) { $\Delta T_{\mathrm{S}} + 25 + \alpha + \beta + a^2$};
\node at (2, 5) {normal sans serif text};
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{sansmath}
\caption{Some caption text with math $\Delta T_{\mathrm{S}} + 25 + \alpha + \beta + a^2$.}
\end{figure}


text text text...

\begin{equation}
a^2 + b^2 = c^2
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I really can't understand why graphs with sans serif type are so fashionable.

Comment: This is great, thank you. It is not so much fashion but more or less a universal style convention in many scientific journals. I have no strong feelings about the issue but when combining different graphs from other sources it is much nicer if they have common typesetting.

Comment: @Alexander Is it a convention? Or is it just that they include a figure which came from a different program so they cannot use (they don't know) the font used in the document? I always thought it was the second option.

Comment: @Manuel That's my impression, too.

Comment: @Manuel, egreg: Taken from the Authors guide for figures of _Science_: "Use a sans-serif font whenever possible (we prefer Helvetica)."