# When creating the PDF usage of pdflatex is encouraged

Tags: pdftex, compiling, ieeetran

I have to send a paper for a IEEE proceeding and, in the instruction, there is this sentences with no other explanations: "**When creating the PDF usage of pdflatex is encouraged**".

The question is: I am using Win32, and MikTeX. What are they asking to me?

Comment: Instead of `pdflatex` you could use `latex+dvipdfm` or `latex+dvips+pstopdf` or any other text editor whith `pdfcreator` (or similar) printer.

Comment: miktex is a distribution of many related programs. It includes tex, latex, context, luatex, ... and pdflatex. They want you to use pdflatex.

Comment: So, @DavidCarlisle they want I use MikTeX. :-)

Comment: This one: `pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex`

Comment: Related: [The differences between TeX engines](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13593)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

miktex is a distribution of many related programs. It includes tex, latex, context, luatex, ... and pdflatex.

They want you to use pdflatex.