# How can I make the board render correctly (Sharelatex)?

Tags: sharelatex, chess

I'm trying to use the psgo package to insert some go diagrams into a sharelatex file, but the boards are failing to render. Here's a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{psgo}
\begin{document}
\begin{psgoboard}
\end{psgoboard}
\end{document}
```

This results in the bad jumble of letters and numbers below:

[image: Go Picture]

How can I fix this? I feel like I'm missing something obvious, but I'm not sure what.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You need to process this with XeLaTeX. Are you doing that? You can change the engine in ShareLaTeX.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! That worked well. Out of curiosity, how does one know in general processor to choose?

Comment: The problem here is that `psgo` relies on the `pstricks` package, which requires compiling to `.dvi` format before compiling to `.pdf` format. XeLaTeX does this automatically. You can read more about it [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8413/32888). We'll probably close your question as a duplicate of that one, if that's okay.

Comment: If you want to know more about the difference between all the different engines in general, you can read more about it at [The differences between TeX engines](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13593/32888)

Comment: In general, you know by reading the documentation. Although you might not know that e.g. XeLaTeX is one way of rendering via DVI, the documentation should at least tell you something e.g. that it requires `pstricks` or that it needs to be processed using `.tex -> .dvi -> ...` or whatever.