# What is the difference between LuaLaTeX and pdfLaTeX?

Tags: pdftex, luatex

What are the differences between luaLaTex and pdfLaTex? What are the advantages and disadvantages?

Comment: see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/13601/2388

Comment: thanks @UlrikeFischer Isn't there the letter " ı " in LuaLaTeX?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by the reference to  ı but lualatex is the latex source running on luatex and pdflatex is the same source running on pdftex so apart from some very small conditional code parts all the differences between lualatex and pdflatex are differences between pdftex and luatex,