# I can't take my shape one step further. how can I draw more

Tags: loops, shapes, rounded-corners, polygon, fractals

I can't keep repeating the shape in the corners. I can't issue a command like corner of the corner. I want it to continue in a loop like fractal but I couldn't make the loop. With the command I wrote, the same shape is not drawn again on the small pink corners, can you help me?

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usepackage{caption}
\tikzset{
    buffer/.style={
        draw,
        regular polygon,
        regular polygon sides=4,
        minimum size=20em
    },
    pics/nine/.style 2 args= {code={ 
            \node[buffer, fill=#1] (A) {};
            \foreach \mycorner in {1,2,3,4}
            \node[buffer, fill=#2, scale=.33, transform canvas] at (A.corner \mycorner) {};
    }},
}
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \node[buffer, fill=pink] (B) {};
            \foreach \mycorner in {1,2,3,4}
            \pic[scale=.33, transform shape] at (B.corner \mycorner) {nine={green}{pink}};
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{Number 4}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi, Welcome to TeX-SE! Please consider to post a MWE, so that we can understand what you managed to do : https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3343/what-makes-a-good-mwe

Comment: I added my answer, but I would like to tell you can ping me only under an answer or a question of mine or if I commented before your ping. I saw your message only by chance, it didn't reach me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sure there are better solutions, but this is very simple, with TikZ:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usepackage{caption}

\tikzset{
    buffer/.style={
        draw,
        regular polygon,
        regular polygon sides=4,
        minimum size=20em
    },
}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[buffer, fill=pink]{};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{One square}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[buffer, fill=pink] (A) {};
        \foreach \mycorner in {1,2,3,4}
            {\node[buffer, fill=green,scale=.33, transform shape] (A\mycorner) at (A.corner \mycorner) {};} 
    \end{tikzpicture}       
    \caption{One square with squares}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[buffer, fill=pink] (A) {};
        \foreach \mycorner in {1,2,3,4}
            {\node[buffer, fill=green,scale=.33, transform shape] (A\mycorner) at (A.corner \mycorner) {};} 
        \foreach \mycornerone in {1,2,3,4}
            {\foreach \mycornertwo in {1,2,3,4}
                {\node[buffer, fill=pink,scale=.11, transform shape] at (A\mycornerone.corner \mycornertwo) {};}}
    \end{tikzpicture}       
    \caption{One square with squares with squares}
\end{figure}
    \begin{figure}
\centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[buffer, fill=pink] (A) {};
        \foreach \mycorner in {1,2,3,4}
            {\node[buffer, fill=green,scale=.33, transform shape] (A\mycorner) at (A.corner \mycorner) {};} 
        \foreach \mycornerone in {1,2,3,4}
            {\foreach \mycornertwo in {1,2,3,4}
                {\node[buffer, fill=pink,scale=.11, transform shape] (A\mycornerone\mycornertwo) at   (A\mycornerone.corner \mycornertwo) {};}}
        \foreach \mycornerone in {1,2,3,4}
            {\foreach \mycornertwo in {1,2,3,4}
              {\foreach \mycornerthree in {1,2,3,4}
                {\node[buffer, fill=green,scale=.0367, transform shape] at (A\mycornerone\mycornertwo.corner \mycornerthree) {};}}}
    \end{tikzpicture}       
    \caption{One square with squares with squares with squares}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I can't thank you enough :) I didn't know that the /mycorner command was used like this.   Now I tried to continue this way and I succeeded.  Thank you very much :)

Comment: can i ask one more thing ?  i am continuing this in polygons but is this possible in a foreach loop ? For example, is it possible to define n and then draw steps for the given n values ?

Comment: @SmmTex Please ask a new question with this one linked. I think it's possible but maybe it is beyond my ability. With a new question someone else could answer.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a way to do recursive drawing in [Metapost](http://www.tug.org/metapost.html) that uses the `luamplib`.  You need to compile this with `lualatex`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{mplibcode}
input colorbrewer-rgb

def do(expr s, level) = 
    fill s withcolor if odd level: Blues else: Reds fi [8][1+level];
    draw s;
    if level > 0:
        for i=1 upto length s:
            do(s shifted - center s scaled 7/16 shifted point i of s, level - 1);
        endfor
    fi
enddef;

beginfig(1);
    do(unitsquare scaled 200, 5);
endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

You may want to adjust the scaling parameter to get different effects, and you can try it with other paths.  But don't try it with more than about 6 or 7 levels, because it will take forever.

Comment: thank you, this is exactly what I wanted but I am getting an error while running the command. Is it possible for me to continue as I wrote? I hadn't heard of MetaPost, now I'll look into it. Why can't I run the tex file you wrote? Is there a separate environment or version difference for metapost?

Comment: You need to compile it using `lualatex` to enable the `luamplib` package.

Comment: thank you, ı will try. @CarLaTeX can you please take a look at my question? I'm trying to continue with the answer you wrote.

Comment: I tried to activate it, but I still get too many errors, the figure does not appear, I don't know what to do. I searched a lot, but I did not understand how to use LualaTex. Is there a command sequence you can recommend as I wrote? @Thruston Sorry for asking so many questions, I'm trying to learn :)

Comment: This [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13593/15036) explains about the different TeX "engines" and how to use them.

Comment: You say nothing about your own environment, so I do not know exactly how you should run my example.  In my environment, I save the code part as `smm.tex`, then open a command line and run `lualatex smm.tex` which produces `smm.pdf`.

Comment: I've added my full command and I'm wondering if I can get your shape by adding on top of that.