# "\tenrm" is not built into TEX. but why can it be used directly?

Tags: fonts, tex-core

On page 15 of the book **The TEXbook : a complete user's guide to computer typesetting with TEX**, Mr. KNUTH said that

> Each font used in a TEX manuscript is associated with a control sequence; for example, the 10-point font in this paragraph is called \tenrm, and the corresponding 9-point font is called \ninerm. The slanted fonts that match \tenrm and \ninerm are called \tensl and \ninesl. These control sequences are not built into TEX, nor are they the actual names of the fonts; TEX users are just supposed to make up convenient names, whenever new fonts are introduced into a manuscript. Such control sequences are used to change typefaces.

If it is true, `\tenrm` should not be used directly in TeX. However, this code can be run directly, which indicates that the `\tenrm` is built in,

```
    \tenrm Ten-point is difference between from
    \bye % end the document
```

Comment: They are not built into the *program* TeX, but they are defined in the `plain` *format*.

Comment: @campa Does TeX use `plain` format?

Comment: The program `tex` or `pdftex` preload format `tex`, which is indeed the format generated using `plain.tex`. AFAIK only `initex` does not preload formats (because it is used to create formats).

Comment: TeX book, page 10, last paragraph.

Comment: @cabohah So, why did the author say **These control sequences are not built into TEX**?  It uses the `plain.tex`, so it is the same.

Comment: Because he is referring to the program, not the format.

Comment: @campa But what control sequences are defined by the TeX program?

Comment: The ones marked by an asterisk in the index.

Comment: @campa How can I find an example in that book. It seems I have met one now.

Comment: `\bye` is similarly not a built in primitive, but is a macro defined in `plain.tex`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are confusing the TeX the *program* (or sometimes *engine*), i.e. the piece of software that actually does the typesetting, with the TeX the *format* (to which we commonly refer as "*plain TeX*"), i.e. a set of macros which the engine uses.

When I type `tex` on my prompt I get

```
This is TeX, Version 3.141592653 (TeX Live 2023) (preloaded format=tex)
**
```

meaning that the program TeX has started by loading the format `tex`, i.e. by loading the file `plain.tex` first.<sup>1)</sup> The program itself doesn't have any preloaded fonts, but the format file `plain.tex` has

```
\font\tenrm=cmr10
```

in line 400.

If I type `latex` on a prompt I get on the other hand

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.25 (TeX Live 2023) (preloaded format=latex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
**
```

which shows that the program pdfTeX (which is a *different* engine than TeX but can do everything TeX can, plus a couple of other things) is being run with format `latex`, meaning that a different set of macros (defined by `latex.ltx` and a couple of other files) is being used. You can of course use the program pdfTeX with the plain tex format: that what happens when you type `pdftex` in a prompt.

Admittedly, the TeX Book isn't always 100% transparent as to which commands are primitives and which ones are macros defined in the format. The primitive control sequences are marked with an asterisk in the index. Another good resource is https://www.tug.org/utilities/plain/cseq.html.

---

Further reading:

- [The differences between TeX engines](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13593/82917)
- [What is the difference between TeX and LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/49/82917)

---

<sup>1)</sup> White lie... the format is built in a more efficient way.

Comment: Why `\fiverm Ten-point is difference between from` will procude overlapping text?