# How to use "\textstrokecapitalt"

Tags: pdftex, overleaf, unicode, latin

I am using Overleaf to create a report, and I have to use some Latin characters in the text.

For the word "SȾÁUTW̱", the unicodes are:

- (U+023E) \textstrokecapitalt for "Ⱦ"
- (U+00C1) \capitalacute{A} for "Á"
- (U+0331) \textsubbar{W} for "W̱"

I can run the A and the W, however, I cannot seem to get the code for the T work.

In the preamble, I have the following packages (I tried to somehow run something for Latin...):

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{unicode}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

along with

```
\inputencoding{latin1}
```

right at the word ""SȾÁUTW̱".

I'm out of ideas... Please help! Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please post the code of a small complete document, from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`, that illustrates your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Suggestion: use a Unicode engine, like `lualatex` (no problem in Overleaf!) and choose a font with the symbols you need. On my computer, `albatross` says that one of them is, for example, `Libertine`, so:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{libertine}
\begin{document}
    SȾÁUTW̱
\end{document}
```

[image]

(BTW: `latin1` has nothing to do with Latin the language... )

If you need to use `pdflatex`, or math, or you need a specific font the thing could be a bit more complex --- we do not know because you did not provide a compilable, minimum example.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply! I just started learning latex on Overleaf so sorry about that. I am using pdflatex, bibtex, documentclass{article}. Would that help? I guess lualatex and pdflatex does not work together?

Comment: Hi! You can read it here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13593/the-differences-between-tex-engines . You can easily switch engine on overleaf, just choose "compiler" in the main menu.

Answer (score 0):

With legacy engines you can use `tipa` for `\textsubbar` and `\ooalign` for the stroke.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[safe]{tipa}

\NewDocumentCommand{\textstroke}{m}{{% open a group
  \vphantom{\strokechar}%
  \ooalign{\hfil#1\hfil\cr\hfil\strokechar\hfil\cr}%
}}
\newcommand{\strokechar}{\raisebox{0.2ex}{\textfractionsolidus}}

\begin{document}

S\textstroke{T}\capitalacute{A}UT\textsubbar{W}

\end{document}
```

[image]

But do remove `\inputencoding{latin1}` which is definitely wrong for your purposes.

Comment: OMG IT WORKED!!!! AHHH THANK YOU SO MUCH!! I spent hours trying to make it work yesterday :'( This is amazing!! Thank you!!  Would it be alright if you could expand and elaborate on the codes you used? I would like to understand how you ended up with the  \NewDocumentCommand bit. Thank you so much for your help!