# Xetex on Texlipse

Tags: xetex, texlipse

I want to enable the use of unicode text in my latex files. How can I compile using Xetex in Texlipse? I can't seem to find the option to select which builder to use like in other IDEs.

Comment: Here is my first google result for *texlipse builder*: http://texlipse.sourceforge.net/manual/configuration.html

Comment: I don't see Xetex though.

Comment: You should look if your distribution of choice has XeTeX included. If yes, look for how you can use Xe(La)TeX with it, as in: http://sourceforge.net/p/texlipse/discussion/search/?q=xetex

Comment: I think I need to say I am only answering because nobody else does. There are certainly way more proficient TeX-users  out there who must have run into this problem and most likely solved it.

Answer (score 1):

I personally don't know what the difference between `XeTeX` and `XeLaTeX` are, when I looked into it on the sourceforge discussion page linked in the comments above there is a question that configures `hyperref` for `xetex` and explicitly states the pdfcreator as `xelatex`.  Additionlly, the Wikipedia page for `XeTeX` provides a source example which explicity refers to `XeLaTeX`.

But in terms of setting up a command line builder I can comment:

1. I don't think `xetex` can be configured from (Window > Preferences > Texlipse > Builder Settings: because each of the listed programs correspond to a specific class file (see list of classes on the left hand side of the image below) within `net.sourceforge.texlipse.builder` of `net.sourceforge.texlipse_10500.0.2.b201407171807E43sw.jar` (found in your plugins folder of the eclipse installation)
   On my computer any of the missing command line paths shown in the right hand side of the picture below as () have not yet been installed.
   [image: TexlipseBuilderSettingsScreenshotClassFilesPerEntry]
2. If `xetex` was to be added to this page, it would probably be done within the source/development of the plugin itself.  I don't have any experience in eclipse plugin development and can't comment on whether you could easily create a class file to point to `xetex`.
3. That being said, Eclipse can setup external programs as builders from within the `Launch Configurations`.  Using eclipse variables with the command line inside this setup is easy and works very well, but it is still recognized as an external program so automatic building requires some editing to use the right program.
4. I find sequencing multiple programs in the builder menu or launch configurations cumbersome and not very stable so I write batch file scripts and set them up once in the external programs

Comment: Concerning the difference between XeTeX and XeLaTeX, these are both formats (TeX and LaTeX, respectively) that use the `xetex` engine.  See [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/151731/17423) for more information.