# Optimization used in latex

Tags: wysiwyg

Can anybody explain which are the optimization algorithms used in latex, that make the difference with wysiwyg editors, like msword?

Comment: It's not just a matter of algorithms. I suggest you to take a look at this: [How can I explain the meaning of LaTeX to my grandma?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/94889/how-can-i-explain-the-meaning-of-latex-to-my-grandma/) and this [What are TeX and LaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6776/what-are-tex-and-latex)

Comment: If you're actually interested in the typographical aspect of TeX (rather than philosophical / workflow aspects), I suggest you take a look at http://nitens.org/taraborelli/latex.