# Usage of LaTeX?

Tags: typography

I've seen LaTeX being used in academic theses, letters, music scores, CVs, reaction schemes, Feynman diagrams and even exam papers.
Did I miss anything intriguing?

Comment: For starters, take a look at [Showcase of beautiful typography done in TeX & friends](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1319)

Comment: This also lists quite a few use cases: [Is LaTeX used outside mathematics and academia?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39029)

Comment: And another one [What professions use TeX/LaTeX besides CS?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/940)